# typescript restrict count of object's properties

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to restrict the count of object properties, say I want to restrict object have only one string propery (with any name), I can do:

```
{[index: string]: any}
```

to restrict the type of property, but can one restrict also the count of properties?

Answer (score 17):

There are many answers to this question on Stackoverflow (including [this detailed one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57576688/2321594)), but none of them worked for my situation, which is similar to the one posted here.

### Problem

I have a function that takes an object.  I want it to throw a **Compilation Error** (Typescript) if the passed object doesn't have exactly one key. e.g.

```
f({}); // Must error here, as it has less than one key!
f({ x: 5 });
f({ x: 5, y : 6 }); // Must error here, as it has more than one key!
```

---

### Solution

Using the popular [UnionToIntersection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286) and [IsUnion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53955431), I achieved it via the following utility function.

```
type SingleKey<T> = IsUnion<keyof T> extends true ? never : {} extends T ? never : T;
```

#### Full Code:

```
// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;

// From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53955431
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true;

// Here we come!
type SingleKey<T> = IsUnion<keyof T> extends true ? never : {} extends T ? never : T;

// Usage:
function f<T extends Record<string, any>>(obj: SingleKey<T>) {
    console.log({ obj });
}

f({}); // errors here!
f({ x: 5 });
f({ x: 5, y : 6 }); // errors here!
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mx6Mzw)

Comment: Broken Playground link, you can now find it [here](https://tsplay.dev/mx6Mzw)

Comment: thanks @Stanislas. updated the link

Comment: @Aidin Is there a way to make an array of SingleKey with all different keys? Doing `Array<SingleKey<T>>` makes it so they all need the same key. (e.g. `[{key1: "value1"},{key2:"value1"}]` throws and error because key1!==key2. Which is sadly the exact opposite behavior that I am looking for.

Comment: @Daniel that should be possible but it's probably a bit challenging. :) I played a little bit on it but couldn't get anywhere.  I highly recommend posting that as a separate question on SO and cross-referencing it here!  GL :)

Comment: @Aidin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71462472/is-there-a-way-to-make-an-array-of-singlekey-with-all-different-keys

Comment: This didn't error as expected `const test: SingleKey<TA | TB> = { a: 1, b: 2 }`. Though this answer did work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370222

Answer (score 3):

Most likely no. The best solution that comes to my mind is wrapping an `Object` (or `Map`) with you custom class with methods `set(key: string, val: any)` and `get(key: string)` that can disallow adding new items to the underlying collection under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Because [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57571664/typescript-type-for-an-object-with-only-one-key-no-union-type-allowed-as-a-key) has been marked as a duplicate of this one, let me answer here.

**Check if a type is a union**

```
/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953814/typescript-check-if-a-type-is-a-union/53955431
 */
type IsSingleton<T> =
  [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>]
    ? true
    : false

/**
 * @author https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/10325032
 */
type UnionToIntersection<Union> =
  (Union extends any
    ? (argument: Union) => void
    : never
  ) extends (argument: infer Intersection) => void
    ? Intersection
  : never;
```

**Allow only singleton types**

```
type SingletonOnly<T> =
  IsSingleton<T> extends true
    ? T
    : never
```

**Restrict a function to accept only a singleton type**

```
declare function foo<K extends string>(s: SingletonOnly<K>): void

declare const singleton: 'foo';
foo(singleton);

declare const union: "foo" | "bar";
foo(union); // Compile-time error
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=33&pc=1#code/PQKhCgAIUgBBnApoyALALugDvAXMYedAQwGMBrAewDdEAnAMwBtKB3AOlMoFtgBHAK6IiAS0oA7eMACsAZgCccgBwBGACzB0ATyzDSdEVnQBaUqkQVjIhseLHtuq-FvGB4seJkLp0tbJVQIMDgDigAkvAAyiLiAOZMiOgSADwAKgB8kAC8UJAA2qkAupCIAB7oiOIAJvD5AKruEqmUYeIVdEik6B5p6YW5kJAA-JDodEIDkLiQDMRMSODgoBDQcMQC6KiUdGiYOPiEJBQ09MxsnDzAAkgdwABMSkoA7HcqSsAAVqRzAF6BcEgUBhsHgCEQyFRaIwWBwuLxiDIAAyyJ7SB4ANmAKmRd2kOMCwVCkAaHmarXanW6KRJEkyOUGAAoaeISuVKjVIMRxFpJiMGcQ6LEBNxKuhpsyAJTZTLUSgiKqTabiRBQ3JSsoVaq1fmC4Wi6YxBj0SDk+iUjxSrIyuUKwaDEamjoWKniXJKlX0ADciyJ0TiCSS4gA8uImFpetlchE-fFEikMqzNRyxhM7cNIKlFZBlarwFULEwBSgGG4uh5IPpEMQKskANKJ9m1IgGOLpBl4SAxgMSENhuvpCXTWXyxb50iFugoLiSdCQeAxWOB6YAcgYlEoy+9leriHbC+74gl3rzBaLFYkREgbg80wARGvKLfIAAfSC3gBGAtvW8nO4Z14kI9IAISAAGEeCwEQEnsEQRRKOg6G2cAgA)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [Tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#:%7E:text=Try-,Tuple%20Types,-A%20tuple%20type) but these are basically arrays and NOT "objects", so this is not a direct answer for the specific question but instead is intended to give an alternative yet easy approach to the problem as long as keeping the object structure is not required.

> A tuple type is another sort of Array type that knows exactly how many elements it contains, and exactly which types it contains at specific positions.

```
function doSomething(pair: [string, number]) {
  const c = pair[2];
  Error: Tuple type '[string, number]' of length '2' has no element at index '2'.

  // you can also destructure the input to named variables
  const [key, val] = pair;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the N pairs type check function so it works not only with single key-value pair but also with any number of pairs.

### Code

```js
/**********
 * Type
 ***********/
// REF: https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues/2988
type ObjectEntries<T, U = Required<T>> = {
  [K in keyof U]:[K,U[K]]
}[keyof U]

// REF: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-885980381
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (
  U extends never ? never : (arg: U) => never
) extends (arg: infer I) => void
  ? I
  : never;

type UnionToTuple<T> = UnionToIntersection<
  T extends never ? never : (t: T) => T
> extends (_: never) => infer W
  ? [...UnionToTuple<Exclude<T, W>>, W]
  : [];

type Length<T extends unknown[]> = T['length']

type NPairRecord<T = Record<string, any>, N = -1> = Length<UnionToTuple<ObjectEntries<T>>> extends N ? T : never;

/**********
 * Type Checker
 ***********/
function asZeroPair<T>(_: NPairRecord<T, 0>) {}
function asOnePair<T>(_: NPairRecord<T, 1>) {}
function asTwoPair<T>(_: NPairRecord<T, 2>) {}

/**********
 * Example
 ***********/
{
    const obj = {};
    asZeroPair(obj); // 
    asOnePair(obj);  // type error
    asTwoPair(obj);  // type error
}

{
    const obj = {a: 1};
    asZeroPair(obj); // type error
    asOnePair(obj);  // 
    asTwoPair(obj);  // type error
}

{
    const obj = {a: 1, b: 2};
    asZeroPair(obj); // type error
    asOnePair(obj);  // type error
    asTwoPair(obj);  // 
}
```

### Outline

1. ObjectEntries

   - e.g) `{a: 1, b: 2}` => `["a", 1] | ["b", 2]`
2. UnionToTuple

   - e.g) `["a", 1] | ["b", 2]` => `[["a", 1], ["b", 2]]`
3. Check the length with Conditional Types

   - e.g)  `[["a", 1], ["b", 2]]` => length is 2, and check if it's expected.

### Playground

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.3&ssl=24&ssc=1&pln=29&pc=47#code/PQKj4hYAoACFYBUCeAHApjeEcmDAFzXVgHkAjAK3QGMCBRAOwICcBLdAZwB5EAaWAFVYAXlgAldAEcArmxboAJrwB8K0bADeWWAG0A0rDaNYAa3TIA9gDMhAXQBcBvoIN27MAL67zV24I9oQmIhRjZLRkRLAElmdBZOWgJwxm5BdTEACh1hdAAPAnRGRU5YRnQAN3jYAH4yyuqHWEyAQxYAcybBAEpRdXKqlhhe-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)