# Why does A | B allow a combination of both, and how can I prevent it?

Tags: typescript, xor, typescript-types

I was surprised to find that TypeScript won't complain at me doing something like this:

```
type sth = { value: number, data: string } | { value: number, note: string };
const a: sth = { value: 7, data: 'test' };
const b: sth = { value: 7, note: 'hello' };
const c: sth = { value: 7, data: 'test', note: 'hello' };
```

I thought maybe `value` was picked out as a type union discriminant or something, because the only thing that I could come up with to explain this was if TypeScript somehow understood `number` here to be a superset of `1 | 2` for example.

So I changed `value` to be `value2` on the second object:

```
type sth = { value: number, data: string } | { value2: number, note: string };
const a: sth = { value: 7, data: 'test' };
const b: sth = { value2: 7, note: 'hello' };
const c: sth = { value: 7, data: 'test', note: 'hello' };
```

Still, no complaint, and I'm able to construct `c`. IntelliSense breaks down on `c` though, it won't suggest anything when I `.` into it. Same if I change `value` in `c` to be `value2`.

Why doesn't this produce an error? Clearly, I have failed to provide one type or the other and instead provided a weird mix of both!

Comment: I don't understand, which statement in your code did you expect to result in an error? It all seems ok.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The discussion in issue [Microsoft/TypeScript#14094](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14094) is relevant here.

Types in TypeScript are *open* in the sense that an object has to have *at least* the properties described by a type for it to match.  So the object `{ value: 7, data: 'test', note: 'hello' }` matches the type `{ value: number, data: string }`, even though it has that excess `note` property:

```
const obj = { value: 7, data: 'test', note: 'hello' };
const val: sthA = obj; // okay
```

So your `c` variable is indeed a valid `sth`.  It would only fail to be a `sth` if it were *missing* all properties required by some constituent of the union:

```
// error: missing both "data" and "note"
const oops: sth = { value: 7 };
```

However: when you are assigning a fresh object literal to a typed variable in TypeScript, it performs [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) to try to prevent errors.  This has the effect of "closing" TypeScript's open types for the duration of that assignment.  This works as you expect for interface types.  But for unions, TypeScript currently (as mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14094#issuecomment-280129798)) only complains about properties that don't appear on *any* of the consituents.  So the following is still an error:

```
// error, "random" is not expected:
const alsoOops: sth = { value: 7, data: 'test', note: 'hello', random: 123 };
```

But TypeScript currently doesn't do excess property checking on union types in the strict way that you want, where it checks the object literal against each constituent type and complains if there are extra properties in all of them.   It does do this with [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), as mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#12745](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12745), but that doesn't address your issue because neither definition of `sth` is discriminated (meaning: having a property whose literal type picks out exactly one constituent of the union).

There is a suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#20863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20863) to perform excess property checks on all unions, but it's not part of the language yet.

---

So, until and unless this is changed, the best workaround for you is probably to avoid unions when using object literals by assigning explicitly to the intended constituent and then widening to the union later if you want:

```
type sthA = { value: number, data: string };
type sthB = { value: number, note: string };
type sth = sthA | sthB;

const a: sthA = { value: 7, data: 'test' };
const widenedA: sth = a;
const b: sthB = { value: 7, note: 'hello' };
const widenedB: sth = b;
const c: sthA = { value: 7, data: 'test', note: 'hello' }; // error as expected
const widenedC: sth = c; 
const cPrime: sthB = { value: 7, data: 'test', note: 'hello' }; // error as expected
const widenedCPrime: sth = cPrime;
```

---

If you *really* want to express an *exclusive* union of object types, you can use [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) types to do so, by turning the original union into a new one where each member explicitly prohibits extra keys from the other members of the union by adding them as optional properties of type `never` (which shows up as `undefined` because optional properties can always be `undefined`):

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;
type Id<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;
type _ExclusifyUnion<T, K extends PropertyKey> =
    T extends unknown ? Id<T & Partial<Record<Exclude<K, keyof T>, never>>> : never;
type ExclusifyUnion<T> = _ExclusifyUnion<T, AllKeys<T>>;
```

Armed with that, you can "exclusify" `sth` into:

```
type xsth = ExclusifyUnion<sth>;
/* type xsth = {
    value: number;
    data: string;
    note?: undefined;
} | {
    value: number;
    note: string;
    data?: undefined;
} */
```

And now the expected error will appear:

```
const z: xsth = { value: 7, data: 'test', note: 'hello' }; // error!
/* Type '{ value: number; data: string; note: string; }' is not assignable to
 type '{ value: number; data: string; note?: undefined; } | 
 { value: number; note: string; data?: undefined; }' */
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAzsAWBBKBeKBvKA3AhgGwFcIAuKAOwIFsAjCAJwBooATHYHUuOgSzIHMoAXwDcAWABQoSLAQAhVBmz4ipCjXpMyAe2AkZPfkLGTw0OPAXnkAHxnxZxiQGMtZOFC3UAVgsy5CegDsTKzspADkunDhmjp64fAQeHha4UbOru7+nAjIaJ5ewlAA9MUeANY4IBIZbsBQHHZ5iv4qUMEsbI2RENHp4i51UADu3MwQZBDMiDkWaDjGg+7Us-JofspBsboRicmp-Uv1o+OTzLKzCtSLmfVOs80bAaQdod1RwDHkcbtJKWkiEpleh0LR0BowKAQAAekCcumYtXcJwmUwAwpc0E4bkMnAAFHiUPTmNYtTYvEJdCIfL7aHZQBJ-A6A0pQuig8E4SEwuEIpHHMao5hogncImYqD4wkQRziCRSaCIZIAaQgIBgAB4ACoAPgUWqh0N0ZGYkIIZHK2mGZCgAH4oOU1VoAGZQA2qCBYejGBVQACSzG1erQBphxtNUF4zvoUAAqnbFABtZWRm2OkAuuMAXVIseTWaEUA9XroPtMUAA+gBRaFOQgwbjOkCxsjcVzapgpsMTCMErSQOigVUgYMSKDjt2G8Nmi1Wm32gPaqAAMigeJwg+4+A1ACUIC46IGa3WCOMNcqmOnM7rNJ76DqH0XyHfS-Ly8f643m6327qFNXa0-JsWzbMgOygJU8GHTVdR1WVfWhcwFA-AgG2An8wPMOCJGKAAqKAEKQ9YxwnVo9DUWhX3ECdOjCfReD4YwaLpCBbVIc1xmdXgpmMQQoFsdASPHMjVCoSimInFicgMRihNonA2KgDiIC4s5eKgXDihqOUBluKAAC9SEQhBfCUZ52kpOiemibZ4j2f4jCBNkOQAQhw-CtXLcInjaCjvXk6SGKKKT6P4IpBDSbhITpCEGz4MgcGoPBoGALQx19byzN8sT-LeQKwu+XRFOU1SeMLWwxx88ictLQriWAGSijeYqTRU7jmHCtJNO0oA)

Comment: Sometimes it seems like typescript has a secret points system the way this works. It's so easy with a discriminated union (especially a partially disjunct one) to fall into these traps.

Comment: I am comparing your `ExclusifyingUnion` function with a comparable function [in an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66407294/4376643).  I ran into some problems when the additional keys specifier included in a  type.  Should that happen?  Also, does `ExclusifyUnion` handle deep objects?  I could not see a recursion call - would that be necessary in `ExclusifyUnion`?

Comment: I don't know if I fully understand what you're doing in your answer, sorry.  Presumably you are mixing the "exclusive union" operation with a "verify but do not widen" operation, but I don't see how this question pertains to the latter.  The `ExclusifyUnion` type function in this answer is not meant to apply recursively to properties (which was not asked in the question), nor will it *necessarily* do useful things if the object types it operates on have [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) (again, not asked here).

Comment: The solution I posted below is answering the question - "What general type function (using distributive conditional types, etc) will compute the general 'ExclusiveUnion'(*)'?  (*  I would prefer OR-Union to indicate 'satisfies one or more union members`).  "General" includes both 'index signatures' and  deep objects with properties that may be Unions.  ---  I posed this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66382997/how-to-define-a-true-logical-or-of-object-types-no-mixing-of-different-object-k) but it was closed and I was instructed to post here.  Wrong question to post to?

Comment: You can post here if you want, although it would help if you explain right at the beginning of your answer what use cases you are trying to satisfy since the question isn't directly asking about them.  Then people who have a similar question but find my answer insufficient will see yours that says something like: "If you are trying to do this for [list of use cases] not addressed by the other answers here, read on:".

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the role of this line: `type Id<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;`.  I suppose if `T` were an interface `interface { f(){}; a:number; }` then `T` would not extend `{a:number}` and `Id<T>` would evaluate to `never`.  Is that the purpose then, to act as a filter?

Comment: I [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66448287/typescript-type-function-can-you-amend-this-function-for-strict-excess-propert) asking if your type function `ExclusifyUnion` could be amended to handle a signature index, also providing a link back to your answer here.

Comment: Wow such a great answer and such great discussion in comments, thanks for it!

Comment: When I use this solution, it does indeed error when adding properties from the other type, but it still shows the property as an option in vscode intellisense :(. Just using the plain old solution in the OP has the right intellisense hints for properties but then doesn't error. Wish there was a wholistic solution.

Answer (score 21):

Another option is to use optional `never` properties to explicitly disallow a mix of fields from the two types in the union:

```
type sth =
  { value: number, data: string; note?: never; } |
  { value: number, note: string; data?: never; };

const a: sth = { value: 7, data: 'test' };
const b: sth = { value: 7, note: 'hello' };
const c: sth = { value: 7, data: 'test', note: 'hello' };
   // ~ Type '{ value: number; data: string; note: string; }'
   //     is not assignable to type 'sth'.
```

The `ts-essentials` library has an [`XOR` generic](https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials#xor) that can be used to help you construct exclusive unions like this:

```
import { XOR } from 'ts-essentials';

type sth = XOR<
  { value: number, data: string; },
  { value: number, note: string; }
>;

const a: sth = { value: 7, data: 'test' };
const b: sth = { value: 7, note: 'hello' };
const c: sth = { value: 7, data: 'test', note: 'hello' };
// ~ Type '{ value: number; data: string; note: string; }'
//     is not assignable to type ...
```

Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=37#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgDQPICU4F84DMoQhwDkMAzgLQCmZZVAdjMAIYA2ZxA3AFDcwCeYKnDIwAFnAC8KDAB5ucRHABubAK5UAXHHpqQAIypQANHAAmzGM22iowegHNO2YwqWrWG7boNHT9CBgtERg7R2csAD5eAGMIelE4axCJaSQPLzgAdlMLK21SGhhibB44hPh9G3Epd3VgnJ1A4OIxKlZWCBKsMvjEmOrUus8G3MtkwtFif2aCto6u0u4AemW4AD84ABVBYWJ0+u89QyhnPOTbeycmoOqw66xiFbXFRWAyG6TaYAd6Zn1WMIYBA4AIhHAAHRQoA) for that last example.

Comment: FWIW, this answer is doing the same thing as mine.  `ExclusifyUnion<A | B>` and `XOR<A, B>` both add optional `never` properties for the "off" keys in the union.

Answer (score 1):

This answer addresses how to compute validation of the assignment of a literal initializer ,e.g., `{ value: 7, data: 'test', note: 'hello' }` to a union of object types, e.g., `type sth={ value: number, data: string } | { value: number, note: string }` without ignoring any unspecified excess properties.

The type function presented here is comparable to `ExclusifyUnion` in the [above solution of @jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370791/4376643). However it is not simply another type function using the same input with slightly different coding.  Instead the function presented here uses *additional input*, as explain below.

#### Adding type of literal initializer as an extra parameter to type function

Consider the statement:

```
type T1 = {<some props>}
type T2 = {<some props>}
type T3 = {<some props>}
type TU=T1|T2|T3
SomeTypeDef<T> = ...
const t:SomeTypeDef<TU> = {a:1,b:2}
```

The last line is an assignment statement.  The processing taking place in the assignment has two distinct and separate parts:

- The left hand side in isolation, which is the type function `SomeTypeDef` with the single input variable `TU`.
- Determining the validity of the assignment of the r.h.s. literal initializer `{<some props>}` to the l.h.s type.  That computation takes place using Typescript's fixed assignment rules that cannot be changed.

Now suppose we define an additional type

```
type I = {a:1,b:2}
```

which you will notice is the type of the literal initializer on the r.h.s. of the assignment.  Now suppose we add that type as an additional variable to a type function on the l.h.s.:

```
const t:SomeTypeDefPlus<TU,I> = {a:1,b:2}
```

Now the l.h.s type function has *additional* information to work with .  Therefore whatever `SomeTypeDef<TU>` can express,  `SomeTypeDefPlus<TU,I>` can also express in the same length code.  However `SomeTypeDefPlus<TU,I>` may express more things than `SomeTypeDef<TU>`, and/or may be able to express the same things in shorter code.  In psuedo-psuedo code:

```
Expressability(SomeTypeDefPlus<TU,I>) >= Expressability(SomeTypeDef<TU>)
```

You should be objecting because

- writing the type `type I = {<some props>}`, AND
- and writing the r.h.s literal initializer `.... = {<some props>}`

is twice as much writing - a code length penalty.  That's true.  The idea is that - if it is worth it - a way would eventually be enabled to infer type `I` from the r.h.s initializer, e..g, a preprocess or a new typescript language feature.  After all, it's kind of silly that the static information `{<some props>}` is right there, but cannot accessed due to a design artifice.

A demonstration of the code is given below, followed by a discussion.

```
// c.f. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42997
// craigphicks Feb 2021
//-----------------------
// TYPES
type T1 = {a:number,b:number}
type T2 = {a:number,c:number}
type T3 = {a:string,c?:number}
type T4 = {a:bigint, [key:string]:bigint}
type T5 = {a:string, d:T1|T2|T3|T4}
type T12 = T1|T2|T3|T4|T5
//-----------------------
// TYPES INFERRED FROM THE INITIALIZER 
type I0 = {}
type I1 = {a:1,b:1}
type I2 = {a:1,c:1}
type I3 = {a:1,b:1,c:1}
type I4 = {a:1}
type I5 = {a:'2',c:1}
type I6 = {a:'2'}
type I7 = {a:1n, 42:1n}
type I8 = {a:'1', d:{a:1n, 42:1n}}
type I9 = {a:'1', d:{}}
//-----------------------
// THE CODE 
type Select<T,I>= {[P in keyof I]: P extends keyof T ?
  (T[P] extends object ? ExclusifyUnionPlus<T[P],I[P]> : T[P]) : never} 
type ExclusifyUnionPlus<T,I>= T extends any ? (I extends Select<T,I> ? T : never):never
//-----------------------
// case specific type aliases
type DI<I>=ExclusifyUnionPlus<T12,I>
// special types for se question https://stackoverflow.com/q/46370222/4376643
type sth = { value: number, data: string } | { value: number, note: string };
type DIsth<I>=ExclusifyUnionPlus<sth,I>
//-----------------------
// THE TESTS - ref=refuse, acc=accept
const sth0:DIsth<{ value: 7, data: 'test' }>={ value: 7, data: 'test' }; // should acc
const sth1:DIsth<{ value: 7, note: 'test' }>={ value: 7, note: 'test' }; // should acc
const sth2:DIsth<{ value: 7, data:'test', note: 'hello' }>={ value:7, data:'test',note:'hello' }; // should ref
type DI0=DI<I0> ; const d0:DI0={} // should ref
type DI1=DI<I1> ; const d1:DI1={a:1,b:1} // T1, should acc
type DI2=DI<I2> ; const d2:DI2={a:1,c:1} // T2, should acc
type DI3=DI<I3> ; const d3:DI3={a:1,b:1,c:1} // should ref
type DI4=DI<I4> ; const d4:DI4={a:1} // should ref
type DI5=DI<I5> ; const d5:DI5={a:'2',c:1}  // T3, should acc
type DI6=DI<I6> ; const d6:DI6={a:'2'}  // T3, should acc
type DI7=DI<I7> ; const d7:DI7={a:1n,42:1n}  // T4, should acc
type DI8=DI<I8> ; const d8:DI8={a:'1',d:{a:1n,42:1n}}  // T5, should acc
type DI9=DI<I9> ; const d9:DI9={a:'1',d:{}}  // should ref
//-------------------
// Comparison with type function NOT using type of intializer
// Code from SE  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370791/4376643
type AllKeys<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;
type Id<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;
type _ExclusifyUnion<T, K extends PropertyKey> =
    T extends unknown ? Id<T & Partial<Record<Exclude<K, keyof T>, never>>> : never;
type ExclusifyUnion<T> = _ExclusifyUnion<T, AllKeys<T>>;
//-------------------
// case specific alias
type SU=ExclusifyUnion<T12>
// tests
const sd0:SU={} // should ref
const sd1:SU={a:1,b:1} // should acc
const sd2:SU={a:1,c:1} // should acc
const sd3:SU={a:1,b:1,c:1} // should ref
const sd4:SU={a:1} // should ref
const sd5:SU={a:'2',c:1}  // should acc
const sd6:SU={a:'2'}  // should acc
const sd7:SU={a:1n,42:1n}  // should acc
const sd8:SU={a:'1',d:{a:1n,42:1n}}  // should acc
const sd9:SU={a:'1',d:{}}  // should ref
// Apparently ExclusifyUnion doesn't handle addtional property speficier in T4
// Also does it handle deep objects?  Have posted message to ExclusifyUnion author, awaiting reply.
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=73&pc=1#code/PTAEGMDoDNNALALogDgZwFwgOYEtHwCuARpOAPYC2wlu4ATuWudIsACoCeKApgMoNcKNrjRpCPNMAAsAJgCc8gOwAoEBHoBDXNhTw6AazSgAYj2KhZABlkBGNcAC0zl67fvnD0OwCaABQBRPhVEbh5vW1AAXlAAb00MADtCSmIeegAaYiSUtPoAXxCw71louITk1PSM8ByqgqLebwBmMviMNER6XETsGoB+OrzC0Kb2aTaE4h0exAzQAG0DHk4Orp7sAF0MabxExBHi9gBWSbXu3vmAEwx2WwAfdllH5sfpQ7HbUpi7x+f2V7jR7HBweMFgry+QJ8UAASQAciYAgAlZEBAAipmRAHkALLeAASATh8Nh7FhAEEADKwgBaKNAjXCsKsbQ+zMiMXatiyGFs7Lh33KfJqfIFsNaXISPOyPNq-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-U8MIKgUIknThfAVgYCxBWxHFi4JaASjXCFYWavWnSalFebzb5i1nitwWhWeG2SIg235NloDqGg8DkIQSZXGB4DgKN24TZ5tgzflBDpnt8WHclqVLWdW07VEAMHctwNpaAYMXTlN1gHdD1PS9b1jZ9BCyD9c0Lf5MPHQkCOuilcOavAybGZdu0EwlR1XGtGCkxk5MJZT1PkJd123fdj3PV1eVWFELFsVYJ7XVj05XNNLEi7ET582jgvtXltii6xsK2JLEAfTL30sRr3K8vyyMRPMqMCxjeWyJrbGyLr0turjLF2yb8pK2ATyW-z6P9XlzT2xKTv626zQ-UHJuynqXvyX7qvQHl0jB9IofjTL0g-Sn3Jx1b6NCy+LHHMHxzpxNVzHD9JftKasdduoAK+yrNtF7ChrB4a5cy4aP0d7XOpPubTfxy3Adt0owdKN3bpKD9k8ehk3r2g33vSM31vj8ULEOsHDoz1cDo-bvtcuhk7rStay++qv3jHBv-uvXl8jB-IB-yD9L+n7qQZD8r1tC2qjVNwXgoxUBQJobozBEigBMvgLyL5uqJDTGpeE2I2zcUii+cssxxK4AAF54XUGAq44RoCMEoKAPgxJ1KoEwCAHSekDLpCMqZcy1BNDWVslYJQ8hbBOSUC5NyioKRJiTAAaRWPudgJ4fiwRAsYQgiQDApRMjA-oJYVitmvBhdIuUXywiuJmWRgEhwKKLIkaA6RQBrhnPNBY4iLGaLLNAGxlY1wOIHE+dCuF6D6OKAAfWKtxUqX5Eh-lAI4sxI4qyMF4PQUIkjOCyM7F2UxwEYlKJUaZdRcIjFtgAGRVkgYgcS6ZkSplkkY4JpD0ziPmC2VxMjkq+JzG0nRvj-FNGCcuUJfFjFlCCW+EJn5+lZlAKIiRUjjE5lykA4B4Z1DEQUqJSi0BqJ0QYmgBMa4OLDN6aM7cglHZeE2ogbZzs0CywwHwXZitzb50Tu9DO8krjfVuZDaUps84Jxtpcq4uMPkezFA835Ad-kRyBV8mOntQUtyFv8rOUKQX-wLmrf5VdkV11hXCzeT9-m9yxYPW+jy-lhyuXPZFVol64x9CSsF+LyWHxuXckmZ8L52hpXaG+uLH6YyZR-LF7KMCKz-ijX5gCwAUhQBAtq+wkyQR6TxMJbpyCSESBtBA4ErgpjAlcK4pTtx0VACgOJ6RQjyV4Osyi1jizjC8KI5gqrJBFmnPAbVurSHDVAGOScaY0AaNAASTQD4TVMHrM9Sgkg0CaGwOERA5BXxcQOWVGBmhCAEFkn1Ey2hSmRTaigBVkAVBAA)

#### Discussion

The code recurses for deep object - `ExclusifyUnionPlus<T,I>` calls `Select` and `Select` then recursively calls `ExclusifyUnionPlus<T[P],I[P]>` when the properties are themselves objects.

Some edge cases are not included, e.g., member functions.

#### Tests

Test cases include

- additional keys
- deep object (only 2-levels though)

## Conclusion

Apart from the requirement to enter the instance twice, the proposed paradigm (adding initializer type to the lhs function) was shown to function correctly for several test cases of detecting excess properties..

We can judge the practical value of adding initializer type to the l.h.s. type function by comparing [`ExclusifyUnion`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370791/4376643) and `ExclusifyUnionPlus` according to these two criteria:

- Ease and clarity:
- Total range of expression:

As for 'ease and clarity' , ExclusifyUnionPlus does seems easier to code and comprehend.  On the other hand, writing the initializer twice is inconvenient. I have submitted [a proposal to Typescript issues](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42997) suggesting that something like

```
const t:SomeTypeDefPlus<TU,I> = {a:1,b:2} as infer literal I
```

would be helpful.

As for 'total range of expression', that is not yet known.

Comment: Can you please clarify the usage of the "instance type" term here? AFAIK, it refers to instances of constructor functions exclusively (maybe you meant initialization?)

Comment: `T4` type causes the original `ExclusifyUnion` to fail because of the index signature, actually, but, frankly, I am a bit at a loss on why would it do that. Off-note: I wonder, where did you find such a peculiar transcription of my name? :)

Comment: @OlegValter `ExclusifyUnion` uses a sub function `AllKeys', which *should* be the union of all keys over all objects, e.g., `'a'|'b'.  However when one of the objects contains an index signature  `[key:string]:<>`,, that dominates the `AllKeys` value and the value becomes `string | number`. Why is `number` included you ask?  That's Typescript . Then the exclusive-or for any object X of the union *not* containing the index signature  `[key:string]:<>` becomes  `X & { [key:string]:undefined, {key:number]:undefined}`, which is effectively `never`.

Comment: I do understand *where* this fails, what I do not get is a grasp on is why would the resulting error state `Property 'd' is missing in type but required in type 'T5'` frankly speaking. It seems like all members are checked for assignability, fail, and then the last one, `T5` is used for the final check resulting in a missing property. Having an index signature of type `never` does not prevent assignment of known properties, e.g.: `type t = { [ x: number ] : never; a: 5 }; const t:t = { a: 5 }; //OK`