# typescript type function - Can you amend this function for strict excess property checking so that it will handle a signature index?

Tags: typescript

This [typescript type definition function (provided by @jcalz)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370791/4376643) enables strict excess property checking in assignment of a literal object initializer to a union of types, *in some cases*.

*Note: The definition of **strict excess property checking in assignment of a literal object initializer to a union** in this question is described in detail below*

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;
type Id<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;
type _ExclusifyUnion<T, K extends PropertyKey> =
    T extends unknown ? Id<T & Partial<Record<Exclude<K, keyof T>, never>>> : never;
type ExclusifyUnion<T> = _ExclusifyUnion<T, AllKeys<T>>;
```

It works in correctly in 1-level objects without index signatures, for example

```
type sth = { value: number, data: string } | { value: number, note: string };
const a: sth = { value: 7, data: 'test' };
const b: sth = { value: 7, note: 'hello' };
const c: sth = { value: 7, data: 'test', note: 'hello' };
type xsth = ExclusifyUnion<sth>;
/* type xsth = {
    value: number;
    data: string;
    note?: undefined;
} | {
    value: number;
    note: string;
    data?: undefined;
} */
const z: xsth = { value: 7, data: 'test', note: 'hello' }; // error!
/* Type '{ value: number; data: string; note: string; }' is not assignable to
 type '{ value: number; data: string; note?: undefined; } | 
 { value: number; note: string; data?: undefined; }' */
```

However it fails when a type with an index signature key is included.

```
type sthA = { value: string, data: string };
type sthB = { value: number,  [key:string]:number };
type sth = sthA | sthB;

type EU = ExclusifyUnion<sth>

const t1:EU = {value:'a', data:'b'} // error
/*
const t1: {
    [x: string]: undefined;
    [x: number]: undefined;
    value: string;
    data: string;
} | {
    [x: string]: number;
    value: number;
}
Type '{ value: string; data: string; }' is not assignable to type 
'{ [x: string]: undefined; [x: number]: undefined; value: string; data: string; } 
| { [x: string]: number; value: number; }'.
  Type '{ value: string; data: string; }' is not assignable to type 
'{ [x: string]: number; value: number; }'.
    Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
*/
type AK = AllKeys<sth>  /* string | number */
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA0hEBnAPAFQHxQLxSZQQAewEAdgCapQCuFA1hQPYDuFUA-FIyiwDNCUAFxQKEAG4QATgG4AUKEhQAklSy4CRUuWq0AlhQGyoAVW5QA3lADaiKEd78hZgLpiz9t1AC+o8SlZRWVoAH0AURIAYzg6VAMBEDMKAxYKLAAaKAddShooAAUZFkgZUGQQLQUoWuE8-XomVg5LdSwoADIigENygx64dAAlCGiWGQ0o2LoqCHREbL4QQUJsbIlpGWwdgM3gpXBoabiEpJS0jJx8KEiY08Tk1PSs2ARKjBxsRUOVVGAABYwG42SSDOgQMT-GRGADm2SoPWAPShwBhFFhfhCRyg-wBACEQVAwXFIeI6ABbABGsmydmWImhcI8FEpNJkWN+0DxNzxwIAPrjAfifqEoBELAQTvFHhcXnjsAoFOMKP8oMAAIwiCUgkkQkQAch6BoRSJRBqpBt8SoA9AAqZXpNWasRWGp1WwkVHo2EeJpzARGCBURR1Oxe8nU2R+hgBoMh921PVkpkY0N1RHI71wxT+QVusOe7MYv2sqPyRPE8Fksvs3MKTA4g2g6vF2FyKCZlFCn0d3wGxy0VjAKA9VAJWEUHpUuDQYAsdVNmxFnvMsSxiCBiQh8NiWvR9fUTfxjvJtsdrvnvxQfO71clvds4JV0mP8t9g0AOndjZUzZf+r3u2nZmle-aDuILAjmOE5TjOc4LmK-4rqmvpvnWAE1k+8h+F+la-hAtCrGAJRlKAUAGsmA59NARjjBSYBIgY8HfmGtQERRqEDgYQ5QaO44GJO06zuqiFNvuMhfgAFAATAAzDJMkAJQKHaNpcrADgEPASAoBgCq1PaQE3pG7JQGpChAA)

Can you amend it to handle types of objects with a signature index?

---

### This questions definition of *strict excess property checking in assignment of a literal object initializer to a union*

#### "(ordinary) assigment" vs "strict assignment"

Typescript has two kinds of structural assignability, i.e., rules for valid assignments to types of objects with properties.

The first kind, which is the [general rule](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-New-Handbook/blob/master/reference/Assignability.md#structural-assignability), allows excess properties to be assigned, even though they are not defined in the type:

```
type T = { a:number, b:number };
let source= { a:1, b:2, c:3 };
let target:T= source           // no error
```

The second kind is an exception to the general rule in the case of [literal object declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) to a constant, i.e., a `const` declaration.  In this case excess properties are *not* allowed.  In the scope of this discussion we will call this *strict-assignment*:

```
type T = { a:number, b:number };
const target:T= { a:1, b:2, c:3 }; // error: 
/* Type '{ a: number; b: number; c: number; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, 
and 'c' does not exist in type 'T'.(2322)*/
```

#### Assignment of literal object initializers to a union of types

In Typescript a new type may be composed as the "union of types",  and the notation is

```
type TU= T1|T2|T3
```

The formal Typescript *definition* of the union type() is described in [Typescript Release notes 3.5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html):

> In TypeScript 3.5, the type-checker at least verifies that all the provided properties belong to some union member and have the appropriate type, meaning that the sample above correctly issues an error.  Note that partial overlap is still permitted as long as the property types are valid.

That is, by definition, the correct definition for *Union* in Typescript, and saying otherwise would be incorrect.

#### A more constrained use case - *strict union*

Suppose a programmer has a use case which requires defining a Typescript-union-similar-but-not-same entity with the following psuedo-code definition:

> *If*
> . type TU = StrictUnion(T1,...,Ti,...,TN)
> *then*
> . const t:TU = x
> *is a valid assignment if and only if*
> . const t:Ti = x
> *is a valid strict-assignment for at least one StrictUnion argument Ti*

An obvious use-case for a strict-union is to disallow accidentally mixing properties from different object types.  For this reason, within the scope of this SE question
.    **strict excess property checking in assignment of a literal object initializer to a union**
is defined as being synonymous with
.    **strict-union**
the latter being much shorter.

(Note: another use-case for the same strict-union is discussed in the appendix below)

In addition, it is preferred, but not required that `StrictUnion(T1,..,TN)`
can be written as a function of the Typescript union, i.e. `StrictUnion(T1|..|TN)`, (which `ExclusifyUnion(..)` does).

#### Back to the original question.

The question asked in this post is how to amend `ExclusifyUnion` so that it handles the case of a type with an index signature property to give a result that is compatible with the above definition of *strict-union*.

The question also artificially restricts the domain of types and object initializers under consideration to be only 1-level deep, and not to be an edge case such a function with properties.  However it must include the case of objects with an [*index signature*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).

It should be noted that Typescript's Union *does* extend to deeper objects and arrays - for example

```
type T1 = {a:number,b:number} 
type T2 = {a:number, c: (T1|T2)[]}
const t:T1|T2 = {a:1,c:[{a:1,b:2,c:[{a:1,b:2}]}]} // legal Typescript
```

is allowed.  Correspondingly *strict-union* must extend to cover the same domain, and would reject that assignment because `t.c` is strict-assignable to neither `T1` nor `T2`.  That case would be a separate question, unless the answer to this question happens to extend to include it.

#### Appendix:

**Another use case for a strict-union - *JSONSchema* compatibility**

Another use case for a strict-union is to define a type that can be implemented in [*JSONSchema*](https://json-schema.org/specification.html) without defining any custom keywords. The downside of defining custom keywords is discussed [in the AJV manual](https://ajv.js.org/docs/validation.html#user-defined-keywords):

> The concerns you have to be aware of when extending JSON Schema standard with additional keywords are the portability and understanding of your schemas. You will have to support these keywords on other platforms and to properly document them so that everybody can understand and use your schemas.

Comment: Could you explain what type you expect `EU` to be above?  That would help me figure out the type function to produce it.  For example, it might be that the best thing you can do is ignore index signatures when looking at the properties from other members of the union, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mL9aAW).  That makes `EU` into `{ value: string; data: string;} | { [x: string]: number;  value: number;  data?: undefined }`... but that's a weird type and I'm not sure it fits whatever use case you have in mind.

Comment: @jcalz - I have added what I hope is a deep and full answer to your question.  Not only a "what" but also a "why".  There is a definition for `StrictUnion` (what), and example use cases (why).

Comment: Before I can think about amending `ExclusifyUnion` to turn `sthA | sthB` into the proper `EU`, I would have to know what the proper `EU` is specifically.  You have written out a set of criteria for judging that type, but not what that type would be specifically.  If you know it, please tell me specifically what it is so I can think about working on changing `ExclusifyUnion`. If you don't know it, then there may not even be any way to make `ExclusifyUnion` work the way you want and one might need to resort to the "generic constraint" version which takes more type parameters.

Comment: I am not at all certain that a function that can be written in current Typescript language with the parameters T1,..,TN (or T1|..|TN) exists to express the criteria I described for strict-union.  That is why the question asks **"Can you amend it to handle types of objects with a signature index?"**.  One correct answer to the question would be a proof that it cannot be so amended.

Comment: @jcalz - by the way, if you have an extended comment which is illuminating and adds understanding of the general issue, but doesn't answer the question, I'll upvote if you post it - even if I can't select it as the correct answer to the headline question.

Comment: @jcalz - Coincidentally "one might need to resort to the "generic constraint" version which takes more type parameters" fits [the description of the solution with `ExclusifyUnionPlus`I posted underneath your original description of `ExclusifyUnion`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66407294/4376643).  The extra type parameter is the generic type parameter of the initializer on the r.h.s.  Did you get a chance to  understand it yet?  That solution computes `StrictUnion` perfectly.  But adding the initializer type param is a nuisance. A fixed 'ExclusifyUnion` would be better - hence this question.

Comment: Yeah, I understand now, and I agree that it's a nuisance and really depends on the use case what the right approach is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR This is impossible.

---

We want to come up with a version of `ExclusifyUnion` that will transform a regular union `A | B` into a different type that behaves like a "strict" version of `A | B`, **even in cases where either `A` or `B` has a string index signature**.

By "strict" I mean that if an object literal `{...}` cannot be assigned directly to a variable of type `A` (due to [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)) and if it cannot be assigned directly to a variable of type `B`, then it also cannot be assigned directly to a variable of type `ExclusifyUnion<A | B>`.  And conversely, if an object literal `{...}` *can* be assigned to a variable of type `ExclusifyUnion<A | B>`, then it must be assignable to either a variable of type `A` or to a variable of type `B`.

This is not currently possible in TypeScript.

Without direct support for *exact types* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), there's just no way to express `ExclusifyUnion<A | B>` as a specific type in general.

---

To demonstrate that this is not possible in general, let's look at a particular case:

```
type A = { a: 0 };
type B = { [k: string]: 1; }
```

Here, `A` has a known key `a` of type `0` and that's it.  An "exclusive"/"exact"/"strict" version of `A` would only allow a value like `{a: 0}` to be assigned.  Meanwhile, `B` is allowed to have any keys whatsoever, as long as every property value is of type `1`.

Let's make sure that the simple union `A | B` does not behave strictly first:

```
type U = A | B;

const goodA: A = { a: 0 }; // ✔
const goodUnionA: U = { a: 0 }; // ✔

const goodB: B = { a: 1, c: 1 }; // ✔
const goodUnionB: U = { a: 1, c: 1 }; // ✔

const badA: A = { a: 0, c: 1 } // c is excess ✔
const badB: B = { a: 0, c: 1 } // a is wrong type ✔
const badUnionAB: U = { a: 0, c: 1 }; // ❌

const badA1: A = { a: 0, c: 0 }; // c is excess ✔
const badB1: B = { a: 0, c: 0 }; // a and c are wrong type ✔
const badUnionAB1: U = { a: 0, c: 0 }; // c is wrong type  ✔
```

In these examples, `badUnionAB` is a problem.  The object literal `{a: 0, c: 1}` is not "strictly" assignable to `A` because `c` is an extra property.  It is not assignable to `B` because `a` is the wrong type.  But it *is* assignable to `A | B`.

So `A | B` is not sufficient, and we must try to change it into some stricter union of the form `StrictA | StrictB` where `StrictA` and `StrictB` allow exactly the same object literals as `A` and `B` respectively.

---

We cannot touch `B` at all.  We do not want to, for example, make `StrictB` prohibit the `a` key, as this does not do what we want.  We want `{ a: 1 }` to be assignable to `StrictB`.  Once a type has an index signature, the "strict" version of it cannot be modified so as to prohibit anything further.  So we are stuck with

```
type StrictB = B;
```

---

Let's try to make `StrictA`.  With no support for exact types, one cannot say "`StrictA` only has an `a` property and no others".  And it is fruitless to attempt to list out all possible excess keys of `A`.  It would look something like

```
type StrictA = { a: 0, b?: never, c?: never, d?: never, e?: never, /*...∞*/ };
```

but of course there is no way to enumerate all possible keys.  Since a valid value of type `B` might have any key at all (e.g., `"kdfsf39jsdc"`), any finite set of keys we choose will have holes.  So we must give up on that.

---

The only other option is to give `StrictA` its own index signature.  Something like:

```
type StrictA = { a: 0, [k: string]: undefined }; // error!
// Property 'a' of type '0' is not assignable to string index type 'undefined'
```

is invalid.  It doesn't mean "`a` is `0` and everything else is `undefined`".  It means "`a` is `0` and *everything* is `undefined`", which is a contradiction.  In order to even have the index signature compile you need to make its property type at least as wide as the union of all known property types:

```
type StrictA = { a: 0, [k: string]: 0 };
```

But of course, this is not what we want either.  It leads to the following behavior:

```
type U = StrictA | StrictB;
const badUnionAB: U = { a: 0, c: 1 }; // 0 is not assignable to 1 ✔
const badUnionAB1: U = { a: 0, c: 0 }; // ❌
```

While `badUnionAB` is now correctly prohibited, `badUnionAB1` is erroneously allowed, even though it is not directly "strictly" assignable to either `A` or `B`.

---

So we're stuck.  There is simply no way to make a union "strict" in this way if any of the union constituents have a string index signature.

In the case where you need something like this behavior, you'd have to give up on `ExclusifyUnion<A | B>` being a specific type, and instead would need to make it a generic constraint on a *candidate* type like `ExclusifyUnion<A | B, T>` which would evaluate to (say) `T` if `T` is "strictly" assignable to `A | B`, and (say) `never` otherwise.  (This is the same general approach as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66407294/4376643) by @CraigHicks)

Then you could make helper functions like `asStrictUnion()` instead of using type annotations:

```
type ExclusifyUnion<U, T extends U> = U extends any ?
  [T] extends [U] ? keyof T extends keyof U ? T : never : never : never;
const asStrictUnion = <U>() => <T extends U>(t: ExclusifyUnion<U, T>) => t;

type A = { a: 0 };
type B = { [k: string]: 1; }

const asStrictU = asStrictUnion<A | B>();

const goodUnionA = asStrictU({ a: 0 }); // okay ✔
const goodUnionB = asStrictU({ a: 1, c: 1 }); // okay ✔
const badUnionAB = asStrictU({ a: 0, c: 1 }); // error ✔
const badUnionAB1 = asStrictU({ a: 0, c: 0 }); // error ✔
```

That works, but it's a fairly complicated approach which requires developers to remember to call a helper function.  Or you could move this validation to whatever function accepts object literals from developers.  But whether or not this is worth the effort is not clear to me.  Especially because the lack of exact type support in TypeScript means that it's still possible for something to fall through the cracks here:

```
const z = { a: 0, z: 25 } as const; // no error
const a: A = z; // no error
asStrictU(a); // no error
```

It's up to you I guess.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkqJLAsgHID2wAygC4BOAlvAwKrAu16HHEGATxjIAgkgC8eJCABcSAAxIAvgG4iA4aKQAhKTIDaAawVRmLYAHMAugoCMa1ZsEjkHAxIA+ejS6TwtOZIVtTUACZiChLSuLIKyupIAPTJSIAo5P6BwMGhEVw8wFFIHrHxSqpOqRn8Atm5YeG6Cvpl8kj2ADQBDpUpaZkCAUEMIY0FtM0lBnHtXT0dfdWZWSNIAEYgkdEz5Yrd8L0q-QFILFBIEAAeiFAXg3Vrm00tu+37C-aqJyBnFwDuTFoViQ2mQD2I9VGzwmRSmpRk7wORyqaUAMuS1SFPLZiew7NoJZEVJLVeB-S43aD3VY5aFbXR4vRvQkLRKo2SyYDhU4gJjIQHA0FuGpDKEbLawsQMhQI2Ysw7E9lk85IAXWIU6GqaFS1UjQOCIJCMVjsSUMBgQMAwUYETEa8TMxX+MFMsomMwWax2DpOHX+aou41sBitIymJDmVhehxOdrACAANwgTGcQwDwqD7BiiJZ6wA-Ap40mmAcCyRE8nuuEy0XK5caxWSykAFQAOnbzbSx1JIGAAHJRhBgABXMCyDAYJAwah3FjrDDIYwQIRQf1pQMWLOOj7uiOe2wKYdciAAM0sEG5JLSwGoo1+CcwLG5YLtG5NDGzcqU3V3kcsB6dIY32DUNdA0IDhQRTMPyQHxoLAu0xTybYkE-PYlgGGkGnybhaGKWV0KvLVRTWZCplDL95gVL4iIhYZaTGHDCnhR0qJRE4VhIhjnmKNCkU+b5SXJa5bmpLjgmecjtyJGifnJNUQRdOixRhXC4RlaSBKI5QVRvO9ZysUB52QBhqEWTjHm4nFGT4+UEgw04VREqkRUsiT6UZCi9iJNk5N7bkyV5fkgXVJSsLpcJJWlaYCW-VkHIxWodT9F0AFEbgwYcoBYE8hFhAAeDhugAFQpC0uQuDgAD4DA8a5yvCC5eyEJA800QxipsMqh0apBDA4Lq8yQJchGoE8kFK+qeouEaxumIbSsLRskCW4sVvLYsNDFEAoGg2EDEKqqAAoAEopBq-LJquBrKuOhgFHS+BMuy3KCqKiaqrOyQaoYPwXVsp0XS839929RxnHwbbds3TgDB2va1Py7w9GOk6-CQ8Y1OzeGYY4I6v0SNGTmoYwQBazIMaYyY4eh988comTVCJ6oSbJmoVIlLHQxxun8e8rTmbSZMgRTCnsUirmvmkHng3p-mFUJ9lheoUXCDFHBYo+LAFAAJgAVm+Hb6PMdkb0uJgRchtZ2mzLBTbM5WmHwGXTSOkBBZIB2LZV-AgA)

Comment: The proof is good.  Your `ExclusifyUnion<U,T extends U>` is an abridged version of the`ExclusifyUnionPlus` which [I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66407294/4376643) under your original `ExclusifyUnion` and I think you ought to provide attribution for that.  The function to hold it `asStrictUnion()`, is a great idea.  Thanks.

Comment: Attribution added.