# Property AAA does not exist on type BBB error from tsc (typescript)

Tags: typescript

I am quite curious why `const { liveCount } = customer` is not working at the following. tsc throws `Property 'liveCount' does not exist on type 'Customer'.(2339)` error. What's the difference between them and what do I need to learn more for understanding this?

TS 4.2.3 is used.

```
type Thing = {
    name: string
}

type Person = Thing & {
    age: number
    address?: string
}

type Cat = Thing & {
    liveCount: number
}

type Customer = Person | Cat

function deliverTo(customer: Customer) {
    // Case A: OK
    const { liveCount } = { ...customer }

    // Case B: Not OK
    // const { liveCount } = customer
}
```

Comment: Wow, I expected the "not OK" result; you can only safely access properties that are known to exist in all members of a union, and `liveCount` may or may not appear in type `Person`.  But I didn't realize that if you destructure a spead union it would magically not complain; not sure if that's a bug or intentional.

Comment: Looks like the behavior where `const { liveCount } = { ... customer }` results in `number | undefined` was introduced in [microsoft/TypeScript#31711](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31711) to support things like `{ foo } = bar || {}`.  I'm guessing this is unintentional but I won't know unless I file an issue and hear back.  If I get around to answering this question I'd probably suggest something like `const { liveCount } = customer as Partial<Cat>;` (see [here](https://tsplay.dev/WJ9Rlm)) which at least is a known way of dealing with things.

Comment: Okay I filed [microsoft/TypeScript#43174](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43174) and I'll come back here with updates if/when they arrive.

Comment: Well, [microsoft/TypeScript#43174](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43174) is apparently considered a bug, so I will write up an answer which says not to rely on `const { liveCount } = { ...customer }` because it's not supposed to be happening that way.  When I get a chance, that is

Answer (score 2):

### You may only access properties which exist on all members of a union.

The following behavior is as expected:

```
declare const customer: Customer;
const livecount = customer.liveCount; // error!
// Property 'liveCount' does not exist on type 'Customer'
//  Property 'liveCount' does not exist on type 'Person'.
```

TypeScript will only allow you to access a property key on a value of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) if that property key is known to exist in *every member of the union*.  See ["Working with union types" in the TS Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types).  In the above, you cannot access `customer.liveCount` because no property key named `"liveCount"` is known to exist on a value of type `Person`.

So for all the code in your example, we should expect an error that `liveCount` does not exist on `Customer`.  The fact that your "Case A", `const { liveCount } = { ...customer }` happens not to result in an error, is apparently a bug in TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#43174](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43174), which I filed about this very question.  At least as of today (Mar 10 2021) that bug is slated to be fixed for [TypeScript 4.3.1](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/milestone/138), so I would not be surprised if in the near-ish future, you would see the same error in both "Case A" and "Case B".

---

If you are thinking "but wait, isn't `customer.liveCount` of type `number | undefined`?", it's probably because your thought process has proceeded like this:

- `customer` is either a `Cat` or a `Person`. ✔
- If `customer` is a `Cat`, then `customer.liveCount` will be a `number`. ✔
- If `customer` is a `Person`, then `customer` will not have a `liveCount` property at all. ❌
- If `customer` does not have a `liveCount` property, then `customer.liveCount` will be `undefined`. ✔
- So `customer.liveCount` will either be `number` or `undefined`. ❌
- So `customer.liveCount` has type `number | undefined`. ❌

The statements marked with check marks (✔) are correct, but the ones marked with cross marks (❌) are incorrect for TypeScript.  Let's focus on where this first goes astray:

- If `customer` is a `Person`, then `customer` will not have a `liveCount` property at all. ❌

This is not true.  Object types in TypeScript are *open* or *extendible*.  You can add properties to an object type without violating the original type.  This is a good thing because it enables interface and class extensions to form type hierarchies.  If `bar` is of type `Bar`, and `Bar extends Foo`, then `bar` is also of type `Foo`.  But it has some annoying implications also, like we see here.

A value of type `Person` is known to have: a property named `name` whose type is `string`; a property named `age` whose type is `number`; and optionally a property named `address` which, if present, has type `string | undefined`.  But a value of type `Person` is *not known to lack any other properties*.  Specifically, it is not known to lack a property named `liveCount`.  And there is no constraint on what kind of property might exist at that key.  It might be `number`, or `string`, or `Date`, or anything.  The only safe thing to say is that it is something like `unknown` or `any`.  So we have to amend our logic to something like this:

- `customer` is either a `Cat` or a `Person`. ✔
- If `customer` is a `Cat`, then `customer.liveCount` will be a `number`. ✔
- If `customer` is a `Person`, then `customer` may have a `liveCount` property whose type could be anything at all. ✔
- So then `customer.liveCount` will be `any`. ✔
- So `customer.liveCount` will either be `number` or `any`. ✔
- So `customer.liveCount` has type `any`, and it's probably a mistake to access the `liveCount` property on `customer` in the first place. ✔

---

Case in point:

```
const undeadCount = {
  name: "Dracula",
  age: 1000,
  liveCount: false
}
const weirdPerson: Person = undeadCount;
deliverTo(undeadCount);
```

Here, `undeadCount` is a valid `Person` because it has a `name` and an `age` of the right type.  It has a `liveCount` property of type `boolean`, but this does not disqualify it from being a `Person`, as demonstrated by the fact that I can assign it to a variable `weirdPerson` of type `Person` without error.  And so I can also call `deliverTo(undeadCount)`.  If the implementation of `deliverTo()` expects `customer.liveCount` to be a `number` if it's not `undefined`, some very weird things could happen.  You could even have runtime errors (e.g., `customer.liveCount?.toFixed(2)`).

---

Note that things would be different if you had a way of saying "a `Customer` is either *exactly* a `Cat` or *exactly* a `Person`, where in neither case could there be extra properties I don't know about".  But TypeScript does not currently have support for so-called "exact types", and there is a longstanding feature request to implement them at [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  So, in the absence of a reasonable way to say `Exact<Cat> | Exact<Person>`, what can be done?

---

### How to proceed instead

There are different workarounds.  One thing you can do is just [*assert*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that your `customer` has an optional `liveCount` property which is either `number` or `undefined`.  Sure, it's *technically possible* that someone might pass in an `undeadCount`, but you really don't expect for that to happen and you don't want to waste your time worrying about such an unlikely event.  One such assertion is this:

```
const { liveCount } = customer as Partial<Cat>; // okay
```

Here we are saying that `customer` will either have the properties from `Cat` or they will be missing and therefore `undefined`.  This includes `liveCount`.

A more elaborate version of this workaround is to say that `customer` is an `ExclusiveCustomer` defined like this:

```
type ExclusiveCustomer = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address?: string | undefined;
    liveCount?: undefined;
} | {
    name: string;
    liveCount: number;
    age?: undefined;
    address?: undefined;
};
```

You're explicitly saying that if `customer` is a `Person` then it lacks any `Cat`-specific properties, and vice versa.  You can even get the compiler to compute `ExclusiveCustomer` from the `Customer` type via a type function like `ExclusiveUnion`, from [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370222/typescript-a-b-allows-combination-of-both):

```
const { liveCount } = customer as ExclusiveUnion<Customer>;
```

---

Another workaround is to use [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) to get `customer` to be considered either a `Person` or a `Cat` by checking things about it.  The easiest way to do this is, on the face of it, completely at odds with the whole first part of this answer about open types:

```
const liveCount = "liveCount" in customer ? customer.liveCount : undefined;
// const liveCount: number | undefined
```

Whaaaat?  Yes, you can use the `in` operator as a type guard which narrows `customer` from `Customer` to `Cat` (if `"liveCount" in customer` is true) or `Person` (if it is false).  This type guard was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#15256](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15256) and the [relevant comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15256#discussion_r154843152) in there implies that people need some way to do this and this is sufficiently indicative of intent that we will let them do it, even if it is technically unsafe:

> The reality is that most unions are already correctly disjointed and don't alias enough to manifest the problem. Someone writing an `in` test is not going to write a "better" check; all that really happens in practice is that people add type assertions or move the code to an equally-unsound user-defined type predicate. On net I don't think this is any worse than the status quo (and is better because it induces fewer user-defined type predicates, which are error-prone if written using `in` due to a lack of typo-checking).

That leads to the next way to do this: write your own type guard via a [function that returns a type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

```
function isCat(x: any): x is Cat {
  return x && typeof x.liveCount === "number" && typeof x.name === "string"; 
}

const liveCount = isCat(customer) ? customer.liveCount : undefined;
// const liveCount: number | undefined
```

By writing `isCat()` that returns `x is Cat`, we are telling the compiler it is allowed to use `isCat()` to narrow something to either `Cat` (if true) or something that is not a `Cat` (if false).  With you call `isCat(customer)` that means either `Cat` or `Person`.  I happened to implement `isCat()` in the most type-safe way possible, but I took on that responsibility and the compiler abdicated it.  One could just as easily write

```
function isCat(x: any): x is Cat {
  return Math.random() < 0.5 // 
}
```

and the compiler would be none the wiser. So there you go.

---

### RECAP

- You may only safely access properties which exist on *all* members of a union.
- The behavior you saw where it works is a bug.  Don't count on it.
- Weird bad things can happen if you make the assumption that types in TypeScript are exact.
- But they probably won't happen so you can use type assertions to make the compiler stop complaining.
- Or you could use type narrowing to make the compiler stop complaining, with varying degrees of safety.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwHYHMoF4oG8BQUpICGAthAFxQDOwATsijgL446iRQAKENlA9khliJUUAGTY8UQinIEArsQBG3SYQAmamhEqUA-BWp1UTFm2gBhQsEHx6YifgA2CAG4RzvOUmAUkC5TQmrOAWctS8pDSCXDz8UAA+UJbALABmXgDGwAhxahDObjQwvAAUGWHAEdwU5hVVNACUDlAZ-NRQBe6e3oLl4ZEAdJ0eXsAA3FAA9JNQ3DS8NACEktOc85A0oFAA5MPdwNtQarzaBLzWEAAeCO1xZju1-dzbKzNrvBtbu65do4fHpyQ51m11uAnu2xifCQ2wGLHwuHw+FaSHaWA6PxGPUYgnRA3xfUqkSgONWijkKAANFQINA4MBgGBKGRpigEMA4HJFANWsRJsQEBl5nxUsBJjAQgBlIUIMBim6UOTaSYAFgAzABGADsKskTkx+10A0qADEEJcIGoSgAmBpjSTMSSIpEotEYtxY6w4zCE+pSSicQibBCERwAHmSAD57fhHQi9S02tZ0XtRiTenViYQAwBRS4ZRxhH4AVSQOSQEcz3GjDpYToTrusqZ6mAARM3gK2oMgWlWorpe08aEMDWmKF48qlkJaY0jVo33b9vL5-NwElAJxAp0hLbX60jE6im6OW93KMkyn2mgPfYMO1Bx0hJ9O1LP8POk4vPSulGvEpvt13WM60ddIkCycszwvS4KEIJAQAaChLjPJIrGaLRgDkGgBGQ0RxDMXhUigS4Rw9fYMHQNs-F-GguzwqACKIkiiFICi20MehW3tR0cDAiC4huAAhdRoNg+DEOIlDknQiBMOwqAAFkrDgAYaDg45iBKJowygAAGAYAFYghwBdNxE8jMGdFjZFbAARNTykcQhW0pVQZAoDVdK81z9TI0YKFSUNKAgEwFwAdwgBAaDUKF+AoWKBEwMy1E9e08k6IpSmSz07VMEIoDzAsizcUtyzDGBqQAaRBYAICfAMOHWbhQEqiAQAwSQYBquq1ADOD2oHABrNrCNgB8CAgQpIw6-AuquWr6qkeCoAHEouvEdEAG0OG7ARCsLPIw0q6lhpAUaYEjABdfQJsKEkmnmnrKEkZBUjXAB5FbsCgbbdqgU7Rvey6KHe7bLvTXxJrXSHCntYJ2H24r3D7QREcoEsy34SshxrSYACoGPytHMRRyyE2sgxaHoN8pHc+QaJp9RNG0PRKaMNB-yfLcXxpjsboAnmmHXZ18ApqgqdQXmTx8emAkZmR+a5wDXwTJmtB0RXnx3FWcTxyYgA)

Comment: This is a very well written answer which deserves more upvotes!  It also answers MY question about why I can't do `const file: File | Blob; const fileName = file.name || "fake name"`. I ended up with a ternary using 'in'.