# Typescript - object OR

Tags: typescript

I'd like to have a type that says:

*If there's property `container` present, also expect property `a`. If there's `item` property present, also expect property `b`. `container` and `item` cannot exist both at the same time.*

The code I'd assume would look as follows, but it doesn't seem to do the above.

```
type A = { container: true; a: string } | { item: true; b: number };
```

How do I build such a type?

---

`null | string` seems to mean `null OR string`, but `SomeObject | AnotherObject` seems to mean `all properties present BOTH in SomeObject and AnotherObject`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript a | b allows combination of both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370222/typescript-a-b-allows-combination-of-both)

Comment: ^ That's only part of the answer - first, you need to define a XOR-like type that either has `container` or `item`, but not both and not none. Then, add a conditional type that, depending on which property is present, intersects the resulting type with either `{ a:string }` or `{ b: number }`. You could also use a discriminated union, but this definition lacks a discriminant property

Answer (score 1):

This may seem hacky, but basically creates an XOR. So if you were to add either `item` or `b` to the variable `myVar`, you would get a typescript error.

```
type ExampleType =
  | { container: true; a: string; item?: never; b?: never }
  | { item: true; b: number; container?: never; a?: never }

// Adding item or b to the below type, will cause a ts error
const myVar: ExampleType = { container: true, a: 'z' }
```

So say if the container key is provided, it will expect the key value for a to be present, and will error if item or b were passed.