# Typescript Column Definitions

Tags: typescript

I would like to have a column definition map of all possible column names that are derived from different model types that are pre-defined. How can I get proper typings in the following?:

```js
export type User = {
  id: number;
  admin: boolean;
  email: string;
};

export type Book = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  author: string;
  userId: number;
};

export type UserUID = {
  id: string;
  admin: boolean;
  email: string;
};

type DataRow = User & Book & UserUID;

export interface ColumnDefinition<F extends keyof DataRow = keyof DataRow> {
  valueFormatter?: (value: DataRow[F]) => string;
}

type ColumnDefinitionMap = {
  [key in keyof DataRow]: ColumnDefinition<key>;
};

const columnDefinitions: ColumnDefinitionMap = {
  admin: {
    // typed correctly
    valueFormatter: (value) => (value === true ? 'Admin' : 'User'),
  },
  id: {
    // should be number | string via models from above
    // currently is "never"
    valueFormatter: (value) => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.toString(),
  },
};
```

Switching the `DataRow` to a Union causes issues as well since it only gives me the `id` column as that is the only common one between the three models.

Wondering if I'm missing something obvious or if there is a better way to approach this from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you ever find yourself with some object which is a `User` *and* a `Book` *and* as `UserId`, you don't want to use an intersection.  The right data type is indeed the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of those types:

```
type DataRow = User | Book | UserUID;
```

Of course, as you noticed, you can't simply index into a union-typed object with a key that exists only in some but not all of the members of the union.  Object types like interfaces are *open* and are allowed to have properties not known to the compiler; for example, the `author` property of a value of type `User` *is not guaranteed* to be missing.  It could be `any` value whatsoever.

---

There are two (related) approaches I can imagine to dealing with such a type.

One way to avoid "unexpected" `any` properties entirely is to use a type like `ExclusifyUnion` as explained in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370222/typescript-a-b-allows-combination-of-both), where any unexpected properties from other members of the union are explicitly marked as missing in each member of the union, and therefore `undefined` if you read them:

```
type DataRow = ExclusifyUnion<User | Book | UserUID>;
/* type DataRow = {
id: number;
admin: boolean;
email: string;
title?: undefined;
author?: undefined;
userId?: undefined;
} | {
id: number;
title: string;
author: string;
userId: number;
admin?: undefined;
email?: undefined;
} | {
id: string;
admin: boolean;
email: string;
title?: undefined;
author?: undefined;
userId?: undefined;
} */
```

You can see that now each member of the union explicitly mentions each property key, but in many of them the properties are optional-and-`undefined`.

With this type, the rest of your code mostly goes through without a problem, except that any column that does not appear in all models will have a possibly `undefined` type you have to deal with:

```
const columnDefinitions: ColumnDefinitionMap = {
  admin: {
    valueFormatter: (value) => (value === true ? 'Admin' : 'User'),
    // (parameter) value: boolean | undefined
  },
  id: {
    valueFormatter: (value) => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.toString(),
    // (parameter) value: string | number
  },
};
```

So while the `value` in `id`'s `valueFormatter` is of type `string | number`, the corresponding type for `admin` is `boolean | undefined`, because for all the compiler knows you will be trying to process the `admin` field of a `Book`.  If you need to fix that, you can change the type of `value` from `DataRow[K]` to `Exclude<DataRow[K], undefined>` using [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion).

---

The other approach is to just keep the original union, but use type functions to represent "a key from any member of the union" and "the type you get by indexing into an object of a union type with a key, if you ignore the members of the union that are not known to have that key":

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
type Idx<T, K> = T extends any ? K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never : never;
```

These are [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) which break unions up into individual members and then process them.

Then your types become this:

```
export interface ColumnDefinition<K extends AllKeys<DataRow>> {
  valueFormatter?: (value: Idx<DataRow, K>) => string;
}

type ColumnDefinitionMap = {
  [K in AllKeys<DataRow>]?: ColumnDefinition<K>; // making it partial
};
```

And now your code should also work as expected:

```
const columnDefinitions: ColumnDefinitionMap = {
  admin: {
    valueFormatter: (value) => (value === true ? 'Admin' : 'User'),
    // (parameter) value: boolean
  },
  id: {
    valueFormatter: (value) => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.toString(),
    // (parameter) value: string | number
  },
};
```

---

I'm not sure which of those, if any, best suits your needs. But no matter what you do, you're going to want to be dealing with a union of some kind, not an intersection.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkgC4CeMyAqlBAE5IC8eRxSAlgCYBcSwArmABG9ANytiITmHbBeQgPYKMEEMHFskEMCHYZeUEnVkBzDUgC+41uUpIAQkoDWTFpq68BwsRNLsSKgZGpuaS-CQAFgp0QcbAZr78tHQAkjx8giJ05laExLbUyVQpACKuBO7phnEJmlIyckiKyqrqvtq6+kjVIay5rKCQsAjIAKIAHvAYSewAbhBUwOwKwCy+BUgA+hNTMwBmZIvLwAA8ACoANEgA0lrjJBDAnFBIAAp0CpR05NcQZAB8TF8xDOdweTxe-GATmACgA7qsAPxIAAUwLYoIAZG8QN92JgTgAlCDwaKcE47aacCAna5XJx-BR7JBnf5XYAQeZ0f7-dEASjBj2eHGAe3oSAA8khkbgkABtV4ipAMshMyUAXV4EoV6ssSE8nPFBq5oVIFDGk2mUHYByOK3OgOY20t+0OS3tlyQAEEMBhfmQoA7-tZNBsSiASCBCfDXJTXXbTjRxQAfBzOJCppN0YolYO+AD0ACozXZw5Ho3Dyr4PBlvNlfPVZPIlCo1KaOnpYr1Q-4VIjeFDqXtZBBOKaQOEonR+0hBxBhxyx4lkmkZ3OF6PTRYM242DWvFlTSRexAu-Fx5PomfamwkvQ0p5Mj46tJZGunvOR0vNB2MO+h1+W47hUe5VME54Nq+jTNK2bQ-jonbdOBN75Ce-6fouF6RNE6Ebt+t4rpwuGAb426FvmeRsBA4wwNEJAig8dB7CMSAAMLKIIwAlBh-jHCcABigoQsqjLMmWUYxswKpquJFaAiBmizJg-AQPx0Q6CQjEziiSnTKeSCyfCcr8eqAqMICPQQZoFiUfk5psRxYBcTxx4rAAsiAMBVpoxByiqSrSWJEYSXCmoOdMTncQuvH2iqebWSGbCksAhhIKSEXOdFrkpbw7EZVFsgxcAHlecwClsI2jTlYpymqepEaMbwOm1WZgLNXpTCMMwRgqdKSAAORelB-X6gNWb9XyFzosQ+b5qicB0OAECMQKukqc2LRqDu65fuiFhTT5HDpNVbBrXVdAaY1qJna1JYQGqZ2dcw-WWSYI3Io9vBnQAdCQCgAMrISik3TUgs3zbiS0rUgZ3XjuB70HtB1sLkxA2QMS3DIgSAAHIrHG1rzGsob2YZlbMFmO6OAoLiZkUpSJXZdg+n6fyBqyrigtR4LCmoZB9YFLKjRyJrrPZaTjOcVzXI6Qvc0KLx831tzy8JgugsiZxytcurGkafCGvW7Q0XRDH0Mx2N5ZxBVLNltJCcKLP+oGZM8ruNV6WpF0NfQ2mw0gEsnGT0v-Ldr1brZd3hdbLnHCV3k+drSpO2zQfBXJ6ozlbkWx-aMuiGDc06E4pgcPRC3HpgpGM2lKypelMdZccUC5Y5mWFdl8dleilW8CdxBnV7l30E1N1MG1j1dd1dC9cig3DaN-XjSDh0zXNKILVD9CrbVG2wUj6I1v3MO1UPPsxNdLXj3dD21U9A2ve9J8dV9tW-QDQMr6v4Mb5DkDQ-7V68Mnx0APglPo+ALBAA)

Comment: Thank you! I had figured I needed to use a union but I haven't worked with them too much before so I had no idea it was possible to infer all of this. Going with your second solution while using an array instead of map:

`type ColumnDefinitionArray = { [K in AllKeys<DataRow>]: ColumnDefinition<K> }[AllKeys<DataRow>][]`