# TypeScript: Object or object

Tags: typescript

Can I somehow fix this code so that typescript prevents a and b from being used together?

```js
type A = {
  a: number;
}

type B = {
  b: number;
}

type C = {
  c: number;
}

type D = (A | B) & C;

const d0: D = { a: 123, c: 123 } // OK
const d1: D = { b: 123, c: 123 } // OK
const d2: D = { a: 123, b: 123, c: 123 } // NOT OK
```

Comment: See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370791/2887218) to the question this duplicates for more information.  If I translate the code in that answer to this example it gives [this result](https://tsplay.dev/WPj95N).  Good luck!

Comment: This package also makes life easy: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-xor 
With it, you can say `type D = XOR<A, B> & C;`

Comment: I saw `XOR` in `ts-essentials` package, but it works only with 2 objects: https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials/issues/183

The solution from @jcalz works very well. I used it.