# Mishmash of union is type checked as OK even when none of the union types check. How to prevent?

Tags: typescript

My goal is to be able to inject new type safe functionality into modular react components.

So for example, I could do something like this:

```
<FooComponent
  $foo="bar"
  $inherit="border"
  $borderColor="red"
/>
// $borderColor is not a prop of FooComponent but is added from the $inherit
```

So I started researching how to achieve this and I came up with:

```
type A = Partial<{ 
  foo: number
  bar: string
}>

type B = Partial<{
  foo: number
  other: string
}>

type C = A & B & { $inherit: "b" }

const a: A = {
  foo: 3,
  other: 'cool', //'other' does not exist in type
}

const b: C = { // $inherit is missing
  foo: 3,
  other: 'cool',
}

const c: A | C = { // OK ????
  foo: 3,
  other: 'cool',
}
```

Here `const c` types checks as OK even though it does not meet the criteria of either A or C.

I submitted this as a [bug on github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45339) and was told this is by design.

So if this is by design, how can I actually make a type safe union on key signatures that requires one of them to actually match? *(without any excess keys, even if those keys exist somewhere else in the union)*

Comment: See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370791/2887218) to the question this duplicates for more info.  If I translate that answer here I get [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wO8A6N); good luck!