# Is it possible to create strict 'A or B' types in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've run into an issue with typing React components that I've never run into before. I've simplified the issue below.

```
interface Circle {
  kind?: "circle";
  radius: number;
}
 
interface Square {
  kind: "square";
  sideLength: number;
}
 
type Shape = Circle | Square;

const shape: Shape = {
  sideLength: 7,
  radius: 7,
};
```

[Link to TypeScript Playground containing the above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMLCggNig3gKGWQGtQATAfgC5kAiBDbCWgbkOSjjOAFcBnGiB4BbAEbQ2AX0L5QkWIhQBlAI484UPO1IgyNWnzUbmbIn2BkIAGQggA5mAAWgkeKhSZYAJ4AHZY7g-ZABeNEYcZAAfZFV1TTZ8BAB7ED4wZD4AvxolLJRQgjMLa1sHZ2QAdgAadk5ufhpq-Ek2IA)

In the example above, I'd expect the `shape` variable declaration to throw an error in TypeScript as neither a Circle nor a Square have **both** a `sideLength` and a `radius`. The defined object is neither a Circle nor a Square, so in my eyes it shouldn't be a valid shape.

Is it possible to define the types in such a way that the following items will be valid or errors (as labelled).

```
// Valid
const shape: Shape = {
  kind: 'circle',
  radius: 7,
};

// Valid
const shape: Shape = {
  radius: 7,
};

// Valid
const shape: Shape = {
  kind: 'square',
  sideLength: 7,
};

// Error
const shape: Shape = {
  sideLength: 7,
  radius: 7,
};

// Error
const shape: Shape = {
  sideLength: 7,
};

// Error
const shape: Shape = {
  kind: 'square',
  radius: 7,
};

// Error
const shape: Shape = {
  kind: 'circle',
  sideLength: 7,
};
```

EDIT:

For further clarification, in my use-case `kind` is optional on a Circle. For those familiar with React the actual problem I'm trying to solve is around the `as` property exposed by styled-components. I want a component to accept an optional `as` prop which will allow the user to change the component (by-default a `button`) to a link (`a`). If the user specifies `as="a"` then I want TypeScript to compalin if the user then tries to use button-specific props on what is now a link (`disabled`, for example). The `as` prop is optional as I don't want all implementors to be required to pass it. In my simplified example above `as` is analagous to `kind`, hence why `kind` is optional.

Comment: *"The defined object is neither a Circle nor a Square, so in my eyes it shouldn't be a valid shape."* Remember that subtypes are still valid examples of their supertype. Your `shape` **is** a valid shape, because it's a valid `Circle`, because it has a `radius: number` property and no `kind` property (so the `kind` property isn't incompatible with `Circle`). It *also* has an additional property, but that just makes it a subtype, not an invalid `Circle`. I'm intrigued, though, that excess property checks for object literals (which are enabled in your playground) are defeated here.

Comment: Why do you define `kind` in circle as optional? with your type `const shape: Shape = {radius: 7};` is valid circle. why? because it has all mandatory props (kind is optional)

Comment: If you make `kind` required in `Circle`, the problem goes away, because `shape` is no longer  a valid `Shape` (it's neither a `Square` nor a `Circle`): [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMLCggNig3gKGWQGtQATALmQCIENsJqBuQ5KOM4AVwGcqQuAWwBG0FgF9C+UJFiIUAZQCOXOFDytSISjR4q1jFkR7AyEADIQQAczAALfkNFQJUsAE8ADortxvyAF40ehxkAB9kZVV1FnwEAHsQHjBkHl9vKgV0lCCCY1MLK1sHZAB2ABpWdk5eKgr8cRYgA)

Comment: Shape would be best defined by having an area. And then square and circle can implement their own calculation. I ported once the [go interface example](https://gobyexample.com/interfaces) that is about shapes in a [blog post](https://dev.to/codingsafari/interfaces-in-typescript-3eh).

Comment: It's unclear why you're making kind optional in Circle. What @T.J.Crowder said. As it stands `{sideLength: 7,  radius: 7}` can be a `Circle`. Are you asking why additional properties are allowed since it does not meet the definition of a `Square`?

Comment: Just as a response to the comments above - I've updated my question to add a bit more context around why I want `kind` to be optional.

Comment: Please see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370791/2887218) to the other question for more information.  If you want you can use `ExclusifyUnion<T>` to transform unions of object types with known keys into a new union where the members of the union are mutually exclusive.  If I use that for your example, it becomes [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mZaveN).  Good luck!

Comment: I've tested it and I believe @jcalz 's comment above is the correct solution. Once I've confirmed that it is I'll add another answer with their solution and accept it, unless you want to do that first @jcalz?

Comment: This question has been closed as a duplicate of [TypeScript a | b allows combination of both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370222/typescript-a-b-allows-combination-of-both) so I don't think SO will allow another answer to be posted here.  You could post an answer on the other question, but if it's essentially the same as the one there, it wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have defined `kind` property as an optional property, so if you create a shape object with only `radius` property is still valid `circle`:

Look at this object

```
const shape: Shape = {
  sideLength: 7,
  radius: 7,
};
```

This is valid circle with one extra property.

So to raise an error in some case you've said, you should make `kind` property as a required property:

```
interface Circle {
  kind: "circle";
  radius: number;
}
 
interface Square {
  kind: "square";
  sideLength: number;
}
 
type Shape = Circle | Square;

const shape2: Shape = {
  radius: 7,//Error
};
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMLCggNig3gKGWQGtQATALmQCIENsJqBuQ5KOM4AVwGcqQuAWwBG0FgF9C%20UJFiIUAZQCOXOFDytSISjR4q1jFkR7AyEADIQQAczAALfkNFQJUsAE8ADortxvyAF40ehxkAB9kZVV1FnwAejjkADU4LFN8BAB7EB4wZB5fbwBGKgVClCCCIi0dAHI6TBxagBpWdk5eKgB2VvFYhOTU9KycvIK-CAAmUvLA5Cq2Dm4%20ZB78Pvx4xJS0sgzs3PzygGYZibmFmqpavWiIFtYTM0sbe27e-sSAUSgoTKh9qMjhMACxnfyVR6mCxWWwOVatIjtZbvdafZA-P4AkaHcbeACs4Iq8yhz1hbwRaM2A0x-0BuPKADYiRdNORrrcDA8kUtOpSNlsMb86TixuUuizIdV2ch6iF7oj8tCXnDUX0gA)

Comment: *"This is valid circle with one extra property."* True, though as I said in the comments, TypeScript's usual excess property checks for object literals would disallow that if it were `shape: Circle` instead of `shape: Shape` (even though it's a valid `Circle`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've just updated the question in response to this and some of the comments elaborating on why (in my use-case) I would like `kind` to be optional.