# Advanced TypeScript extending a type with required and optional properties

Tags: typescript

Here is a simple case that is easy in isolation, but breaks down when composed into a larger type.

If `scrollToItem` is defined, then `getRowId` **must** also be defined. Otherwise, `getRowId` is optional.

This type definition works just fine:

```
type ScrollProps<T> =
  | { scrollToItem: T; getRowId: (row: T) => string; }
  | { getRowId?: (row: T) => string; };

const a: ScrollProps<number> = {}; // ok
const b: ScrollProps<number> = { scrollToItem: 6, getRowId: (row) => '' }; // ok
const c: ScrollProps<number> = { getRowId: (row) => '' }; // ok
const d: ScrollProps<number> = { scrollToItem: 6 }; // error - expected
```

It can be extended further to pick the `getRowId` property from an imported library type.

```
type LibraryObject<T> = {
  getRowId?: (row: T) => string;
  otherProps?: boolean;
};

type ScrollProps<T> =
  | ({ scrollToItem: T } & Required<Pick<LibraryObject<T>, 'getRowId'>>)
  | Pick<LibraryObject<T>, 'getRowId'>;

const a: ScrollProps<number> = {}; // ok
const b: ScrollProps<number> = { scrollToItem: 6, getRowId: (row) => '' }; // ok
const c: ScrollProps<number> = { getRowId: (row) => '' }; // ok
const d: ScrollProps<number> = { scrollToItem: 6 }; // error - expected
```

Unfortunately, I have to add this type definition onto an existing type, which is already extending the library type. For some reason, TypeScript no longer requires `getRowId` when passing `scrollToItem` **IF ALSO** passing some of the other properties it extends.

```
type LibraryObject<T> = {
  getRowId?: (row: T) => string;
  otherProps?: boolean;
};

type ScrollProps<T> =
  | ({ scrollToItem: T } & Required<Pick<LibraryObject<T>, 'getRowId'>>)
  | Pick<LibraryObject<T>, 'getRowId'>;

type MasterType<T> = LibraryObject<T> & ScrollProps<T>;

const a: MasterType<number> = {}; // ok
const b: MasterType<number> = { scrollToItem: 6, getRowId: (row) => '' }; // ok
const c: MasterType<number> = { getRowId: (row) => '' }; // ok
const d: MasterType<number> = { scrollToItem: 6 }; // error - expected
const e: MasterType<number> = { scrollToItem: 6, otherProps: true }; // NO ERROR, but I wish there were!
```

Why would setting any of the other properties negate the required properties managed by `ScrollProps`?

Answer (score 1):

The comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69316625/typescript-dependent-optional-properties) led me to an answer. I don't fully understand, but TypeScript seems to allow partial implementation of Type contracts. Updating the `ScrollProps` type to use `Partial<Record<'scrollToItem', never>>` in the second union option gives the expected results.

```
type ScrollProps =
  | ({ scrollToItem: number } & Required<Pick<LibraryObject, 'getRowId'>>)
  | (Partial<Record<'scrollToItem', never>> & Pick<LibraryObject, 'getRowId'> );

const d: MasterType = { scrollToItem: 6 }; // error - expected
const e: MasterType = { otherProps: true, scrollToItem: 6 }; // gives an error now
```