# Is there a better way of structuring this typescript type definition?

Tags: typescript, data-structures

I just started using TypeScript in my Node projects and I was wondering if there is a cleaner, more concise way of implementing this:

```
import { XOR } from "ts-xor";

type _RemoveNull<T> = {
    [P in keyof T] : string;
}

type UserIdParam = {
    a: string;
}

type BudgetIdParam = UserIdParam & {
    b: string | null;
}

type AccountIdParam = _RemoveNull<BudgetIdParam> & {
    c: string | null;
}

type TransIdParam = _RemoveNull<AccountIdParam> & {
    d: string | null;
}

type IdsParam = XOR<XOR<XOR<UserIdParam, BudgetIdParam>, AccountIdParam>, TransIdParam>;
```

I wanted a type that would accept any of these sample objects:

```
const a = {a: "1"};
const b = {a: "1", b: "2"};
const c = {a: "1", b: "2", c: "3"};
const d = {a: "1", b: "2", c: "3", d: "4"};
```

Also, only the last available property of the object can be null, that's why I had to intersect with the previous type and removed the null from the union.
I tried to do a union of the four types `UserIdParam`, `BudgetIdParam`, `AccountIdParam`, and `TransIdParam` but after I read other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370222/why-does-a-b-allow-a-combination-of-both-and-how-can-i-prevent-it), I decided to use an XOR instead (ts-xor) to accomplish what I needed.

Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks!

--

EDIT: as mentioned by @Thomas in the comments, there is no concept of order for the object's properties, so there is no "last" one.

Comment: Properties in an object don't have an order. It's all up to you to decide what's the "last" property. That's why this is a quite peculiar problem. I'd define a base-type with all properties and then use `Pick<Base, ...> | Pick<Base, ...> | ...` to select which combinations of properties are allowed. https://tsplay.dev/mL4Gkm

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that approach. I might have to do away with the null design because it makes it more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reimplement it using generics, mapped types, and conditional types (thanks to this [article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/typescript-advanced-mapped-and-conditional-types-2d10c96042fe) for pointing me in the right direction):

```
type UserIdKeys = "userId";
type BudgetIdKeys = UserIdKeys | "budgetId" ;
type AccountIdKeys = BudgetIdKeys | "accountId";
type TransactIdKeys = AccountIdKeys | "transactionId";

// added for readability
type AllIdKeys = TransactIdKeys;

type IdParamGroup<T extends AllIdKeys, N extends AllIdKeys> = {
    [P in T]: P extends N ? (string | null) : string;
};
```

Here's an example usage:

```
// valid
const trans1: IdParamGroup<TransactIdKeys, "transactionId"> = {
    userId: "1",
    budgetId: "3",
    accountId: "56",
    transactionId: null,
}
// invalid
const budget3: IdParamGroup<BudgetIdKeys, "budgetId"> = {
    userId: "1",
    budgetId: null,
    accountId: "23"
}
```

You can try it here: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=48&ssc=2&pln=44&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgSQCYGkIjlAvFAIgFcEVUCBuAWAChRIoAhI1AcwmDU2z1lK6w4APoQBGLdp3JRqdcNACCAYyUB7IgDsp3HPmZsOAniIIBDFeq1pKtetAAqiUxrjntg3srWb3xwsCcXNwBLVQ1rWVoAeiioU1RUCFQoADNVRChECHjTUWCAG2DQW3koBXz8o10oR2dXJV84SLkGNAAFUycAWwBxRHUwAB57KAgAD2AIDVQccsqMQQAaKAA5UYmpmbKKqoA%20XgBvWigTqABtNqhgjRqAXQAuKEvxyemcNYB%20KAAKOADr1hQEQaIgVACUUEef0QANkAF9mlEAFRQABupkKySRUVoahcwCgJCQAEZHu1OqZev0iEN4EgqstiPxyPt8EcaKdCczHgRiQRaHDcWE-lykAAmMmoDrdPoDQZ0sg6RlEsgEVlQdmclVoR4gioCoX4qDiAzAUlQcky6lDfSSBliCSGFmHY6nbWoHl8xauk4mu0eqB6-IGmh4kV%20jgSi1SilUuW2p1Kh2m6zqzVu7mEL0%2042OqQ80xwVApfk0QWh4UE8zeLTmy2U2U0wZeSyNRnV1upl0cjP0gO8gjenu%20vM6whiwc5js%20MdBkNhgkBOp1mNWuW1IINe0EJeb4ChcLOtk592eyfD3Mp-sAZnPnOnVn7AFYAGx3067%20r7sKz0HBsu0NEKLXOimJQNihoiiq16StKDbWvKzJJkyfZqt2WqZpoiQpNcSTzpWl6SDB0ZwXGTYJm2yb%20mhx4XqeWbviOV66n%20Q73hYM79mKt74UaEbAAALLBsaNjao4LNgjL8V2tGctJ-aFsWpblgucQcVoUb1mRQwtpxyEPlINEaiemYDmxpzyTyE7mScBm-vqF6fiEP79gAjspkGLoEcCaau8Hrt5bjbk5DQHjJxl0aZ2YXpZhC3jZUAhd%20h4sQ5cJAA)