# disjointed record types using different literal types for keys

Tags: typescript

I am looking to define a type which allows either a set of optional keys, or a single key 'all'. How to do it in Typescript? Is it possible?

I tried this in 4.1, and it did not work:

```
type STAGE = 'alpha' | 'beta' | 'gamma';

type ALL = 'all';

type Config = Partial<Record<STAGE, string>> | Record<ALL, string>;

const c1: Config = { // ok
  alpha: 'asd1',
  beta: 'asd2',
};

const c2: Config = { // ok
  all: 'asd3',
};

const c3: Config = { // I want an error here
  all: 'asd5',
  alpha: 'asd4',
};
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKqxKN) meet your needs or am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does A | B allow a combination of both, and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46370222/2887218)