# Infer type of constructed object

Tags: typescript

In my TypeScript app, I'm taking an [OpenAPI spec](https://swagger.io/specification/) and constructing an example from it. So the spec might look something like this, to simplify:

```
const spec = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
     firstName: { 
       type: 'string',
       example: 'Johnbob',
     },
     lastName: {
       type: 'string',
       // No example provided
     },
     age: {
       type: 'integer',
       example: 30
     },
  }
}
```

Etc. It's much more complicated than that, because OpenAPI also has more complicated "keywords" (`oneOf`, `anyOf`), as well as array types, and objects/arrays/keywords can be nested within one another.

But fundamentally, any OpenAPI specification for a "schema" can be converted into an example object, including with auto-generated dummy examples. The above would become something like this once I've turned it into an example:

```
{
  firstName: 'Johnbob',
  lastName: 'Default example string',
  age: 30
}
```

The question: Is there any way to automatically infer/generate the type of the generated example? I know I could do this:

```
const example = {
  firstName: 'Johnbob',
  lastName: 'Default example string',
  age: 30
}

// Ideally, { firstName: string, lastName: string, age: number }
type ExampleType = typeof example;
```

But I want the return of my generate-example functionality to be typed automatically. Currently, it's just throwing its hands up and returning `any`.

Its basic structure is that it has a `processSchema` function that takes any schema type (whether object, oneOf, or simple integer type), and then recursively runs through it "processing" each child.

Full playground of code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTge0nUAVc0C8UBEBnYOASwDsBzHKAH1xIFcBbAIwjkpp1OAjNfdwRMAVhADGwfjiYIEAGwgBDEpIVw4CkDgDcAKD2hIsRMlBRMOqNSgAhGfKXwkrUBasA5RiziOTIVzQBJEm5eb2NnP0saAGVCUjIfCP8oAHlhMWBElEirAEE1DSzQXR0uVgAzBVFoFJIIFPKoAG9XBDqGgC4jJ2yUuABpCBAAdwQ4ABMAbQBdXQBfUuCKquhckhAG5tclDfKuoo2BodGJmfmdA2hBkbHxs1T2xpo13d1L7t8+65O77AOrb63ErvIpECB4e4AJTEtwAPARiOQADQfCJfY63AB8JUW3DglWqNgUeAgB1hqExW0sl324Wy6EguksEHoDAA-F18uoQOTsa4IAAPBQMMDyDlQVBMqDjcGiYhgYBENrihHxc645aE2xyRQkf6C7gkcYQ6zE0l00Cw6Q6pSUlrUjBdKR2XXaHQLDX4lZQDzMVj6gWG41Eklk1leO2uGm0Tx8KUMUhEBiMcXh1jxhQCpMprppuBS8pjBgKYDinDlWQIEtuj1lL2EoIhf0WkBQA0s4Om0Mt2F5yMOyBOsqhN2WBMkbPs3Ox-OuYtZ5NTqB59UXDBQWKIsgAMSLJYh5ksAHoj6lICRcjAAlAmHQiLJgABaUhQQtwYvAPBdAAWwGAYC-E88GGBQyFCAA6JUj3GBBRDwI88EgUQiHKIhRBLJUSGgksFEfBgEBlWR4PGHDH0ueCAGJVXIZIcBI7gcFo+iIDIpMIEYqJcDAYlgNuDirCkEAGNophSFUTRXBPGw6GAKBVFEwhxKgBBgG-VgIVUaAqmqBUIHGWi6DvcZ+I4CBi3vN1PQJaBN3iAMgxNM0yWosh+ygaN8DichR1fPdSy6WzyF3d99ylI8ACpwqgXIoBc5TGgUKA4B4QUoG4v9WBIKBIqPVx0rxEgVS8sh1TrazUnScR7I7Rzux6S1oVEOEXJRA5MTcjzBBEcQfLAC0wS-KBGua4rWpbdEbgmPlLGSgBHO9kvGIqtzOKMiGAMUuhcrQoCkgIEti0Q1OLbZxnGdbMIUWRQXBcVrXsEhSqWetVgKEBqqNWrzXqnkuQ0WEdnaql3MdXBVG5Hz1rMwaDgmn51VEWQeKgABRIURXkYHBWFUUIClPAjrMhRaR+uGgT0SwmpIBE6HEMYAAoCeO4nUV6I5JvGABKYHqW-Ig8HApmifuIXiylSm2gIKAADcrroLB3L5gWAH0+tg8E8GiQni0Z7WFE58XFf58DsYxhXZdkeW5IhS4EEaC35alD1LHKOhZFkNGcfkemZQJ+VFWVLbRrbQNMqugA1OWIGW+JuftSwkogYA6DgLKmhlqOulU43TdxlFfblIgFUwlF21TiOo6gOYnYp3bIoldRpfU8FDuZuSjRvO9ZGDJQQ696AuoyV9EAYKB1ohNWTAG7LcssVXEGqPBNb13XmZJz52Z+OPXEsFCoHpnA2nqcpKBfUX9Z5hPkuT1OjZVtXF+X5nV6J8Cj4aSYAAZpgNneq7bIi0A94Hx2A0U+WVz7bwTlfJOKcsrZ3vgvDWWtn7n3AqA8oX8f6GzmAAkkY9GgHyhgwPA4DW5EygdAxON8sqTAQeBee6sl4oKJi-YskFuAkM5rMP+uCICAIIfvHAlwyGQMvrvQhaD3iYBkQISqEhKFUOoXAiq3VgAm2CMQcEbCFDgUns4AanNwKLVphAemf8lH0y6iiSYABrIYKILY-zMJSem8clHQLsUMaYWclYMIfsgleFtras1AGTCYnMkQWI8eBWJ1jonQLmJEhJCcmi4OJMpeRKTf5KL4QI9xVDgGTE4EsEcKIcB5hwNMSCJBEZ0F9jo8ClxObc3oYwx+0Qky4wODo7mGSVwpOAVI9cMjsDOhtMoVpfj2nIK6fIHpYiMn3V1IbaBQy9ZNJGbIipM4cBTONjM5hczvq+F6SEgZHjlG3zaQEo5ZsFl6z6RCba0SFiJNcM7OuUVHDjFMRpWKLI8BECYJjXOmM3zLjaI+Qe4g0r9RbuFWeUBDma2OT0v+k8ui+i8P8GIxVcU2BdA4FsVhGwpTCD9VwnNpx+jgFYZZvcaBxQKXtBKWUwXQG-EsiALIQ6ijQutWQrYSTABRNfFRqkSx-2AZPE26Ncbc3FbfWVHKSjQNZe3NsrIQaQBRGQdQTBFbQFQnAKWSAA5ZQyb3Dl0rCEqtZIq2ByrjAaMYFgtVCcNWJTiu8YY61vy+RCqKq5lrA0fm4HcFytr96yukdslylAABkia4VIHAm+D8iiYE0PEQnQyRBxhOmJOMSoj48AlsUI+E4ABGAAzI+Y06FSFRMucxJ01aACcAB2T+j5P7VsfNWgALDgFtHjinMVYgwdiPjcCdp7X2gdw7UCfwAKwdFrUOjoq6AAcAAtAA1P2jon9P6jpSUTe8TpL2yAAAI3vAk1Bg57LncSXj8J0eBT3IDwLW2tcok4vo8UwISEAnSf3GKupgQ7xhDtreMJg5QABMq7RBwdrQoIdq7V2wYgF22tAA2AjO6sM9rwzujtq6INAaUaJEg4lwPVurf209zGWPMbY0xjjLGeNMZ48ZMdiTJiyozSWaYISXnvL-lJFIqlWB+pJGKp1oaSTU2BZjGUlQ3bAD-kqtO0SXJOk9mbWKxUaMJ2HKwLoq7BMJzzF0Id4EbPRIZSQLolRAG2bmMJl1lweGWAWB6KmUtEJiC6GkNR-xsDx2jAAchhcAWLY79EoAGl0Apr4iCmuAG4YUYHmhQASXFlySWEkcq6LFgAUggb8JBpBMFK1QuYtmoBIwILl6d6Wiug1iyVlrx5TxuAQH3EzatpYFr0hY5rFjQL5YywOfLsXLNwEa0o8rUBa2fym2OwLJRguyQ5fcOowxUbyu9qF0Qv8dDBZ1OBSsZB6Ycrlf3K7+2oBPtxgKaISFwvyKi8DOLCXVspcVOCLrVCTXtby+lwrHjivFVW1Q9bVWat1cEIjgLLW2s5eh7mnVi2+sJKkkNkbuNU3jZlPpJrLXZvg6UXF5bGOE7rc29tixlRpZjChqgPm5A6dUPfnsKAkx5sJ0B-Ipn0CQdpbx9A+jnXZdUPh1uSXHjkfWB5StlJCdpuXITrIKGpr+d6-xxVxn-W1dnfy9W7XAXtdvNyRb0XC2KtA4t5YaXYPFeWHl3N23YueuE5N8zq3FWACyCBxsQFi-73XJv5DkFUkEMPpBBrO6Vz183-vmSh6gNWpDW3g8O48cX95SjphTY+e6Pbktbv3fpsd07-d6YffkF9pCRiOWcyAA), and the current WIP implementation below:

```
type PropertyType = "string" | "number" | "integer" | "object" | "boolean" | "array";


type Property =
  | BooleanProperty
  | NumberProperty
  | IntegerProperty
  | StringProperty
  | ObjectProperty
  | ArrayProperty;

interface OneOf {
  oneOf: PropertyOrKeyword[];
}
interface AnyOf {
  anyOf: PropertyOrKeyword[];
}
type Keyword = OneOf | AnyOf;
type PropertyOrKeyword = Property | Keyword;

type Properties = Record<string, PropertyOrKeyword>;

interface BaseProperty<T> {
  type: PropertyType;
  enum?: Array<T>;
  example?: T;
  description?: string;
}

interface BooleanProperty extends BaseProperty<boolean> {
  type: "boolean";
}

interface NumberProperty extends BaseProperty<number> {
  type: "number";
  minimum?: number;
  maximum?: number;
  format?: "float";
}

interface IntegerProperty extends BaseProperty<number> {
  type: "integer";
  minimum?: number;
  maximum?: number;
}


type StringFormats =
  // OpenAPI built-in formats: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#string
  | "date"
  | "date-time"
  | "password"
  | "byte"
  | "binary"
  // But arbitrary others are accepted
  | "uuid"
  | "email";

interface StringProperty extends BaseProperty<string> {
  type: "string";
  format?: StringFormats;
  /** A string of a regex pattern **/
  pattern?: string;
}

interface ObjectProperty extends BaseProperty<Record<string, Property>> {
  type: "object";
  properties: Record<string, PropertyOrKeyword>;
  required?: string[];
  title?: string; // If a schema
  additionalProperties?: boolean;
}

interface ArrayProperty extends BaseProperty<Array<any>> {
  type: "array";
  items: PropertyOrKeyword;
}

class Example {
  example;
  schema: PropertyOrKeyword;

  constructor(schema: PropertyOrKeyword) {
    this.schema = schema;
    const value = this._processSchema(schema);
    this.example = value as typeof value;
  }

  fullExample(description?: string, externalValue?: string) {
    return { value: this.example, description, externalValue };
  }

  /** Traverses schema and builds an example object from its properties */
  _processSchema(schema: PropertyOrKeyword) {
    if ("oneOf" in schema) {
      return this._processSchema(schema.oneOf[0]);
    } else if ("anyOf" in schema) {
      return this._processSchema(schema.anyOf[0]);
    } else if ("items" in schema) {
      return [this._processSchema(schema.items)];
    } else if ("type" in schema) {
      if (schema.type === "object") {
        return Object.entries(schema.properties).reduce(
          (obj, [key, val]) => ({
            [key]: this._processSchema(val as PropertyOrKeyword),
            ...obj,
          }),
          {} as object
        );
      } else {
        if (["integer", "number"].includes(schema.type)) this._processSimpleProperty(schema) as number;
        if (schema.type === "boolean") this._processSimpleProperty(schema) as boolean;
        if (schema.type === "number") this._processSimpleProperty(schema) as number;
        return this._processSimpleProperty(schema) as string;
      }
    }
  }

  /** Produces a sensible example for non-object properties */
  _processSimpleProperty(
    prop: NumberProperty | StringProperty | BooleanProperty | IntegerProperty
  ): number | boolean | string {
    // If an example has been explicitly set, return that
    if (prop.example) return prop.example;

    // If an enum type, grab the first option as an example
    if (prop.enum) return prop.enum[0];

    // If a string type with format, return a formatted string
    if (prop.type === "string" && prop.format) {
      return {
        uuid: "asdfa-sdfea-wor13-dscas",
        date: "1970-01-14",
        ["date-time"]: "1970-01-14T05:34:58Z+01:00",
        email: "email@email.com",
        password: "s00pers33cret",
        byte: "0d5b4d43dbf25c433a455d4e736684570e78950d",
        binary: "01101001001010100111010100100110100d",
      }[prop.format] as string;
    }

    // Otherwise, return a sensible default
    return {
      string: "Example string",
      integer: 5,
      number: 4.5,
      boolean: false,
    }[prop.type];
  }
}

const spec: ObjectProperty = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
     firstName: { 
       type: 'string',
       example: 'Johnbob',
     },
     lastName: {
       type: 'string',
       // No example provided
     },
     age: {
       type: 'integer',
       example: 30
     },
  }
};

const spec: ObjectProperty = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
     firstName: { 
       type: 'string',
       example: 'Johnbob',
     },
     lastName: {
       type: 'string',
       // No example provided
     },
     age: {
       type: 'integer',
       example: 30
     },
     favoriteThing: {
       oneOf: [{
         type: 'object',
         properties: {
           name: {
             type: 'string',
             example: 'Beer'
           },
           liters: {
             type: 'integer',
             example: 1
           }
         }
       },
       {
         type: 'object',
         properties: {
           name: {
             type: 'string',
             example: 'Movie'
           },
           lengthInMins: {
             type: 'integer',
             example: 120
           }
         }
       }
      ]
     }
  }
};

console.log(new Example(spec).example)
```

Comment: If you need us to consult the full WIP code then it should be included as plain text in the question itself, so that the [mre] doesn't require that anyone navigate away from stack overflow to see it.  If it's just a supplement and you don't need an answer based on it, then that's fine.

Comment: You will need to make a recursive type function like `SchemaToType<T>` that takes a schema-like `T`  and turns it into the corresponding TypeScript type.  Given the example code in the question itself, it could look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mq10rm).  Does that meet your needs enough for you to make progress?  If so I could write up an answer explaining it.  If not, please [edit] the question to show a fuller example

Comment: Does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/NBy1xw) meet your needs?  I'd rather not get into the whole `Example` class and its implementation, or even your particular interfaces.  The important bit is the mapping from a schema-like type to the example type, and that's what this shows.  If this works, please let me know and I'll write up an answer explaining it.  If not, please give a concrete (and hopefully minimal) use case that it doesn't work for or you can't figure out.

Comment: Thanks! The examples you have are working, in that they show the right types, but I'm having trouble making sense of it, and so adapting it to my particular use case. I think in particular, the ternary stuff is hard to understand. When you write `type SchemaToType<T> = Schema extends T  ? unknown  : T extends OneOf ? SchemaToType<T["oneOf"][number]>` (...) you're defining a new type which takes a generic, and then, if the generic is an extension of Schema, returns unknown, otherwise, if it's an extension of OneOf, returns a schema-to-type of the opts (and on and on). Am I getting that right?

Comment: I'm happy to write up an answer explaining how it works but as a preview: `Schema extends T ? unknown : ` catches the situation where the compiler doesn't know anything more specific about `T` than that it's a `Schema`, so we immediately return `unknown` instead of having to slog through the union of all possible cases and end up with a circularity warning.  After that you're right... if `T extends OneOf` then we return a union of a schema-to-type for all the `oneOf` array elements; same with `AnyOf`, etc.  The full writeup probably won't happen for a while, it's bedtime in my time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main goal here is to write a type function `type SchemaToType<T> = ...` which takes a schema type as input and produces the corresponding value type as output.  So you want `SchemaToType<{type: "string"}>` to be `string`, and `SchemaToType<{type: "array", items: {type: "number"}}>` to be `number[]`, etc.

First we should probably write a `Schema` type that all schema types are assignable to.  This isn't strictly necessary, and you can do it differently if you want, but here's one way to do it:

```
type Schema = ObjectSchema | ArraySchema | PrimitiveSchema | OneOf | AnyOf;

type ObjectSchema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: Record<string, Schema>,
}

type ArraySchema = {
  type: "array",
  items: Schema,
}

interface PrimMapping {
  string: string,
  integer: number,
  number: number,
  // add here
}
    
type PrimitiveSchema = {
  type: keyof PrimMapping,
}

interface OneOf {
  oneOf: readonly Schema[]
}

interface AnyOf {
  anyOf: readonly Schema[]
}
```

And of course you can augment this definition with other schema types.  You can see that `Schema` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of specific schema types, some of which (`ObjectSchema`, `ArraySchema`, `OneOf`, and `AnyOf`) are recursively defined in terms of `Schema` itself.

The reason why I want to allow [`readonly` arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type) is because it is a less restrictive type than regular read-write arrays, and because [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) tend to result in readonly tuple types.

---

Armed with that, here's one way to write `SchemaToType<T>`:

```
type SchemaToType<T extends Schema> =
  Schema extends T ? unknown :
  T extends OneOf ? SchemaToType<T['oneOf'][number]> :
  T extends AnyOf ? SchemaToType<T['anyOf'][number]> :
  T extends PrimitiveSchema ? PrimMapping[T['type']] :
  T extends ObjectSchema ? {
    - readonly [K in keyof T['properties']]: SchemaToType<T['properties'][K]>
  } :
  T extends ArraySchema ? SchemaToType<T['items']>[] :
  never;
```

This is a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types).  The idea is that we go through each `Schema` union member and convert it into the corresponding value type.  Well, the first thing we do is `Schema extends T ? unknown :`, which means that if `T` turns out to be just `Schema` itself, we short-circuit the computation and return [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown).  This sort of thing is necessary to avoid circularity warnings, since otherwise `SchemaToType<Schema>` would end up recursing into itself forever.

Let's look at the other lines of that type:

```
  T extends OneOf ? SchemaToType<T['oneOf'][number]> :
```

If `T` is a `OneOf`, then we need to [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into its `oneOf` property, which is going to be an array of schemas... so we index further into its `number`-valued properties (which gives the array element type).  `T['oneOf'][number]` will be a union of the schema types in the array.  And since `SchemaToType` is (mostly) a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), then `SchemaToType<T['oneOf'][number]>` will itself be a union of the value types for each element of that union.  All of this means that the output type will be a union of all the `oneOf` array element value types.

```
  T extends AnyOf ? SchemaToType<T['anyOf'][number]> :
```

If `T` is `AnyOf`, we do the same thing as `OneOf`. Presumably your schema cares about the difference between "any of" and "one of", but in TypeScript both of these are fairly well represented by a union.  If you really care about the difference, you can build an "exclusive" union for `OneOf`, using a technique like that shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46370222/2887218), but I consider that out of scope here.

```
  T extends PrimitiveSchema ? PrimMapping[T['type']] :
```

This is the easy one... I wrote `PrimMapping` to be a map from `type` names to primitive types.  So if `T` is `{type: "integer"}`, then the value type is `PrimMapping["integer"]`, which turns out to be `number`.

```
  T extends ObjectSchema ? {
    - readonly [K in keyof T['properties']]: SchemaToType<T['properties'][K]>
  } :
```

If `T` is an `ObjectSchema` then we make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over each key from the `properties` property of `T`.  And finally:

```
  T extends ArraySchema ? SchemaToType<T['items']>[] :
```

If `T` is an `ArraySchema` then we make an array of the type corresponding to the `items` property of `T`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const spec = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    str: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    strOrNum: {
      oneOf: [{ type: 'string' }, { type: 'number' }],
      example: 30
    },
    strArr: {
      type: 'array',
      items: {
        type: 'string'
      }
    }
  }
} as const;

type SpecType = SchemaToType<typeof spec>
/* type SpecType = {
    str: string;
    strOrNum: string | number;
    strArr: string[];
} */
```

Looks good!

---

When you come to implement some function or class method that takes a value of type `Schema` and produces an example, you might have some issues getting the compiler to infer the right type for the schema.  If you write the above `spec` initializer without the `as const`, the compiler will fail to even remember the specific [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `type` property and things break:

```
const specOops = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    str: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    strOrNum: {
      oneOf: [{ type: 'string' }, { type: 'number' }],
      example: 30
    },
    strArr: {
      type: 'array',
      items: {
        type: 'string'
      }
    }
  }
} ;

type SpecTypeOops = SchemaToType<typeof specOops> // error!
```

So if you save things to their own variables you need `as const` or something like it.

You can write the function/method in such a way as to make the compiler try to infer narrow types from its input, but it's a bit obnoxious.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) for a feature request to make it easier.  Here's one way to implement it:

```
type SchemaHelper<T, K extends Types> = Schema & (
  { oneOf: readonly [] | readonly SchemaHelper<T, K>[] } |
  { anyOf: readonly [] | readonly SchemaHelper<T, K>[] } |
  {
    type: K,
    properties?: Record<string, SchemaHelper<T, K>>,
    items?: SchemaHelper<T, K>
  }
);

declare function schemaToExample<
  T extends SchemaHelper<T, K>, K extends Types
>(schema: T): SchemaToType<T>;
```

All `SchemaHelper` does is ask the compiler to pay attention to the `type` literal types and the individual array types and values.  But yuck.

In any case, let's test it out:

```
const ex2 = schemaToExample({
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    firstName: {
      type: 'string',
      example: 'Johnbob',
    },
    lastName: {
      type: 'string',
      // No example provided
    },
    age: {
      type: 'integer',
      example: 30
    },
  }
});
/* const ex2: {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;
} */

const ex2a = schemaToExample({
  oneOf: [{
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      name: {
        type: 'string',
        example: 'Beer'
      },
      liters: {
        type: 'integer',
        example: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      name: {
        type: 'string',
        example: 'Movie'
      },
      lengthInMins: {
        type: 'integer',
        example: 120
      }
    }
  }
  ]
}
);
/* const ex2a: {
    name: string;
    liters: number;
} | {
    name: string;
    lengthInMins: number;
} */

const ex3 = schemaToExample({
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    firstName: {
      type: 'string',
      example: 'Johnbob',
    },
    lastName: {
      type: 'string',
      // No example provided
    },
    age: {
      type: 'integer',
      example: 30
    },
    favoriteThing: {
      oneOf: [{
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          name: {
            type: 'string',
            example: 'Beer'
          },
          liters: {
            type: 'integer',
            example: 1
          }
        }
      },
      {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          name: {
            type: 'string',
            example: 'Movie'
          },
          lengthInMins: {
            type: 'integer',
            example: 120
          }
        }
      }
      ]
    }
  }
});
/* const ex3: {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;
    favoriteThing: {
        name: string;
        liters: number;
    } | {
        name: string;
        lengthInMins: number;
    };
} */
```

Looks good, I think.  The output types are the ones you wanted.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAygxgCwgWwIZQLxQPICMBWEcw8SaUAPlAIIBOtqIpK6VACrQJbKfCcBuEZuSrYAdhGwAzSjTEhpAbgBQy0JBwEiJRC0xQA3sqhR1EAFxQARAHstxKwBpjUMLRuRafCAGdLAJSIbWgATAB4fYC4xAHNHWF00AD5nAF9VTjFgCFopVDhoDm4AWVQwMEyYwxdI6JjLWsrnE0zsmJzLMQBXZFwc5qhu3o7Bnr7aAYB6SahUEJCoJFoIZXS1cGg6BiZE9CwjEzNLK1R6RicXXhQ-BLJUNNUzKCKePkFhPerDjcsAawgQDYZC9SuUmqsMlkcnkCjgJNIvlAbPCpJZlnNkQAbEC3FgAbQAuhDWtD8pt5AiDrMKaioOiQlicR9CRD1hoPgAVGwcjZhDlQCAAD2yYhCPlxyUwLg+AuFEFF4v5AH4oF0xL8xDYAO5iKDmFz8oUisVwyQyFWc7m8jl4gDkyLNtoJeKG4wJST1BtlxvF1BpUAtuy5PMgfLtqBpTpdYxy7s9JkNcoVzy4rwEQl2AZTJTKFVieJttrMToJ8agiZ9mkIxBlKqpJgAtHSIBixNioHiANJQTJQf6AmSFtweHLeHwlyyWkMQMO24eeMdRzvulypMsV+UmraMWsS1DB612q7IcfuwlliSCWgqNnQafirAyo2b8WZKQ5WBZmDel+GUw-HsxHfWgoG7NcVW7ToICvPVBmgnJHg2PcAAkIExTw+Xibtn2Te8PUfTMADIoAAChcAwkRRNEWwZNscXPKh6UZFC0IwjksKSc81wocjqQUWkmLojtS0YmjmI+VD0JyTDQM40tuPIlxvkgSxOwGEx51HThfCVAIglCCIoiaFipNoGTOySFIlJ7bIT10ky2I41dlAAShvEIiExU5oCkNViE4ZEoB8IMbAAUUFVBkDATEZy9HCTQk1jpPY2SsJ-XCNh8ZQkhI4K7ksDkXMnELpz5JIbzgZFIiCyA4H0Kkjige17GAW0Bk0rxtJuesgqiSweuUiwmsaWI2us1J1N62hsFoAA5Hp+uskwHWkSw8QoxrbRGmJbSgCa-0210cl21ICUmkwhUi6KhoAZgABnGybai2RaTDe-8VKa05tjG96Wls7qlrezbtttIH0neiG9tWWZxUqsRIhvJ4YFq6d9CnXkzCBGqiCSZRJgAKg+6AUaINH9ms2oGiM2IVHe2oZvm5BqbqWQjuvSmoheqbKkJFQ1wJyZVHh6qfFq7APAfRFNrsatWva9wFy6163qpxF3pBmmdsmibOemuaFvVt6VtpdbicsLatZO+INoA212ZOs6gcuqKYsse7Hr17mBvNr6zhAX6-uPQG-uBu3QfB8bnNSJGkNJuBpwlsApYx0MsZkMWiCTnwPWmAV6GCABCYWquAWUrpi-Q8pYLlworiBctqtz8aJkWy5d66VZMNXtrp1WokZw3trZmMOfprn6BZ3mCX5qBBdUZQ29lAAmKuQrr12G4au3Ze0QOOrHLuoCkThaEiWbIqGn3NbqQP3o7t2moAKRsBAxFwOw772yavPPy+j8GhbUG50oB51mjYcum9XDuH4JwDyIRPbvVQO0ABvtbQknaLQL+F0Iqb3dg9SGAx0ipGboTKAS8hTLyPifM+wAL7ICGr3ayv86H-x5rTayyChrs1nvPRepcV6fGrmgWuuDrokSpCbNaPUZYtS-gfZWRsTBiDYT7QBw0rYgJwfXC2AAhCAx1wYgMxFcM+qD1HoKhJg7Bb0H5DQAIyR0hquAYMid5yMmgo3wqCVEMPMWg4BQNtF4KasUGwsCIBg1DrrUOMVYjAAQAASTEMUTIIdQ5oIwcdLRkDO5QHscvAhf0oYmChlDIk6RSGtwEZQ1AR9fGMK1n3EwJjshmNGMMDm3EjYNKnhw96cSYgJOSakhGnRR68KFvwhG7dBQ3TXncUR9cJEuFkXLfeistLeKNjQv+filEBM0c7MRj9bQvzfh-XAX8YlvRYfQq+QMb6VBsWAiBdjoHhLgRABBhDOEoIOZtLJWCQF2PwYgt6eR+DBCuByBAlRUFSI7GotBu9iA2I0pszq2zkXKNUUEv6TzRo5Pvicoatp9GGIyW9G5VLWk5HSVSixQL0V-VBfk-FpT8UlOpSA5Fay945K8QyjJvSDmh0JdrDltjSUWzCREqJjKaUZMGcMlJaT-Eaztsy4l0qdH5MKVK7lzjolAyJMa6GJCVBkIoXM6hp89mNLqM0qAdy2FMKQf8nh1lIXQuyLC+FYrBhuqafiul7SvWQ1kMi0V7rlXyiGUktVYyOnjGdTHGGgsgA)