# Typescript array of union type - identify type by structure

Tags: typescript

I have a union of two different types, and an array of this union type.
I want to get an error when I try to pass a combination that doesn't exist on any of the interfaces.

```
interface IMenuItem {
  title: string;
  theme: 'primary' | 'secondary';
}

interface IMenuDivider {
  isDivider: boolean;
  margin?: number;
}

type TItem = IMenuItem | IMenuDivider;

const items: TItem[] = [
  {
    title: 'item title',
    isDivider: true // doesn't error
  }
]
```

I'd expect this example to trigger an error since this combination isn't defined in any of the interfaces composing the union.

How should I type my TItem to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be reproducible.

Comment: I updated the post. It was throwing an error because I forgot to mark `margin` as optional. But now that I did, it's not throwing an error

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370222/why-does-a-b-allow-a-combination-of-both-and-how-can-i-prevent-it

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out.
Apparently for this to work they need to share a property to discriminate by.
Not sure 100% why, but adding the type attribute works:

```
interface IMenuItem {
  type: 'item';
  title: string;
  theme: 'primary' | 'secondary';
}

interface IMenuDivider {
  type: 'divider';
  isDivider: boolean;
  margin?: number;
}

type TItem = IMenuItem | IMenuDivider;

const items: TItem[] = [
  {
    type: 'item',
    title: 'item title',
    isDivider: true // Error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'isDivider' does not exist in type 'IMenuItem'.
  }
]
```

PS - I can *guess* why. Without the type attribute, typescript can't really know which interface I was aiming for, so it can't tell me which property is wrong. ‍♂️