# Type which allows nullable members of any of its options

Tags: typescript, types

I have a function that can take arguments of types `A` or `B`, which have some members in common but lack others. Within the body of the function, however, I'd like to be able to reference members that occur on only `A` or only `B`, with the understanding that they may be undefined at runtime.

An example looks like this:

```
type A = {
  common: number;
  a_only: string;
}

type B = {
  common: number;
  b_only: string;
}

type ArgType = A | B; // this doesn't actually work in the desired fashion

function takesAorB(arg: ArgType) {
  if (arg.common > 1) {
    // no need to check for undefined since both A and B have `common`
  }
  if (arg.a_only?.length) {
    // the effective type of `arg.a_only` should be `string | undefined`,
    // since the property exists on A but not B
  }
  if (arg.b_only?.length) {
    // the effective type of `arg.b_only` should be `string | undefined`
    // since the property exists on B but not A
  } 
}
```

I can get pretty close by doing something like this:

```
type ArgType = A | B | Partial<A> | Partial<B>
```

However, this makes *every* member of `A` and `B` optional. I would like it if the members that `A` and `B` have in common were still available as non-nullable. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3B7yN) solve your problem? If yes, I will write an answer; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: If the shared members have the same type, https://tsplay.dev/wOlkRN

Comment: @jcalz Added a concrete example which should hopefully illuminate what I want to do.

Comment: Do you really mean *nullable*, or do you mean *`undefined`-able*? :-)

Comment: Okay now this looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46370222/2887218), at least to the extent that you think `A` should actually *prohibit* the `b_only `property instead of being merely *unconcerned* about it.  You can use the `ExclusifyUnion` utility type from my answer there to write `ExclusifyUnion<A | B>` and it will probably do what you want.

Comment: Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1nZAN)? I've gone with "If the property only exists on A or only on B, it should be optional" (rather than `| null`) in `ArgType`. The key bit is the `MergeAsOptional` type. I wouldn't be surprised if it's more complicated than it should be, though.

Comment: I would beware of this, though, since from a types perspective, whatever you pass in doesn't match the definition. In particular, if you pass in a `B` and the *assign to* an `A`-only property, that object shouldn't really have that property. Although excess properties are generally allowed, this seems a step over the line to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```typescript
type ArgType =
    (A & {[Key in Exclude<keyof B, keyof A>]?: B[Key]}) |
    (B & {[Key in Exclude<keyof A, keyof B>]?: A[Key]});
```

That describes a union of two types:

- `A` intersected with an object type with an optional property for every property in `B` that doesn't already exist in `A`. (Is the `?` before the `:` after the key that makes it optional.)
- `B` intersected with an object type with an optional property for every property in `A` that doesn't already exist in `B`.

I haven't tried to make any provision there for types where `A` and `B` have the same property name but differing types for it.

Instead of defining that directly, you could use a generic utility type to do it if you need to do this with other types:

```typescript
// Utility type
type MergeAsOptional<A, B> =
    (A & {[Key in Exclude<keyof B, keyof A>]?: B[Key]}) |
    (B & {[Key in Exclude<keyof A, keyof B>]?: A[Key]});

// Using it
type ArgType = MergeAsOptional<A, B>;
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oGMD2BbX2AdgFxSECuuARhAE4DcaGAhgPpEA2IpAzsLQEtCAc0YBfRilCQoAIQTIm6HPiKkK1OowxQq7Ql1JVs2DhGaFxk6dACydYRBg8A8mGACizDgB4YAGjkAPgQlKAAKOAAyZABtAGkIECghKABRAA9MDnIAEwgfAGsk7AAzOUDikDLYIIBdAH5SWQSkurEASigAHzDw+RikVuTUzOy8gqqagKgp8tl6pthh9o7rcGgYWmEAFQ2Fe22nV3dPQm8-QIXJUvJCTA8iKGBmYp4YbFpZcOZt0i3dhsuqgdAJyj9tgA6FQEQhQEIARmBYR0AHpUWRsGQIBBcs8sZgABYQTCFKClT5QO75UpCXFQHhCTDQYzAQmwKAWPHyQnMABu0AABjCiIKwmIwmCIr9hJC2JwQA1IWYRGzkTo0Ri2dAIKVSiSPALnvsaoKZXL9FxBQzCdhyBw8TQoIKAHL2jjMKhmHx8QQiIKCwKM+7QbVQMC0bCQWigKAQDICPg8KBPOBUcjATGZ2TiyXg816BUIeCIUreHgQdUa9Do57EuN6g0CI02FPlM1QwsGEDWni2+2OoVujger0FYymcyEAMMpmh+sRqN0WPxxPAZNPeTpzOEbCZmC5sRAA)