# How to create an interface with generic, conditional and optional property?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create an interface which involves conditional types but I have an issue related to optional parameter.
I receive
`Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'true'` error for my boolean property.

react-select library is inspired me to build this behaviour. They have used it to handle isMulti property to decide value is either MultiValue or SingleValue

```
export declare type OnChangeValue<Option, IsMulti extends boolean> = IsMulti extends true ? MultiValue<Option> : SingleValue<Option>;
```

reference link: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/packages/react-select/src/Select.tsx

[Below code playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcCMyDeAsAFDLLAIYioYDOwYwVAXMrWFKAOYDcJAviRKhIsRCnTYATAUHESEAB5YMUMOXDR4SZAEkAInEgAlOCC4QAYsAA2ogDwkyANWRLIIACa1kGAEYAVhAIYAA0TsgA6gwAFgDCAK7sGAC2uiBYCWAAKm6KHt7IfhgYNhBmyAC8yBwJECQAfAQRYBisqHBqwHA29tFg8UmtaRlZue4QXj7wNrQoAPxomFgy7cs4DXykyDCYKQBycCkQrADWEACeGDDIzltkAO6xickjmWCs-YOv6e-ZW3IFMpVOoRFpxHprHZoAB5LCMKi0ewAaUu2QuWBQEymyHOVxuZguoVueQKPn8QRCTSI2xgwAgNk881YqIu6Mx92QniMEGZekMJjMFihDmcmwEQmIShUahqGJQuhFsPhTBAtAAytwyuyIPZxvlJoUKcEwE1qorbKI4Qi1Y5tnjrshsuFttlGlswWIdLo6dCoM1tgBBELAABuDAu6rAnTAApObA43ABJAA9CmdqAelzgjZOkZVUCZepKGr1MYIDBoFAerQlVBaKwLX7raqNVqIDr7D7LdAGgBtAC6VWQfYiNLIZG5kFY44nZFaM4ic7IFCoNHoNtYACJDVuXcvkPx98vdqlDsdt8HGOGwJHo2o43ulxOngMXsNfllWDM5sS08gAFEoEwKBWB1ZAAHIfwgCDyB8EAMHUOBaHoLgQDgPwyhqDA5UxSDahg5BnyPCISOIAceCAA)

```
interface Prop1 {
  iconPosition: string;
}

interface Prop2 {}

export interface IDateRangeFilter<
  V extends object,
  WithCustomInputT extends boolean = true
> {
  to: Partial<WithCustomInputT extends false ? Prop2 : Prop1>;
  fromName: keyof V;
  withCustomInput: WithCustomInputT;
}

export interface IFilterOptions<KeyType extends keyof any, V extends object> {
  field?: KeyType;
  date?: IDateRangeFilter<V>;
}

export type IFilterOptionsSingleType<T extends object> = IFilterOptions<
  keyof T,
  T
>;
interface Ifilter {
  ActivityStartDate: string;
}
// final declaration
export const ReferralsFilters: IFilterOptionsSingleType<Ifilter>[] = [
  {
    date: {
      to: {
        iconPosition: "end",
      },
      fromName: "ActivityStartDate",
      withCustomInput: false, // Error: Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'true' 
    },
  },
];
```

The aim here is that

- if `withCustomInput` key is true, `Prop1` interface will be the type for `to` key.
- if `withCustomInput` key is false, `Prop2` interface will be the type for `to` key.

Comment: Your reference link is dead

Comment: You never pass a second type argument to `IDateRangeFilter`, so it always uses the default of `true`.  I'm not sure where you want to fix this, but that's the problem.  You could do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/w8gn4W) maybe?  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (but please [edit] the question to [replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for you answers. I updated link and I added codesandbox link for who wants to exact error. The reason why i don't declare true for WithCustomInputT is that I  want to control it in the json not on the type declaration.

Comment: I checked [your suggestion](https://tsplay.dev/w8gn4W) but I want to give error for `iconPosition` when WithCustomInputT is false.

Comment: ① Please put the error message as plaintext in the question; external links are nice supplements but they do not suffice... we can't require people to navigate away from SO to see the code and errors relevant to the question. ② Your `Prop2` doesn't prohibit the `iconPosition` property; extra properties in TS are not type errors. If you want `Prop2` to prohibit `iconPosition` then you need to give it a type like `{iconPosition?: never}` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAL51N). Does that work for you?

Comment: Thank you for your assist on the question. That's the good suggestion actually but the problem will be that when I have countless property or complex prop, defining `never` for all properties will take too much time.

Comment: ① Could you address this, please? ② "too much time": That sounds like the next problem you hit after resolving the one in the question. You can save time and build mutually exclusive unions programmatically, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKbAgm) for example, but this really seems to be out of scope for the question as originally asked.  Could we please limit the scope here to the original question and then if you have followup problems you can't resolve you can open a new question? I'm happy to mention the `AndNot` approach in my answer but only briefly.  Thoughts?

Comment: ① I removed the image and i mentioned error text in both the code and issue description. I hope the question looks more sufficient now.  ② Yes, according to my question, it's slightly out of scope but that is what i was aiming to do. In the example, you have shared can work. I really appreciate your answer and your effort while answering my questions. Should i still need to open separate question for the last requirement ?

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance; if that works for you then great, otherwise if you still have further issues you might want to open another question.  It will probably be a number of hours before I write my answer because it is past my bedtime now.

Comment: All good. Thank you once again. I am waiting for your answer to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with the code in the question as asked is that you give `IDateRangeFilter<V>` a [default generic type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of `true` and never pass in any explicit type argument for the `date` field of `IFilterOptions`, so the default of `true` is always used.  You can fix that by explicitly saying that `date` can be either `IDateRangeFilter<V, true>` or `IDateRangeFilter<V, false>`. That is, use a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types):

```
interface IFilterOptions<KeyType extends keyof any, V extends object> {
    field?: KeyType;
    date?: IDateRangeFilter<V, true> | IDateRangeFilter<V, false>;
}
```

---

That's the answer to the question as asked. But since unions are not *exclusive* in TypeScript, and since object types are not sealed (a request for sealed types is at [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)), you'll need to do more work if you want to prohibit, say, an `iconPosition` property for `Prop2`.  See [Why does A | B allow a combination of both, and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46370222/2887218) for a relevant question and its answer.

We can define an `AndNot<T, U>` utility type so that if `T` and `U` are object types with some non-overlapping property keys, the type `AndNot<T, U>` will allow a `T` but prohibit a `U` by requiring that any keys of `U` not present in `T` be missing (well, [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#optional-properties) keys whose value is of type [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type)):

```
type AndNot<T, U> = T & { [K in Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>]?: never }
```

And now your definition of `IDateRangeFilter` can use `AndNot<Prop2, Prop1>` and `AndNot<Prop1, Prop2>` to distinguish the types from each other:

```
interface IDateRangeFilter<
    V extends object,
    WithCustomInputT extends boolean
> {
    to: Partial<WithCustomInputT extends false ?
        AndNot<Prop2, Prop1> : AndNot<Prop1, Prop2>>;
    fromName: keyof V;
    withCustomInput: WithCustomInputT;
}
```

---

Let's test it:

```
const ReferralsFilters: IFilterOptionsSingleType<Ifilter>[] = [
    {
        date: {
            to: {
                iconPosition: "end",
            },
            fromName: "ActivityStartDate",
            withCustomInput: true,
        },
    },
    {
        date: {
            to: {},
            fromName: "ActivityStartDate",
            withCustomInput: false,
        },
    },
    {
        date: {
            to: {
                iconPosition: "end", // error!
            },
            fromName: "ActivityStartDate",
            withCustomInput: false,
        },
    },
];
```

Looks good; `iconPosition` is prohibited when `withCustomInput` is `false`, and allowed when it is `true`, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcCMyDeAsAFDJnLAIYioYDOwYw1AXMnWFKAOYDcJAXxIlQkWIhTpsAJgKDhxMAE8sKAIIgAJgDkMYADwAVADTIAqgD5kAXmSHkAMgLIA2gGkKIZAFEAHggAbAFdNCH0AawglDBhzU0jo2MMLAF0AfjYQCAA3aGQhYhFwaHgkZABJABE4SAAlOBBuCAAxYACxfRJyZAA1ZAhfSC06ZAwAIwArCAQwYy7yAHVGAAsAYSCODABbcpAsILB7AaHNEbGMDACIBpIrIlJyMAw2VDgoJjgA-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)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this does what you want, but I think this might work?

```js
type IFilterOptions<T> = 
  (
    { 
      withCustomInput: true,
      prop1: T
    } | {
      withCustomInput: false,
      prop2: T
    }
  ) & {
      fromName: string;
      date: {
        to: T
      }
}

const foo1: IFilterOptions<number> = {
  date: {
    to: 123,
  },
  fromName: 'ActivityStartDate',
  withCustomInput: true,
  prop1: 123,
}

const foo2: IFilterOptions<number> = {
  date: {
    to: 123,
  },
  fromName: 'ActivityStartDate',
  withCustomInput: false,
  prop2: 123,
}
```

Comment: Hi, This approach works if it's only the way to do it. But yes I am trying to do that behaviour. Thanks for your answer.