# How can I differentiate types with overlapping optional types and without a discriminator?

Tags: typescript

If I have two types with an overlapping property, but different optional properties, the types can be used interchangeably. **Is there a way I can prevent this, so they cannot be used interchangeably?** I understand the concept of discriminator properties, but I am not able to add additional properties to the interfaces.

Example: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnIK4jACOeEAjAPwBcyAzmFKAOYDcOyCA9gLbecjU6DZmwC+WLKEixEKAEKZ2BYqQBMg+oxCt2XXvw3DtYiVxD1kcGugC8i3MpLkaAcjguANLp58Qr917iWAD0wcgAcpzIAKJQUJxQWGYWAEY0CnZwbBIwBAhgwPzIMJycABRpyHIAlPbIocgAJlEgnGAAFsxYQQ2RMXEJWCXlcNUsQA)

```js
interface A {
  unique1?: string;
  common?: string; // Can be optional or not
}

interface B {
  unique2?: string;
  common?: string; // Can be optional or not
}

const a: A = {
  unique1: 'a',
  common: 'a',
}

// No Error
const b: B = a;


function foo(b: B) {
  // do nothing
}

// No Error
foo(a);
```

Comment: Can you modify the interfaces or not?  If not, then this is just a design limitation, see [ms/TS#42479](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42479). If so then you can tell each one that the other property does *not* exist, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NBdVkW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I cannot modify the interfaces. They are auto generated from another tool. I can potentially wrap the types like `Wrapper<A>` if there is some way a wrapper could force the exclusion. The wrapped type would need to be used interchangeably with the non-wrapped type though (e.g. `const a1: Wrapped<A>; const a2: A = a1;`)

Comment: If you need something programmatic, does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbraBm) version work for you? But that's essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46370222/2887218). Let me know how you want to proceed.

Comment: I don't think that is what I want. I am fine to accept an answer of "this is just a design limitation"

Comment: I found a way to modify the type generation tool to add additional discriminator property like `__type?: 'TypeName'` to each interface, so I will go with that.

Comment: Sounds good. Do you want to write up an answer to help future users?