# TypeScript: How to create an interface for an object with many keys of the same type and values of the same type?

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-typings, normalizr, typescript-types

I'm building a React Native app in TypeScript with Redux and [Normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr). So I will have noramlized state.

I have four interfaces: `Emotion`, `Need`, `PainData` and `PainReport`:

```
export interface Emotion {
  name: string;
  chosen: boolean;
  rating: number;
}

export interface Need {
  name: string;
  rating: number;
}

export interface PainData {
  note: string;
  emotions: Emotion[];
  needs: Need[];
  date: Date;
}

export interface PainReport {
  [date: string]: PainData
}
```

Now I would like to create an interface that is not an array, but an object an allows several PainReports like this (pseudo code):

```
export interface PseudoPainReportsObject {
  [date: string]: PainData,
  [date: string]: PainData,
  [date: string]: PainData,
  // ... dynamically have as many as I'd like. Maybe 1, maybe 100
}
```

I want to use this for normalized state like you get when using Normalizr.

How would one do such a type or interface?

Comment: `[date: string]` allows arbitrarily many properties.  It makes no sense to have that multiple times.

Comment: It sounds like your existing `PainReport` interface already does exactly what you want.

Comment: @SLaks You are right, wow, thank you. My questions that I guess is, how would one design an interace, that does not allow that? So an interface with just ONE key?

Comment: There is no way to do that.

Comment: @SLaks Thank you! I learned a lot. Mind copying your comments into an answer, so I can accept them?

Comment: @J.Hesters, it's an old questions, yet for future readers there is a way to constrain an object to just ONE key: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60807986

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[date: string]` allows arbitrarily many properties; `PainReport` does exactly what you want.

There is no way to constrain it to only one property.

Comment: There is a way to constrain an object to have only one property.  It is not trivial though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60807986

Comment: Downvote: The second part of the answer is wrong. (See comment by Aidin)

Answer (score 19):

One liner using TypeScript's [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) type:

```
type PseudoPainReportsObject = Record<string, PainData>;
```

`Record<K, V>` represents an object with any number of `K` type keys that map to `V` type values.