# Interface for object with multiple keys of same type with a unique key

Tags: typescript

My question is somewhat similar to this: [TypeScript: How to create an interface for an object with many keys of the same type and values of the same type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52768308/).

I'm trying to create an interface for an object which can have several keys, all optional, but with the same type. In this object, there's also 1 unique key with a boolean value.

At first, I was trying to use a mapped index signature like:

```
const foo : {
  [key in 'String 1' | 'String 2' | 'String 10']? : MyInterface
} = {}
```

However, with this approach, if I add another key like:

```
const foo : {
  valid : boolean
  [key in 'String 1' | 'String 2' | 'String 10']? : MyInterface
} = {}
```

TypeScript complains:

```
A mapped type may not declare properties or methods.
```

I can fix this by doing something like:

```
const foo : {
  [key in 'string_1' | 'string_2' | 'string_10' | 'valid']? : boolean | MyInterface
} = {}
```

which works, but as you can see, it would also mean that `foo.string_10` could also be a `boolean`, which would be incorrect.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really close with your second code block, but you need to separate the `valid: boolean` object type from the indexed object type, and then use an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) to join them. Since you're defining optional properties, I'm assuming you'll want a type alias for this to make it reusable, so:

```typescript
type TheType = {
    [key in "String 1" | "String 2" | "String 10"]?: MyInterface;
} & {
    valid: boolean;
};
```

Alternatively, you can use `Partial<Record<"String 1" | "String 2" | "String 3", MyInterface>>` for the indexed object type; it does the same thing, it's just a style preference either way:

```typescript
type TheType =
    Partial<Record<"String 1" | "String 2" | "String 3", MyInterface>>
    & {
        valid: boolean;
    };
```

Either way, here are some example uses:

```typescript
// Valid, since all the string properties are optional
const foo1: TheType = {
    valid: true,
};

// Valid, has only allowed properties
const foo2: TheType = {
    valid: true,
    "String 1": { someProperty: "x"},
};

// Not valid as desired, has "excess" property
const badFoo: TheType = {
    valid: true,
    "Some Other String": { someProperty: "x"}, // Error here
};
```

[Playground link - indexed type version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlTkBnAewFsIAFKSgB2jHQC4KwpQBzAbiIBfIkTYtkAFQAWESegkBeQiTIBtANYR0yUMgBEAZW59kARn3IAPgeM8QvZACZLNoyYfmADPoC6Afk4MbEhYRAhBIWQAMhUyZAA3OAAbYAATTgAjSkpkiDgQSMEiAHoS5AA1FPSAGgpQfBTk5DBZLntHJkYWKDBgCHJkOCgUZj7KEBSiBAnyMGQYHLNOGTkFFGVieKTUjJaoAFcIGuFissrqtLrpOEGJ5J0mygB3CDTkLuZWfvJp2fnFpQnCtZPIlHEyDt0pxuEcTvF3B1zPpOAQKDR6N1WBwDAAPfRCE5CM7lABylHmUPet2QaQGwBGV2QN0G+gguKQ5HIlk+PTYfxAc2QmTgaQAYjkQWtwVtIZcYYdjqpSEYMcgAPKtaDIOx8FGEdG0BhfXo4-T4wmnIA)

[Playground link - `Partial<Record<__>>` version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlTkBnAewFsIAFKSgB2jHQC4KwpQBzAbiIBfIkTYtkAFQAWESegkBeEmTpwoYYHAA2AHgBKEBJSgATXQCIAytz7IAjBeQAfZNdsheyAExPX7nk9kAGYLABo0LBxYRAgAPjiVUgAyQiSyUgA3HWBTTgAjSkptCDgQQQyhQSIAehrkADUc0wjyUHwdbWQwWS5AryZGFg1gCHJkdRRmTUoQHSJjEHIwZBgi+04ZOQUURTSM7O1czm4AVwgw4Wq6xuaI6Thx2e10Ce1tSgB3CFNkQeZWKNyAtZstVkVvJtZPIlPsyIdjt0oOdLhkAnZHJwCBQaPQhqwOG4AB4WISXKqiG4AOUoKwRv0eyFMY2AUB+90ZFggRKQ5HITn+wzYIKWK3ycFMADEilDtrDiAdmidkRd0tZccgAPI9aDIGz9CxYnG0BgAjSEiwkslXIA)

Comment: I totally forgot I could use intersections! Thanks, that fits perfectly.