# Typescript: check if a type is a union

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to check if a given type is a union?

```
type IsUnion<T> = ???
```

---

Why I need this: in my code, I have the only case when some received type can be a union. I handle it with a distributive conditional type. However, it can be not obvious for one who looks at this code why a DCT is used in the first place. So I want it to be explicit like: `IsUnion<T> extends true ? T extends Foo ...`

I've made a few attempts with `UnionToIntersection`, with no results.  I've also come up with this one:

```
type IsUnion<T, U extends T = T> =
    T extends any ?
    (U extends T ? false : true)
    : never
```

It gives `false` for non unions, but for some reason it gives `boolean` for unions... And I have no idea why. I also tried to `infer` U from T, with no success.

P.S. My use case may seem to someone as not perfect/correct/good, but anyway the question in the title has arised and I wonder if it's possible (I feel that it is, but am having hard time to figure it out myself).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So it seems I've come up with an answer myself!

Here is the type (thanks Titian Cernicova-Dragomir for simplifying it!):

```
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true

type Foo = IsUnion<'abc' | 'def'> // true
type Bar = IsUnion<'abc'> // false
```

And again [UnionToIntersection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/9259778) of jcalz came in handy!

The principle is based on the fact that a union `A | B` does not extend an intersection `A & B`.

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20UnionToIntersection%3CU%3E%20%3D%20(U%20extends%20any%20%3F%20(k%3A%20U)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3A%20never)%20extends%20((k%3A%20infer%20I)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%3F%20I%20%3A%20never%0A%0Atype%20IsUnion%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%5BT%5D%20extends%20%5BUnionToIntersection%3CT%3E%5D%20%3F%20false%20%3A%20true%0A%0Atype%20Foo%20%3D%20IsUnion%3C%27sdf%27%20%7C%20%27zcx%27%3E%0Atype%20Bar%20%3D%20IsUnion%3C%27sdf%27%3E)

UPD. I was silly enough to not develop my type from the question into this one, which also works fine:

```
type IsUnion<T, U extends T = T> =
    (T extends any ?
    (U extends T ? false : true)
        : never) extends false ? false : true
```

It distributes union `T` to constituents, also `T` and then checks if `U` which is a union extends the constituent `T`. If yes, then it's not a union (but I still don't know why it doesn't work without adding `extends false ? false : true`, i.e. why the preceding part returns `boolean` for unions).

Comment: Isn't the condition `[T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ` sufficient?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Oh, it seems it is, indeed :D

Comment: I'm pretty dumb I guess.  I looked at this answer, but in my mind I came up with it from scratch.  Now I realize that it's virtually identical.  But to answer the question of why the extra conditional: `U` is distributed.  So youre getting basically a nested for loop here, and the fact that some members don't extend the others includes `true` in the output.  When compared against itself, a member will evaluate `false`.  Therefore for unions the result is `true | false`, AKA `boolean`.

Comment: Why are both sides of `[T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>]` tupled? Wouldn't `T extends UnionToIntersection<T>` work?

Comment: @3dGrabber because if we omit the square brackets, then we will have a *naked* type parameter `T`, which will be "distributed" by Typescript. More: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51651499/typescript-what-is-a-naked-type-parameter

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for optional unions such as `string | undefined`

Answer (score 4):

> **NOTE:** This answer was for a case where someone explicitly did not want to use `UnionToIntersection`.  That version is simple and easy to understand, so if you have no qualms about `U2I`, go with that.

I just looked at this again and with the help of @Gerrit0 came up with this:

```js
// Note: Don't pass U explicitly or this will break.  If you want, add a helper
// type to avoid that.
type IsUnion<T, U extends T = T> = 
  T extends unknown ? [U] extends [T] ? false : true : false;

type Test = IsUnion<1 | 2> // true
type Test2 = IsUnion<1> // false
type Test3 = IsUnion<never> // false
```

Seemed like it could be further simplified and I'm pretty happy with this.  The trick here is distributing `T` but not `U` so that you can compare them.  So for `type X = 1 | 2`, you end up checking if `[1 | 2] extends [1]` which is false, so this type is `true` overall.  If `T = never` we also resolve to `false` (thanks Gerrit).

If the type is not a union, then `T` and `U` are identical, so  this type resolves to `false`.

#### Caveats

There are some cases in which this doesn't work. Any union with a member that's assignable to another will resolve to `boolean` because of the distribution of `T`.  Probably the simplest example of this is when `{}` is in the union because almost everything (even primitives) are assignable to it.  You'll also see it with unions including two object types where one is a subtype of the other, i.e. `{ x: 1 } | { x: 1, y: 2 }`.

#### Workarounds

1. Use a third `extends` clause (like in Nurbol's answer)

```js
(...) extends false ? false : true;
```

2. Use `never` as the false case:

```js
T extends unknown ? [U] extends [T] ? never : true : never;
```

3. Invert the `extends` at the call site:

```js
true extends IsUnion<T> ? Foo : Bar;
```

4. Since you probably need a conditional type to use this at the call site, wrap it:

```js
type IfUnion<T, Yes, No> = true extends IsUnion<T> ? Yes : No;
```

There are a lot of other variations that you can do with this type depending on your needs.  One idea is to use `unknown` for the positive case.  Then you can do `T & IsUnion<T>`.  Or you could just use `T` for that and call it `AssertUnion` so that the whole type becomes `never` if it's not a union.  The sky's the limit.

Thanks to @Gerrit0 and @AnyhowStep on gitter for finding my bug & giving feedback on workarounds.

Comment: I'm confused that what does `T extends unknown` do? Once I remove this judgement, it failed.

Comment: @RickShao See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types - this triggers "distribution" of the conditional - kind of like a `map` over type unions. These days I'd usually write `T extends T ? ...` for something like that - it's shorter and maybe a little clearer. 

Many/most people are surprised by distributive conditional types when they first encounter them.

Answer (score 3):

Both answers provide by others here will provide likely unexpected results for the following:

```js
type Foo = IsUnion<'a' | string> // false!?
type Bar = IsUnion<boolean>      // true!?
```

This is because of the way Typescript collapses types:

```js
type a = 'a' | string // string
```

So unless one can control that the provided union type is never collapsed `IsUnion` is not currently possible and is probably a bad idea as it could lead to unexpected and surprising results.

Comment: `IsUnion<'a' | string>` being `false` is correct; `"a" | string` is just a long-winded way of writing `string`, completely aside from `IsUnion`: `type X = "a" | string;` makes `X` an alias for `string`. `IsUnion<boolean>` being `true` is initially surprising, but only initially. `boolean` is `true | false`, which is a union.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for TypeScript 5:

```
type IsUnion<T> = (
  [T, never] extends [infer U, never]
    ? U extends unknown ? [T, keyof U] extends [U | boolean, keyof T] ? false : true
    : never
    : never
) extends false ? false : true;
```

Works with boolean and empty object