# TypeScript: enforce string literal type to have only one value

Tags: typescript, types

Let's use following string literal as an example:

```
type Country = "RU" | "US" | "CN"
```

### TL;DR;

The question is: **is there any operator that can enforce a certain enum to accept only one possible value?** Something like `First<Country>` or `Single<Country>`.

### Reasoning

There is the `Exclude` operation which subtracts a set of certain values from another set of possible values. Using `Pick`, `Omit`, `Exclude`, etc. applied on a set of values, a new set of values is returned, which swill allows potentially multiple values.

Usecase I'm interested in: `Replace<T, K extends keyof T, NEW>` which replaces a key in `T` with a new type `NEW`. The `K extends keyof T` allows multiple keys on `T`. I'm trying to find if it's possible to limit down to define only one possible values (i.e. if more than one passed, TS would throw an error).

If there's no way to limit down the set of allowed values, likely proven, that'd be still a valid answer.

Comment: What enum do you mean when you write "this enum?"

Comment: Could you write some code which shows which situations you want to allow and which situations you'd like to disallow?

Comment: thx guys for the interest. I have improved my question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an actual enum instead of a string union. It might look like this:

```js
export enum Country {
  RU = 'Russia',
  US = 'United States',
  NZ = 'New Zealand',
}
```

Then it is simply a matter of asserting that your value is one of the types. Eg: `Country.NZ`.

*Note*: Type `"New Zealand"` is not assignable to type `Country.NZ`, as it is  a string. To check that the strings match you might use a reverse mapping.

Check out the docs on enums and reverse mappings here -> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a passed type [is a union](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53955431/9259778)

```
type Single<T> = IsUnion<T> extends true ? Error<'Must not be a union'>  : T

interface Error<M> {msg: M}

type x = Single<'foo' | 'bar'> // Error<'Must not be a union'>
type y = Single<'foo'> // foo
```

The `Error` type may only serve type-check purposes, and doesn't have to be implemented in runtime. It is supposed that it will generate a type error somewhere down the program, when `string` is expected but `Error<...>` is received.

Comment: The `isUnion` answers whether the type is a union or not. However, I'm looking for a way to narrow down a union into a single allowed value. Could be 'FirstInUnion' or `LastInUnion`.

Comment: @ducin Unions don't guarantee any order of its constituents. You are doing something wrong if you need this

Comment: You're right, I don't need the order. But I do need to enforce that the union has only a single item.
I need to perform an operation on an object type - I need to replace a field's original type with a new passed type. But I want to be able to enforce it to define only a single field. Not a whole range of fields (which is the default), because its simply too much error-prone.