# How to type an array's values with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the code below I am retrieving each key from an object, removing the digits and duplicates and then I store them in an array. I'd like to use that array as a type.

Here's what the color object looks like.

```
const color = {
    blue100: '#...',
    blue500: '#...',
    red100: '#...',
    red500: '#...',
    yellow100: '#...',
    yellow500: '#...',
    ...
}
```

Here's what I came up with so far

```
const colorChars = Object.keys(color).map((x) => x.replace(/[0-9]/g, ''))
const colorArray = [...new Set(colorChars)]
const colorNames = colorArray as const

export type ColorNameType = typeof colorNames
// expected: type ColorNameType = 'blue' | 'red' | 'yellow'
```

Here's the error I get

```
A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.
```

The error disappears if I wrap `colorArray` like so `[...colorArray]` but it doesn't solve the issue because the type stays as `String[]`. Any idea on how to solve this or is there another attractive work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to convert object keys to union type you can simply use `keyof typeof YourConstObject` like this:

```
const color = {
    blue100: '#1',
    blue500: '#2',
    red100: '#3',
    red500: '#4',
    yellow100: '#5',
    yellow500: '#6',
} as const;

type Keys = keyof typeof color;//"blue100" | "blue500" | "red100" | "red500" | "yellow100" | "yellow500"
```

Or if you need to create union type with values of object you can do like this:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]

type values = ValueOf<typeof color>//"#1" | "#2" | "#3" | "#4" | "#5" | "#6"
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=77&pln=12&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBKA2IBOMC8MDeAoGuYCN4BXAUwEYAGCgLhgHIBiMugGhz0NIFYrbGAmVu1xISAE0o16DAMxC8MUWJ5TGAFnl4AniXiIA7pL4Mum3Dr0h9K4wDYhAXxgBDCHHDQA3FixQtABxIYAGkSLTd0AGswkAAzGD9AuPdEJE8AenSAIk5yKiyYAB8YHOISFQLirKVJSpKlCqKSiwNapqyWqwqfRKCANWcygHlYgB4AFQA%20NBhxgG1orWTxgF0egKCAN0HSCJgB4bHe5IRkScyspjrL-mvZO7U7rjvbLJ8sIA)

But note that whenever you try to manipulate the object keys like using `map, push, replace` so `ts` compiler have face with `string[]` type because it does not make sense for the compiler your new array, like: `blue, red...`.

Comment: Accepted answer thanks to the last paragraph, this shed some light.

Answer (score 1):

First of all we need to iterate over `color` keys an get rid of `number` sufix.

```js
const color = {
    blue100: '#hex',
    blue500: '#hex',
    red100: '#hex',
    red500: '#hex',
    yellow100: '#hex',
    yellow500: '#hex',
} as const;

type MapColor<T extends Record<`${string}${number}`, string>> = {
    [Prop in keyof T as RemoveNumber<Prop>]: T[Prop]
}

// type Result = {
//     readonly blue: "#hex";
//     readonly red: "#hex";
//     readonly yellow: "#hex";
// }
type Result = MapColor<typeof color>
```

We need just to get rid of `number` suffix.

This is our main util

```js
type RemoveNumber<T> = T extends string ? ReduceToString<Filter<T>> : never
```

Let's start from the end. Our `Filter` utility type converts the string into tuple and removes all numbers:

```js
const color = {
    blue100: '#hex',
    blue500: '#hex',
    red100: '#hex',
    red500: '#hex',
    yellow100: '#hex',
    yellow500: '#hex',
} as const;

type Filter<T extends string, Cache extends string[] = []> =
    T extends `${infer Color}${infer Tail}`
    ? Color extends `${number}`
    ? Cache
    : Filter<Tail, [...Cache, Color]>
    : never

{
    // ["b", "l", "u", "e"] | ["r", "e", "d"] | ["y", "e", "l", "l", "o", "w"] 
    type Test = Filter<keyof typeof color>
}
```

Because we need to operate on string, we need to convert it back - to the string.

```js
type Elem = string;

type ReduceToString<
    Arr extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>,
    Result extends string = ''
    > = Arr extends []
    ? Result
    : Arr extends [infer H]
    ? H extends Elem
    ? `${Result}${H}`
    : never
    : Arr extends readonly [infer H, ...infer Tail]
    ? Tail extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>
    ? H extends Elem
    ? ReduceToString<Tail, `${Result}${H}`>
    : never
    : never
    : never;
{
    type Test = ReduceToString<Filter<keyof typeof color>>
}
```

Let's make a quick summarize. We ended up with this type:

```js
// type Result = {
//     readonly blue: "#hex";
//     readonly red: "#hex";
//     readonly yellow: "#hex";
// }
type Result = MapColor<typeof color>
```

Now we need to convert `keyof Result` to a tuple with permutation of all possible states:

```js
// credits goes to https://twitter.com/WrocTypeScript/status/1306296710407352321
type TupleUnion<U extends string, R extends any[] = []> = {
    [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S]>;
}[U];

{
    // | TupleUnion<"red" | "yellow", ["blue"]> 
    // | TupleUnion<"blue" | "yellow", ["red"]> 
    // | TupleUnion<"blue" | "red", ["yellow"]>
    type Test = TupleUnion<keyof MapColor<typeof color>>
}
```

This is because `Object.keys` does not give you a guarantee of key order.

Now we can implement the function:

```js
function colorNames<
    Key extends `${string}${number}`,
    Value extends string,
    Color extends Record<Key, Value>
>(color: Color): TupleUnion<keyof MapColor<Color>>
function colorNames<
    Key extends `${string}${number}`,
    Value extends string,
    Color extends Record<Key, Value>
>(color: Color) {
    return [...new Set(Object.keys(color)
        .map(
            (x) => x.replace(/[0-9]/g, '')
        ))];
}

const result = colorNames(color) // ["blue", "red", "yellow"]

type ColorType = (typeof result)[number] // "blue" | "red" | "yellow"
```

WHole code:

```js
const color = {
    blue100: '#hex',
    blue500: '#hex',
    red100: '#hex',
    red500: '#hex',
    yellow100: '#hex',
    yellow500: '#hex',
} as const;

// type Result = {
//     readonly blue: "#hex";
//     readonly red: "#hex";
//     readonly yellow: "#hex";
// }
type Result = MapColor<typeof color>

type Filter<T extends string, Cache extends string[] = []> =
    T extends `${infer Color}${infer Tail}`
    ? Color extends `${number}`
    ? Cache
    : Filter<Tail, [...Cache, Color]>
    : never

{
    // ["b", "l", "u", "e"] | ["r", "e", "d"] | ["y", "e", "l", "l", "o", "w"] 
    type Test = Filter<keyof typeof color>
}

type Elem = string;

type ReduceToString<
    Arr extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>,
    Result extends string = ''
    > = Arr extends []
    ? Result
    : Arr extends [infer H]
    ? H extends Elem
    ? `${Result}${H}`
    : never
    : Arr extends readonly [infer H, ...infer Tail]
    ? Tail extends ReadonlyArray<Elem>
    ? H extends Elem
    ? ReduceToString<Tail, `${Result}${H}`>
    : never
    : never
    : never;
{
    // "blue" | "red" | "yellow"
    type Test = ReduceToString<Filter<keyof typeof color>>
}

type RemoveNumber<T> = T extends string ? ReduceToString<Filter<T>> : never

type MapColor<T extends Record<`${string}${number}`, string>> = {
    [Prop in keyof T as RemoveNumber<Prop>]: T[Prop]
}

{
    type Test = MapColor<typeof color>
}

// credits goes to https://twitter.com/WrocTypeScript/status/1306296710407352321
type TupleUnion<U extends string, R extends any[] = []> = {
    [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S]>;
}[U];

{
    // | TupleUnion<"red" | "yellow", ["blue"]> 
    // | TupleUnion<"blue" | "yellow", ["red"]> 
    // | TupleUnion<"blue" | "red", ["yellow"]>
    type Test = TupleUnion<keyof MapColor<typeof color>>
}

function colorNames<
    Key extends `${string}${number}`,
    Value extends string,
    Color extends Record<Key, Value>
>(color: Color): TupleUnion<keyof MapColor<Color>>
function colorNames<
    Key extends `${string}${number}`,
    Value extends string,
    Color extends Record<Key, Value>
>(color: Color) {
    return [...new Set(Object.keys(color)
        .map(
            (x) => x.replace(/[0-9]/g, '')
        ))];
}

const result = colorNames(color) // ["blue", "red", "yellow"]

type ColorType = (typeof result)[number] // "blue" | "red" | "yellow"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKA2IBOMC8MDeAoGuYCN4BXAUwEYAGCgLhgHIBiACxIA86AaHPQ0gViq1GLdlzwwkJACaUa9Zm07dckqQLnDFYvAE8S8RAHdZQhaOUw9BkIfWmRSgL4wAhhDjhoAbixYA9H4wUDoADiQwAEokEETwsOjYAeISJC5S4PA6BMQktABEZnk%20SeKSaRlZqvmFxYGlqelgmZb6RtUiRf6BjljBYZHRsfEwALIuIQDCIIhIADx9JCAAZh4zAHy%20CzAAYgCWcSRzACowbFAkYFLu0Ei7YADmHDATLsAsp6znl9dQtw8A2gBdNAwIFrNAWE5nC5XGAAAwAJBg7ktDs9pshHEiUWiji59o44RYAPzomYfL6wxEYMBEAC2%20EOhJJz1eLAstD2B2O%20PgT3%20ADohS83iQnlMZoCNuJaGASAA3Q6%20bDiJL-PL4PJPPLwLUwPJEPV5Eh5YEAH1BeSQRpN2qkppgFvVOhtRt12vd%20pARsMDosWyO0WGXPOcwA1iQdMsgqFFisEMgNj1erGYABReAkOkgm53e4%20FP9KJSIjAEhHEAAZV%20edmFgAgkgUNDvgNyk0dI2kC4dLMM1m1tpcFEYnEKTCfn97iC6HQLOD0F3x62gSyR0MOTAly3Yf8cSgABKAlkH5ew-t0lnU9dxLEYA-MmUwOWKpCb7efCcpdvNPdgVGHk8QoCvuMB4vsx7iKS4HwGe7hRD%20nZNj2faZnS0p4KSp47u4F5rtIpbllWNYPLMMFPNegy3kiD5whhuCygqSpPi%20zF4Ixr4%20CqeBJBqOR5I6%20qqAJFp5FYRh5P6qaBtAILFoRFbVlOswhocswRlGKwLNGCZIGsSabKmUR0iAioAHL0oyxwLmBcEwLmDwwKS8llopJH3Cp%20yhmR%20kwBxSqFuEYyTBixx2VEoBIFIszUg59x3rSDJMnCTxxb5CQWP8AAKSAgCEMB3DAGnRicbgDCZ5mWWpOV5WsgK0Ec2W5SEx7JtxuABkGILBRKyDzLGOmhQZXRwKouxQO49wgNEQQgDATBQFAIQQNQARQIY42hgKoB0n4ADquXAEcsaVsAtwhFAfjQC4UBEBAfhkAAzBQABsABMACcL0AOyUAALBQ32PXwb2PW9ZCBWBRAhJmACqYC7OAsyw3ZcVPBEdkuGAOhAiCYIgu1oKVgVYAwLD9XpqwwDEFIJDI08lbgjhz5MSgpKCkKEQM8CDXQ3DCNI2mVM03TsMM4OoLAVzMCVlKPiOP85MFoTSQWkcfMkPDiNgLMVrSCJ%20riTYerqrwJpSjAFiq1DMOawLOt8aQBtia0xv8nr9oW1bgRqxrWtI47JqCR7Jsu9YvpSlJ-QycM6u2-7OvFSsPWhf1YSDesw1LEQYDAFA2urMgZkuHS0R1uIADSkZ2bF7kJVVSCEkOMAAGouDkqPuc3vXNp%20rYRcg0VVzoTxtzkGxrAAFLptA9wAlLz8f2%20pkbRinMyzD3%20lYNnuf5%20AhdIMXpcQOXeDDzXSJxfXSWNylFhj6QndTt3oXhSQkVD5Go-t6QE-T6FWeoU56YAsJIW6SBSYcwFHKQwMsSBQEngAeXwAAKw-lAAUGkIAAJmHPCw4gBR0nGJPAhyRcCT1YCA1A4JWACkkDDV4JBJ5%20H%20BQAAtB9QEfhHj0DoPg8huA55z0BPLXwoBICwEkKOYYulj7RFwcgEBapA5GmEtqI2EdDL9B7sdfo6BJ7aRWNIoYc9-iJSssCXiZtnbCWDpoySQA)

List of useful links:

1. [Convert union to tuple](https://catchts.com/union-array) - [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65533827/get-keys-of-an-interface-in-generics/65534971#65534971)
2. [Hex validation in typescript](https://catchts.com/hex-validation) article - [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66851513/a-way-to-mark-arbitrary-strings-in-typescript-template-literals#answer-66852494)
3. [My blog](https://catchts.com/) where you can find some interesting typescript examples
4. [Reduce literal type](https://catchts.com/tuples#reduce) in typescript
5. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68207767/typescript-infer-possible-object-keys-based-on-value-of-previous-argument/68208487#68208487) you can find more explanation of how `Reduce` works with pure js examples

Please keep in mind that it is not required to use `as const` with `color` object. I have used it only for  type utilities test purpose. `colorNames` function is able to infer each `color` key.

If you are interested in function arguments type inference. please take a look [on my article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

`as const` can only be used at declaration.

So this example would work:

```
const color = {
  blue100: '#...',
  blue500: '#...',
  red100: '#...',
  red500: '#...',
  yellow100: '#...',
  yellow500: '#...',

  ...
} as const;
```

but not this:

```js
const colorChars = Object.keys(color).map((x) => x.replace(/[0-9]/g, ''))
const colorArray = [...new Set(colorChars)]
const colorNames = colorArray as const
```

I don't think there is a way to achieve what you're trying to do in Typescript.