# Typescript won't let me iterate through multiple types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a typescript type that looks like this:

```
type Colors = {
  'blue': string;
  'blue20': string;
  'blue40': string;
  'blue60': string;
  'blue80': string;
  'green': string;
  'green20': string;
  'green40': string;
  'green60': string;
  'green80': string;
}
```

There's more colors and color variants but this is a simplified version. I'm trying to generate this like this:

```
type Variations = '' | 20 | 40 | 60 | 80;
type TAllColors = {
  [P in Variations as `blue${P}`]: string;
  [P in Variations as `green${P}`]: string;
};
```

However, I'm getting an error:

> Conversion of type 'boolean' to type '`green${any}`' may be a mistake
> because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was
> intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.ts(2352)

It works if I just have the `blue` line inside but when I add the line for `green` it no longer works and gives me that error. Does anyone know how to accomplish what I'm trying?

Comment: Is your question related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68971574/how-to-type-an-arrays-values-with-typescript ?

Comment: @futur union distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try something like this

```
type Variations = '' | 20 | 40 | 60 | 80;
type Variations2 = '' | 25 | 45 | 65 | 85;
type TAllColors = {
  [P in Variations as `blue${P}`]: string;
}&
{
  [P in Variations2 as `green${P}`]: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is invalid.

You need just replace `blue` and `green` with a union of all allowed colors:

```js
type ColorNames = 'blue' | 'green'

type Variations = '' | 20 | 40 | 60 | 80;

type TAllColors<Color extends string> = {
    [P in Variations as `${Color}${P}`]: string;
};

type Result = TAllColors<ColorNames>

type Colors = {
    'blue': string;
    'blue20': string;
    'blue40': string;
    'blue60': string;
    'blue80': string;
    'green': string;
    'green20': string;
    'green40': string;
    'green60': string;
    'green80': string;
}

// true
type IsCorrect =
    Colors extends Result
    ? Result extends Colors
    ? true
    : false
    : false
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGzgJwHIEMC2EDOUC8UA5AEYICuERUAPsQObIQQB2RAUO6JFAGrrIAlumCC4LPISLU6AJgAMtKABZFdAGxqoADnkBuTt2gAVAIIIE8JMhwAeKyigQAHsFYATPDmBCW9AHwEUADe7FDhUADaAApQgix8AsKi4njoeAAGACTBDsgAvjnR%20RkAugBcUN6%209Ab5Blzg0ABKuOQIwEFmFnl2eRjYOP6GTbCIKJIhYRGkFFSV1fG10%20GzlApECz5LBhHEZJSqm1XbfrszBxCax4tnK-tzujeny3tEjMxsWzXnqx%20sG2%20O3u7yYrCOQLub3%20LGukNeMxhT3hdU4AHo0VAfJRGjwAJI4eDIJgAY06%20HuvScrg8eFaOHawHuAH4oPTGdS3CxPGNrDgWVjkDi9pUAGboBA4CD3MUSqVAA)

**What if green and blue have different variations ?**
Then you need to create appropriate map data structure and iterate over newly created map and variations.

```js
type ColorNames = 'blue' | 'green'

type VariationsBlue = '' | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40
type VariationsGreen = '' | 20 | 40 | 60 | 80;

type VariationsMap = {
    blue: '' | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40;
    green: '' | 20 | 40 | 60 | 80;
}

type NameConvert<T, V> =
    T extends string
    ? V extends string | number
    ? `${T}${V}`
    : never
    : never


type TAllColors<Variations> = {
    [V in keyof Variations]: {
        [P in V as NameConvert<P, Variations[V]>]: string
    }
}

type TransitionResult = TAllColors<VariationsMap>
```

Sush iteration produces two levels of nested properties.

```js
type TransitionResult = {
    blue: {
        blue: string;
        blue10: string;
        blue20: string;
        blue30: string;
        blue40: string;
    };
    green: {
        green: string;
        green20: string;
        green40: string;
        green60: string;
        green80: string;
    };
}
```

We need somehow to obtain all values from above object and merge them. Retrieving all values is relatively easy:

```js
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type TransitionResult = Values<{
    blue: {
        blue: string;
        blue10: string;
        blue20: string;
        blue30: string;
        blue40: string;
    };
    green: {
        green: string;
        green20: string;
        green40: string;
        green60: string;
        green80: string;
    };
}>
```

As you might have noticed we ended up with union of all values whereas we need an intersection.

```js
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never;

type Result = UnionToIntersection<Values<{
    blue: {
        blue: string;
        blue10: string;
        blue20: string;
        blue30: string;
        blue40: string;
    };
    green: {
        green: string;
        green20: string;
        green40: string;
        green60: string;
        green80: string;
    };
}>>
```

Whole code:

```js
type ColorNames = 'blue' | 'green'

type VariationsBlue = '' | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40
type VariationsGreen = '' | 20 | 40 | 60 | 80;

type VariationsMap = {
    blue: '' | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40;
    green: '' | 20 | 40 | 60 | 80;
}

type NameConvert<T, V> =
    T extends string
    ? V extends string | number
    ? `${T}${V}`
    : never
    : never


type TAllColors<Variations> = {
    [V in keyof Variations]: {
        [P in V as NameConvert<P, Variations[V]>]: string
    }
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never;

type Result = UnionToIntersection<Values<TAllColors<VariationsMap>>>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAwgewDYIE4DkCGBbKBnGAXhgHIAjJAVyhJgB9SBzVKKAOxOFElgDVNUAS0whBCNngBCVWMRK0GARgAM9GACZVDAMxaYAFmXdoMfkJFiJAcRbsipBRr2G1ANj0AOZQG4u4E2bCouJ4ALKYEPYA3sAwcTAU1ABcDmoqappqumqGvvEwzKxsKfIZznrual6%20AL5%20PDBYuIhsAG5QqCAAPAAqADSmAHxEsfE9MFAAHiDsACYEeCBCbIyjcQD8phPTcwtLgitqbJTYZB1rMJsABgAkUT01d7w1VxcpbFDtqG8wH19cxlgPQAgkgkIgUKg8F1AhYQsNiDF8gBtXgwA4wADWUDACAAZqYBEFLHgALopJH5eLIgAK6LYW0wBCaUBaX26NIGsOCElRpMG5Jgi2Wq3ydTqgMJMmhPQRMB6yOxuIJPVJXAA9OqYABjFizQQgAiMBD4GAgBAwAAWIBAEDwSU1i0w2sxCC%20eJQAHcAHTahDYdWYdUAVmU2gA7MH1B5XJKAKpsSw9BAASTYMyhUG1PK6cblAAo49sZmx5jBMGwwJcYPnMSk4wBKIjDVoIQSzGDvT4dJtTEtl-MXOv0vEdGAp4BNwgttuzC6bCf5LtfXySgBK%20EoSBA9gTSdT6Y6eCzOf40t6oPByDQ0O5JPCEEGT64QA)

Comment: What if green and blue have different variations. So I have `type VariationsBlue = '' | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40;` and `type VariationsGreen = '' | 20 | 40 | 60 | 80;`. How would I do it then? Thanks!

Comment: :D yes, it might be a cryptic a bit

Comment: Remove UnionToIntersection and Values and try to understand whats going on. I will provide more explanation tomorrow. Good luck