# Can I turn two types <K, V> into an object type with a single field with those types?

Tags: typescript

I have a function:

```
const singleton = <K extends string, V>(k: K, v: V) => ({[k]: v})
```

The inferred return type of this is `{ [x: string]: V; }`, which means I cannot do:

```
const foo: {bar: 'baz'} = singleton('bar', 'baz');
```

Is it possible to give a better return type to this function in TypeScript so that the second snippet typechecks?

(I'd obviously only expect this to work if the first argument to the function is a literal string.)

I tried the following:

```
<K extends string, V>(k: K, v: V): {[K]: V} => ({[k]: v})
```

but it says:

> A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.(1170)
>
> 'K' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.(2693)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCWYDmAbAplcMC8MA8A0jGgB5RpgAmEcUATokgDQwBqAfABQDWAXDARYA3fqwCUOdjE4BvANrcAuvyEBfMQFgAUNtCRYAMxAh+MgEYBDOvwDklgF43VOOI3SYwnO1ZstvjsQBubV1waFdkd3AAJhdCYjIKaloGZBYOHn5BGBE2MVM5AmU2Z2wpWQVitU0tIA)

Answer (score 3):

There are good reasons this is not type safe. While `T extends string` will ensure `T` is a subtype of `string` it is wrong to think that `T` must be a string literal type. It could also be a union of string literal types:

```
const singleton = <K extends string, V>(k: K, v: V) => ({[k]: v})

const key = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "baz": "bar";
const foo: { bar: number, baz: number } = singleton(key, 0) as Record<typeof key, number>;

// one of these, at random will fail at runtime 
foo.bar.toExponential
foo.baz.toExponential
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCWYDmAbAplcMC8MA8A0jGgB5RpgAmEcUATokgDQwBqAfABQDWAXDARYA3fqwCUOdjE4BvANrcAuvyEBfMQFgAUNtCRY3NAE8cMALIBDKAAsAdHQtUQAW04SpABlsBWGAH4YACIAIwsAL0D+EIs6QIBuXXBoGAAzEBB+GRhQun4wAFdnYLQ6FlCwvMLiuhhVUwRkdEwwHmMWDwkLGgAlNFA6SjwoIwAHNBAUmEMjFgKikvYEnS0AehWYcDQNyZs0CDQWKxgHJ2cYAHd4FBRUiyuYI7p8sCh4Zy3tNJBbHNtMAFESCNNi94BYUJ90j9wn8QIDgWAKK9wdpUcsgA)

Now could typescript do a better job here? Arguably it could infer `Partial<Record<K, V>>`. And there is an issue on this topic which I can't find at the moment.

To get the type you want you will need to use a type assertion in the function body. You can either assert to `Record<K, V>` (with the caveat that if `K` is a union this is unsafe) Or you can assert to `Partial<Record<K, V>>` which is safer but less convenient.

```
const singleton = <K extends string, V>(k: K, v: V) => ({[k]: v})as Partial<Record<K, V>>;

const key = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "baz": "bar";
const foo = singleton(key, 0) 

foo.bar?.toExponential
foo.baz?.toExponential
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCWYDmAbAplcMC8MA8A0jGgB5RpgAmEcUATokgDQwBqAfABQDWAXDARYA3fqwCUOdjE4BvANrcAuvyEBfMQEMaABQ10o8DSjwAlNKDqVCLDuwDcAWABQz0JFjc0ATxwwAshpQABYAdHQaVCAAtpwSUgAMIQCsMAD8MABEAEYaAF4Z-Nl6GY5ObtAwAGYgIL4IyOiYYDzeLPESzs7VICE5dKkhmACiJAAO4BQGRl01vXkDw2MTYFMonS4bQA)

If yo want to get creative you can test to see if `T` is a union. Using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53955431/125734)

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never
const singleton = <K extends string, V>(k: K, v: V) => ({[k]: v})as ( [K] extends [UnionToIntersection<K>] ? Record<K, V>: Partial<Record<K, V>>);

const key = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "baz": "bar";
const foo = singleton(key, 0) 

foo.bar?.toExponential
foo.baz?.toExponential


const foo2 = singleton("key", 0) 
foo2.key
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4oAKGKCADxzgBN8oBDOEFAD8jANYAuWAEo6NAG5IEnKJLgQ5eGWw7dGDCVARwAZnigYZteYs4yRGFVDUbcAWABQRFPmBR8RgHMAGwhgFDoocgBpFnYILh4fXECAGigANSp9SSi0uUl0yxoGAG8AbVEAXUk5AF8pXh4GKDKoytidHjL4MnQsHAJiUhRoqnaRACViJFxOaLTMyQAFXlxSXiDyKa9Z+YyqKikAbg8PLzgfKFEIQXoAWV5gAAsAOlx+TiQAWwYZGgAGF4AVmEUAARAAjXgALzBkkhqzBJ083l8xiQSAi-jgwVCKH0NzS-xkp3c6KQLyhuCELzCAFFWGAUPF1kEPOTKTCafTGczsAgNqSzqioOSAExYwIhMJwBhg64gMFEklkjFil4KoXuDxAA)

Comment: Thanks, your explanation of the type inferred by default makes sense. So there's no way to be more specific and say that a type should be a literal string? I slightly modified your last snippet to get a better inferred type plus I don't want to support key being a union type. Do you think it's still typesafe?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4oAKGKCADxzgBN8oBDOEFAD8jANYAuWAEo6NAG5IEnKJLgQ5eGWw7dGDCVARwAZnigYZteYs4yRGFVDUbcAWABQHoinzAo+IwBzABsIYBQ6KHIAaRZ2CC4eX1wggBooADUqfUlo9LlJDMsaBgBvAG1RAF1JOQBfGV4eBnLoqridHnL4MnQsHAJiUhQYqnaRCtFDOCg2wrrHZ00Abg8vHz9RCEF6AFleYAALADpcfk4kAFsGGRoABmOAVmEoACIAI14AL1fJD95cK9Vu5vHBfFBjEgkJEAnAQmEUPptuk7jI1u5IUhjp9cEJjuEAKKsMAoBKkXjBDyY7HfPGE4mk7AICno9ZgvyYgBMMKCoXCcAYry2IFeKLRGKhnOOwvRoPBmIAzJFSsdVbD4fzBcLRVBUelVcd1XzEULtpyda9eP5gCk4a8pOlhQrJKU6nUgA