# How to flatten nested union types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a union of types having a property also containing union types:

```
type Union =
  | {
      name: "a";
      event:
        | { eventName: "a1"; payload: string }
        | { eventName: "a2"; payload: number };
    }
  | {
      name: "b";
      event: { eventName: "b1"; payload: boolean };
    };
```

I'm trying to flatten it to get a single union type like this:

```
type Result =
  | { name: "a"; eventName: "a1"; payload: string }
  | { name: "a"; eventName: "a2"; payload: number }
  | { name: "b"; eventName: "b1"; payload: boolean };
```

I tried to use mapped typed and various utility types but couldn't figure it out. Is it something that can actually be done?

Comment: I assume you mean with mapped types, utility types and such. It might be possible, but I feel like it would be impossible to encrypt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Link to typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZygXgFBW1APlAbyxxLgEMBbCALigCIy6BuYk7CANwjmGtbfwEonbsABylGvTIBGZlDBkQAGyRkAJrQDOwAE4I4AcygBffiUHCuPCVVoMATPMUq1mqHACuFAEYRdpiwkZhaE5jjkdvQ%20zOHs1ryEVqK2UnQ%20ckwKSqoatD5ISMoQZKgmQTjlGBigkB4QOhDq6GEkANqoBrCIKG0A5JEQfQC6w7REbDht0F0AogAeemQAxsAAPPDIcAA0SYO0ZQB8-SI8IycJqSNjrZNs%20x7bcWyn4pK0EE93bC657gtLVYbHpwC6iEa7AivVIfEzHPq-NwjZ4hSoYMwAegxUAAFsBgGAtNQsToVgBrJBcXQAM1UAHcAHTLJAUDFkDEAVgADABmADsHIcAA4AGwYnn83kAFhkNXA0E2KAAKkgAJI8fxaCCrLYbQ4tYgAChgwkW3HUWigpRAUAA-FBDWTaDAAJRoQ4cJAIZoHES6F2m4Dmy2Gx20AzU-xQVVuj1e9QB%202qqC%20qnVWrQAJobpbFXqoO6LU6lBrOANIPqNpkiAgJDU%20qNdTDQ5yuoAJQanmUwBaUF0VZrdb7w3T8qgC0gqya6H4lgeDHk0Pe0ky2VceSgOn0RlMs72y4XWSXUUczhybgO3j8AVR2DnB5iR8uD9XiI3BSKJTKLAw6m1yjIXRoGZOAdFNScK1oCdtQrFg-2WACgKgECwKArQu0SDt0O7FgsWjVBljILUoAzS1AOgOAkB7YAcWgLRJGjcCYKtEix38XQkACWigIwFCexAWgsIwloIHmCCml4lAwOUKCxJg6dszQjCgA)

The utility type converting a union to an intersection was fundamental: I've taken it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/3370341)

```
type Union =
    | {
        name: "a";
        event:
        | { eventName: "a1"; payload: string }
        | { eventName: "a2"; payload: number };
    }
    | {
        name: "b";
        event: { eventName: "b1"; payload: boolean };
    };

type nested = {
    [n in Union['name']]: {
        [e in Extract<Union, { name: n }>['event']['eventName']]: {
            name: n,
            eventName: e,
            payload: Extract<Union['event'], {eventName: e}>['payload']
        }
    }
}
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/3370341
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type r = UnionToIntersection<nested[keyof nested]>
type Result = r[keyof r]

type Expected =
    | { name: "a"; eventName: "a1"; payload: string }
    | { name: "a"; eventName: "a2"; payload: number }
    | { name: "b"; eventName: "b1"; payload: boolean };

declare const expected: Expected;
declare const result: Result;
// In case types are not the same I expect a type error here
const y: Result = expected
const l: Expected = result
```

I wonder if there is an easier way.

I've started by creating a nested object type, but with the aim of putting `name` and `eventName` on the same level.

The intermediate result was something like this:

```
type nested = {
    a: {
        a1: {
            name: 'a',
            eventName: 'a1',
            payload: string
        },
        a2: {
            name: 'a',
            eventName: 'a2',
            payload: number
        }
    },
    b: {
        b1: {
            name: 'b',
            eventName: 'b1',
            payload: boolean
        }
    }
}
```

Then I've extracted a union of only the inner values types.

I've tried using things like `Extract` on `eventName`, but while it works for `'b1'`, it leads to `never` with `'a1'` and `'a2'`.

```
type b1 = Extract<Union, {event: {eventName: 'b1'}}> // ok
type a1 = Extract<Union, {event: {eventName: 'a1'}}> // never
```

Comment: In the end, I managed to achieve my goal by slighthly changing my initial data structure. But your solution is quite clever and works perfectly :)

Comment: @Ilario Pierbattista can I use your solution in my TS blog? I will put e reference to this question and your name

Comment: @IlarioPierbattista https://catchts.com/flatten-union

Answer (score 1):

Much uglier solution  than @Ilario Pierbattista, but works:

```js
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type/50375286#50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

//https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901
type UnionToOvlds<U> = UnionToIntersection<
  U extends any ? (f: U) => void : never
>;

type PopUnion<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends (a: infer A) => void ? A : never;


type UnionToArray<T, A extends unknown[] = []> = IsUnion<T> extends true
  ? UnionToArray<Exclude<T, PopUnion<T>>, [PopUnion<T>, ...A]>
  : [T, ...A];

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953814/typescript-check-if-a-type-is-a-union#comment-94748994
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true;

type ArrayOfUnions<T> = IsUnion<T> extends true ? UnionToArray<T> : T

//https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types
type Distributive<T> = [T] extends [any] ? T : never

// treat this predicate as Array.prototype.map predicate
type MapPredicate<T> =
  T extends { event: object, name: string }
  ? IsUnion<T['event']> extends true
  ? ArrayOfUnions<T['event']> extends any[]
  ? Distributive<ArrayOfUnions<T['event']>[number]> & { name: T['name'] }
  : T
  : T['event'] & { name: T['name'] }
  : never
//https://catchts.com/tuples#map
// This util works similar to Array.prototype.map
type Mapped<
  Arr extends Array<unknown>,
  Result extends Array<unknown> = []
  > = Arr extends []
  ? []
  : Arr extends [infer H]
  ? [...Result, MapPredicate<H>]
  : Arr extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
  ? Mapped<[...Tail], [...Result, MapPredicate<Head>]>
  : Readonly<Result>;

type Union =
  | {
    name: "a";
    event:
    | { eventName: "a1"; payload: string }
    | { eventName: "a2"; payload: number };
  }
  | {
    name: "b";
    event: { eventName: "b1"; payload: boolean };
  };

type Result = Mapped<UnionToArray<Union>>[number]


type Expected =
  | { name: "a"; eventName: "a1"; payload: string }
  | { name: "a"; eventName: "a2"; payload: number }
  | { name: "b"; eventName: "b1"; payload: boolean };


type Assert = Result extends Expected ? true : false // true
```

Algorithm:

1. Convert union type to array. See UnionToArray
2. Iterate over the array and change all elements. See Mapped & Predicate
3. Convert array to union

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=64&ssc=61&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4oAKGKCADxzgBN8oBDOEFAD8jANYAuWAEo6NAG5IEnKJLgQ5eGWw7dGAWABQUKBKgI4AMzxQMhmbXmLOh4yNtGVUNRtwBuQ4agkLCIKOgA8nIANtyUNPTwZOhYOATEpCjkLrAs7BBcPPyCIgwWkjD2jkqe3niGVP4GgeDQAApIYImZ1HQhSUiRMfhxuTo8DLyS5la4UACClVAK1SJzNep4jc3BXWhIc7i4vCDkqAA086P5ugCucKJwSADucADaALq9H-E2%20LunNG01x4wFwNwg2REu3QByOJwAoqwiFEbpwIKcLu1OqEKKgqFQLq8sf88RcAHQUubvKjZSSvc5QClkqlbAxBaAYP44gFfVCfIEFKCvaGYbB4QgkMgAz4iCy8KKETyg8Gs9nzQ7HcIWXbDPG9TkkwF5QXK6BQnEwjUnPWSVABNktKAAEQQ%20FBCAARjdSBoefR6fzjbpXkUZVBUOsfPa1QBZXhgVq4CCcBBEXg4P3ZCMC3QAbxYGmwkiQHoAVukLnBeABbCCSN24cwAcygAF9Ib8Sa8AOQbbDd6lXE1giEeVZWrU6049vvAAdGsZ8AQfDsuhue70IX2wzXanG6meFufU15wG7Vj14QcAMig%20artdtPYfEAHbdp4Y-qEP%20WPUFv941nW4bPkBb7th4qgbLg0aOnGYCQJwWQeLCQ66DuJx3A8zxwAS2QAEoQPgNxRMAaE8Bh5BYY8Lw-CuHg-KhOY8PRrhCu8H5MUGLHTNYAASHFjkKTKEcRpEXPBibJqm6bonxVCCcYkhcYury8bMfEQLwnDkhS6nhrwCBRIpwhQPBiHkK8TKoIZxmEiJREkcAEnxlJKZphmmnaQpNKQVAhHaSgUQnKJTkNLBOw4nQ2QAD53tkxgvpIABEvDJY0xjGLO4gJVAcX5rOAByQEpbwACM6VQGAxxREg2n1u6cAthBmV5XeBa-sVj5QKlABMlXVSAtX1V456XrMrYZe%20Hj5blSU9R66W5dl7VFSVC0Vb4VU1XVnCSB6SBIFEWlwG2U2TRF0ChaRvTmcmlAWvsVoPWQ%20KnmNV72ts0CIpAJDJtFM3tfNqWVWt3WpZt21DbtDWNk103GPlXjraDW3g8BfUDTtI1nhe1gtW1gEQ4t6NHl1mMelDg3DXtUAHUdJ1nV9DrBHM%20CELgZH0NdZHMVAv3pADIimp4coKtAAD0ktQKaQA)

[Here](https://catchts.com/) you can find more examples