# How to make an array of all the strings in string union type?

Tags: typescript, types

I want to take `type stringUnion = "Value1"|"Value2"`
and make an array from all the strings in `stringUnion`

so the array looks like this `["Value1","Value2"]`,
I want an array so I can iterate over it like this:

```js
theArray.map((current, index)=>{

})
```

How do I do that?

Comment: ("Value1"|"Value2")[ ]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `stringUnion` as a value in a variable (because types are not transpiled to js code).

But if this array is gonna be a constant, you can use:

```
const stringValues = ["value1", "value2"] as const;
type stringUnion = (typeof stringValues)[number];
```

Which will allow you to write the values only once.

Comment: The OP is asking about transforming a union type into a tuple.

Comment: @OlegValter From the question it's not clear if they ask about transforming it to a type of array or to a value of array...

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible.

```js
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type/50375286#50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

// credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901
type UnionToOvlds<U> = UnionToIntersection<
  U extends any ? (f: U) => void : never
>;

type PopUnion<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends (a: infer A) => void ? A : never;


// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953814/typescript-check-if-a-type-is-a-union#comment-94748994
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true;

type UnionToArray<T, A extends unknown[] = []> = IsUnion<T> extends true
  ? UnionToArray<Exclude<T, PopUnion<T>>, [PopUnion<T>, ...A]>
  : [T, ...A];

interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  surname: string;
  children: number;
}

type Result = UnionToArray<keyof Person>; // ["name", "age", "surname", "children"]
```

Here is an alternative way:

```js
// credits goes to https://twitter.com/WrocTypeScript/status/1306296710407352321
type TupleUnion<U extends string, R extends any[] = []> = {
    [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S]>;
}[U];

interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    dob: Date;
    hasCats: false;
}

type keys = TupleUnion<keyof Person>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGMCcFMBMEsAuBnUBzA9tViOgBaKIAOyAXCMogIbgDWGAbtJAGYA2GA7gHTgYBbYAEcArtkTwMAO2TAArAAYAzAHYALAE5FADmCJI1WawyQBAWlHSp084gCexaHYzn40xC2TRwkmXcdoBRVVeQAmHQA2AGIlNXCogCgHJ1AAVWsZABUMAEkPLx8-aQAeNIA%20UABeUAAKNNBoAA9PaVhUI3tQAH46ujJ0gEpqysYMeFhQAeloZkhh5tb2usTQUH7Qd1YWUFzE4arR8dhVnt3T6dmWAG5ExJAIGAQUdCwcPEISchA0JHxRABGfEEwAE8CgGGQGFYiGAWUCAGUoPBiLD4MhkOI5ABGZRhTQ6aLozE%20QQCaAeczqSI6bHYrSKbHJQLpTLSHIAeUY7HaZUqNQyNhy%20U8kG8vhsJVODUWFOWnTOtVYAzSByOEymoBmc0S5VuzNSAAUMMRBTI%20dVWUKMFyecgLbK2qhatQBlsdgBBNWgMYa3oezXam53e5gKBwJCoTDYUC4AhEUgUYBUWgMOYcbjAoRiCQ2OTyZSaAu09T6QLIZGo8zgfA%20OhuVjmagBJxuZBNyxs6L8ATkymadQaHSaAcG6C7ZBm0pZfmgADaWQAuo0WnLUHOp8KCmKipKZ8veqxqOxvJqDOJ9Slx5uMB7IIZ7CUsgAaUABx3LKx0aTcaRz5c1P%20s65JObJPpUH44JA4inL0N53g%20JQAKJNOA7CiLA0BPq%20xqmmBM7lK%20c64VO4GvjwFEeou5QXPOL6gBRPBUfq7iike4DjoaXgyKAADepzSNQ5IDFQkDuGgtxrNQaDQNMogCACwZrJikCCcJoCieJkkQPg8A8jA0hyQpwYAL53FeoAAErYKI7CIJa8H3tQj50NA9jQqAXFijIeqgA8c4AERqdAAWvgF0khWFKnBaFoABTWemwAZAWLiG-FrBZWSiMQ7DQKRMqrk6GkGOJr6WSuSwdNI9j-paQGWulazzgimzSOki4DChaEYVhaSvgiEGFcsQaQGcc6MZZ-XLgMWU5XlYFdehmFlP1hHzhNU16qcJkbou%20prKxLDsZx3FtY1aysPAYqIAAckJsnFWJ0gSacazsNQVB3epmnPdpaywBgAIDAAItQnh-QQH0AMJg%20QoBHie0DaWZpwWQA0m5qA1LNuWka57msJ5p1bSZQA)

More explanation you can find in my [blog](https://catchts.com/union-array)

Comment: This is a brilliant answer.

Comment: Agree, it's brilliant! Would there be a way to make it independent of the order in the array?

Comment: @jorgen could you please elaborate? I mean with some example and expected result

Comment: I mean (referring to the first method): type T = "a" | "b" means that const a: UnionToArray<T> = ["a", "b"] is permissible but not ["b", "a"]. In our case the type T is derived (using amongst other things Exclude), and somehow the correct order seems to depend on environment (local vs CI).. Not sure exactly how that happens

Comment: Note that in our case the second method gives an error "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.". I guess our derived type is just not amenable to this!

Comment: @jorgen please provide typescript playground to your case

Comment: That is a very nice explanation, thanks !.
I would say that the first approach is slightly better than the alternative way because the TS compiler will pop a more readable description when you hover the type

Comment: @Boogie agree, first approach is considered as a little bit unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create a value out of a type. So you can't convert your union type to an array. If you wish to create an array type though. You can do it in 2 ways.

1. `type YourArrayType = StringUnion[];`
2. `type YourArrayType = Array<StringUnion>;`

This type will create the following type: `("value1" | "value2")[]` and it will only allow you to have either `"value1"` or `"value2"` in your array with this type.