# Typescript: Given function (keys: K[]) => Record<K, ...>, which return type would enforce exactly the keys of K[] to be in the Record?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes an array of Pets, and returns a map where the keys are the pets and the values are their eye colors:

```js
export enum Pets {
  KITTY = 'KITTY',
  PUPPY = 'PUPPY',
  BABY_SEAL = 'BABY_SEAL',
}

const colors = ['RED', 'BLUE', 'PURPLE'];

function getEyeColor(pets: Pets[]): Partial<Record<Pets, string>> {
  // call some internal service to get eye colors for each Pet, then return them as a Record. Here as example we randomly assign:
  return pets.reduce((acc, pet) => {
    acc[pet] = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

I want to define the return type of this function in such a way, such that when I call:

```js
getEyeColor([Pets.KITTY, Pets.PUPPY]);
```

that typescript tells me that the return type of this function is

```js
{ ['KITTY']: string, ['PUPPY']: string };
```

and that if I try to get `['BABY_SEAL']` from the result, it will give me error `TS2339: property 'BABY_SEAL' does not exist on type { ['KITTY']: string, ['PUPPY']: string }`.

Comment: Question feels bad worded as  it reads like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66939607/how-to-make-an-array-of-all-the-strings-in-string-union-type

Comment: `function getEyeColor<K extends Pets>(pets: K[]): { [P in K]: string } ` ?

Comment: @Dimava hello, sorry if it wasn't clear, I added some clarification. If I try your suggested function signature, and then return hardcoded value `{ [Pets.KITTY]: 'red' }`, TS complains with `TS2322 [Pets.KITTY]' does not exist in type '{ [P in K]: string; }`. I don't understand why :) so that's what I'm hoping to find out.

Comment: I'm confused: why would you want to return a hardcoded value if the output is supposed to depend on the input?  Could you please [edit] to make your code a [mre] that we can paste into our own IDEs to see exactly what you're talking about? Right now the above code is giving errors you're not mentioning, and the suggestions people are giving you [look reasonable to me](https://tsplay.dev/m0xBPm).  How do you want to proceed?

Comment: @jcalz hiya, I'm sorry that was just an example of how I thought it might look like. I edited the post, removed the latter example and expanded the former example to working code. Yes I see that Teneff has posted what I was searching for, in fact :) I will accept their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it like this

```js
function getEyeColor<T extends Array<Pets>>(pets: T): Record<T[number], string> {
  throw new Error('not implemented')
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=7&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwArBgZzgbwCg44BpASQBVKBNOAXjgHILqamAaYzAVQwzqMmGPgM7cAQgEEJNAPoBlAKJSAMg2bTZilavEBfQoQBmyRAGMYASwiI4Ac2xKAnsADCEADbQAPJQQgMEgAJnhSUFAAhs4+WLgAfPEAFGDYOABccJQAlJkASsDm0MF+ANooqABGwFAAuhxwODBQVoj28QTcMAAWUBAA7nCIwINKEdBJTIgQ8FaoYJ7AqEhBwUzZhIaERYhNCK4e3lA4AIwajjAu7l4TpbXZANzbtnvABzfHAEznTu9HSaU4jgAHSsWgNIHAkT8Gj3J6EAD0CLgAAFcABaUCpSyY8ZQZ67eBFI5nRhva5HU6AtKgqi0WqI5EkZkAPQA-EYdntidBvmS-tAcJ9qbhaWwGUjmayOUA)

Comment: If I may be so rude to ask, what would be your advice if there were default input parameters, like so: `(pets: T = [Pets.KITTY])` ? It gives a `TS2322` error, which I can "fix" by with casting: `(pets: T = [Pets.KITTY] as T)`. But is there a solution without having to cast?

Comment: Provide the default value from the outside `getEyeColor(somePets || [Pets.KITTY])` [ts play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwArBgZzgbwCg44BpASQBVKBNOAXjgHILqamAaYzAVQwzqMmGPgM7cAQgEEJNAPoBlAKJSAMg2bTZilavEBfQoQBmyRAGMYASwiI4Ac2xKAnsADCEADbQAPJQQgMEgAJnhSUFAAhs4+WLgAfPEAFGDYOABccJQAlJkASsDm0MF+ANooqABGwFAAuhxwODBQVoj28QTcMAAWUBAA7nCIwINKEdBJTIgQ8FaoYJ7AqEhBwUzZhIaEwYWekVDAcOZ7OHhxOBh9AG5WO1CdJI4w50m5mH2oVjjAsWmltXAAD5wMw7YytYDBeKbIyRHDOCxwUwWay2OCoZzkeaLZaIGCRVGIV4PI62JqNCDLc4aSL9SJWeBJYaDc6XCA3O6vAB0Txe2Q2JAOMGQUDsTxc7i8ExwlOA1MBwNK5y5rFotQ2+iAA)