# How to filter union type?

Tags: typescript, tuples, union-types

I have a union type like:

```
type Animal = "cat" | "dog" | "rabbit"
```

And I have a union type of all combinations between these animals:

```
type PairsMap = {
    [K1 in Animal]: {
        [K2 in Animal]: K1 extends K2 ? never : [K1, K2]
    }
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]
type Pairs = Values<Values<PairsMap>> 
// type Pairs = ["dog", "cat"] | ["rabbit", "cat"] | ["cat", "dog"] | ["rabbit", "dog"] | ["cat", "rabbit"] | ["dog", "rabbit"]
```

The question is - how can I remove all pairs which are "inversed" duplicates? (e.g. remove dog-cat if there is a cat-dog).

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UBEBjFYHKAH1wBMB7Ac2LJwCcUAjZhIgWAChvRIoACigQMAzgFkUYLFADe3AJABtANIBGKAjixEqNAF0AXHMXKVAJk3b4ydEajqoEAB7AIccqIeWA-FDgQAG4QDFDGqmoANN76igC%203Ak8XHzQAGroAK4QogA8ACoAfDL5SgDWECCUAGZQ%20bEp4NBCIl7YGWjZeR1duS1ikmCFhdwA9KNQqVAAYghobgwQ5P1tUD7rUNy8TYLCodhKNnrRR3bb-ACSohdwwWIQfRoubh5e-dECls-unrsixdgBGolAAGfROVw-N7mJRqcGKPxA2Hg76vQQwsGbLgKBR%20YAMbJhKDVdCiCCKYwktBkraNfj9DQHfCEHDRHBUWgNKb9SxMjms3AEIhcnb9ADMMiU7JoAsYLDYwvO0HyBOg2CuNzuZL6eyifwY5hGdOVqoA%20ryoBrbiFtTyPrqjVNpqS1Zbrtb7jqRHrxUagA)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need this as a type?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I did not came up with simple solution. If anybody know simpler solution - I'm all ears.

I have rewritten PairsMap implementation. I think it is more generic but I might be wrong, so you can use any implementation you like. Every one has his own style, right ?:D

```js
// credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31751#issuecomment-498526919
type IsNever<T> = [T] extends [never] ? true : false;

type PairsMap<
    Union extends string,
    Used extends string = never,
    Cache extends string[] = never
    > =
    IsNever<Union> extends true ? Cache : {
        [Prop in Union]: PairsMap<Exclude<Union, Prop>, Prop, [Prop, Used]>
    }[Union]

type PartialPermutations = PairsMap<Animal>
```

Next, We need to filter the union. Since we can't iterate over the union of tuples we need to convert it to tuple.

```js
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never;

// credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901
type UnionToOvlds<U> = UnionToIntersection<
    U extends any ? (f: U) => void : never
>;

// credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901
type PopUnion<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends (a: infer A) => void ? A : never;

// credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953814/typescript-check-if-a-type-is-a-union#comment-94748994
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true;

type UnionToArray<T, A extends unknown[] = []> = IsUnion<T> extends true
    ? UnionToArray<Exclude<T, PopUnion<T>>, [PopUnion<T>, ...A]>
    : [T, ...A];
```

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68949858/how-can-i-get-tuple-type-from-the-members-of-another-type-in-typescript/68950848#68950848)

As you might have noticed there are links with explanation above each type utility.

[Article](https://catchts.com/union-array)

After we had converted it to the inerrable data structure (tuple), we can actually iterate over it:

```js
type Inverse<T> = T extends [infer Fst, infer Scd] ? [Scd, Fst] : never

type MapPredicate<Original, Tuple> = Inverse<Tuple> extends Original ? never : Tuple

type Filter<
    Current extends Array<any>,
    Result extends Array<any> = []
    > = Current extends []
    ? []
    : Current extends [infer H]
    ? [...Result, MapPredicate<Result[number], H>][number]
    : Current extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
    ? Filter<[...Tail], [...Result, MapPredicate<Result[number], Head>]>
    : Readonly<Result>;
```

[Here](https://catchts.com/tuples), in my blog, you can find more explanation how it works

Here you have pure js to understand what is going on here. Please treat `null` as `never`. Like I said - it is pseudocode, in typescript you should not treat `never` as `null`

```js
const predicate = (result, head) => {
    const [fst, scd] = head
    // pseudocode, includes works with primitives
    if (result.includes([scd, fst])) {
        return null
    }
    return head
}

const filter = (current, result = []) => {
    if (current.length === 0) {
        return []
    }

    const [head, ...tail] = current;

    return filter(tail, [...result, predicate(result, head)])
}
```

Full example:

```js
type Animal = "cat" | "dog" | "rabbit"

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never;

// credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901
type UnionToOvlds<U> = UnionToIntersection<
    U extends any ? (f: U) => void : never
>;

// credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901
type PopUnion<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends (a: infer A) => void ? A : never;

// credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953814/typescript-check-if-a-type-is-a-union#comment-94748994
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true;

type UnionToArray<T, A extends unknown[] = []> = IsUnion<T> extends true
    ? UnionToArray<Exclude<T, PopUnion<T>>, [PopUnion<T>, ...A]>
    : [T, ...A];

type IsNever<T> = [T] extends [never] ? true : false;

type PairsMap<
    Union extends string,
    Used extends string = never,
    Cache extends string[] = never
    > =
    IsNever<Union> extends true ? Cache : {
        [Prop in Union]: PairsMap<Exclude<Union, Prop>, Prop, [Prop, Used]>
    }[Union]

type PartialPermutations = PairsMap<Animal>

type Inverse<T> = T extends [infer Fst, infer Scd] ? [Scd, Fst] : never

type MapPredicate<Original, Tuple> = Inverse<Tuple> extends Original ? never : Tuple

type Filter<
    Current extends Array<any>,
    Result extends Array<any> = []
    > = Current extends []
    ? []
    : Current extends [infer H]
    ? [...Result, MapPredicate<Result[number], H>][number]
    : Current extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
    ? Filter<[...Tail], [...Result, MapPredicate<Result[number], Head>]>
    : Readonly<Result>;

type Result = Filter<UnionToArray<PartialPermutations>>; // ["dog", "cat"] | ["rabbit", "dog"] | ["rabbit", "cat"]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UBEBjFYHKAH1wBMB7Ac2LJwCcUAjZhIgWAChuB6XqHgYRy7AM5RqlCBOCUoAC2DAwYgFz8xwFHgDWlAG4QGAMzSUA7gDo8lJLxS8ArAAYAzAHYnAJgAcANm5QSCgAVURKOAAVSgBJOGBjMQg8YARIgB5QgD4sKAAKUKgIAA9EuHIJFDgQKAB%20At01MIBKLFyDSgRyKGa4CCMGNtLyyoLuAEgmqAQ4E2MoWO42zA6u8kmGpa4JvoHjAG5uPgEhEXFJaVl5JRV1fmp2BQBXZhs7XiQEIUoxShNgLwouAIABlIQIMCAhBiMTPGS8ACMbm8AE5fABiGFwlJ2JAQBIAWgALP5fIjEcTUS5EUEQWEItFKAB5AxoSpZXLYcLpJnxRIMZKpXkZSZFEYEsbVWoNfImZqhFZrbq9KD9QbcbJHHhcfiCYSiYASKQyKByRTKVQaXiPYAvN62exfH5-AFAkHghiQ6Gw%20FiJEo9FY324pD4omk8mU6m0rjBaAABUoYB5mRyeVTTNZ7LEnOKZUlEnyKGas3mDFgSqgnRVDRgqvVh2OutOBvYl1N5tuVs02j0hmMZks73sAEc-WlIv6nG5UTPycTePGxBCoYS8AoUrpCQgTISUIT4zuxPvCc9GRjHeHgITUcSPMTfKi73SQrExJmMlEuVAANpRABdfNRgkX9MxifkkhSSc4C-bIgIaEx0GSVVgAYeFtVfaBwMoGAGCYEAvwAGlgYDCygc9dDgSw4F-IDsDon930-b8yIqWR0IgTYGV5GI8IIjIAFESjwNBnnICBiKgJMU0ZODshI38ZJYhSoCsdSYAA7JJmaf8SPUqxNMwuN6XfAA5fYGDgvJ-yAiV2L-RsGAQs1ONVJC0GSYz42klAEEFABZFAwFFHZMzYsYtC9OBqCIsVkh6ezIrQ2ZqDyJy4p2ABhHRNwiiQotSuj0ssyYuUmczLKyRlciSjj4XqKAco3aBmgAb0mCYlIYZMZjgHjIgA5oEz8wLgqEkSxIk6reRIhMerAVT5uTRTlrAEjQgSrTJgAXzAxkAObHyRoYNJ0ATYwkGebQYIkbARv8sQgpC%20BkHQbSdR8%20JBmSazsCifK-zLBYADEtBI4GK3BcgXN-aGSLB4AgL2DVPvpZ75vOAhEgyZkvUeOB0BIqJnjANAICYuAfskkmyYpwG8YQAn0EapzVVp8mjvpEGEDQAVQomLLnnwglgEB-iUEI6UFMmAAlGRnj58X8MljJpZsw6dh-IWRYSQG6O4g2dmaHXhD1uqgbmBYAAlNYmBpfwM%20W4T5kiMbbbHJOdxXgF-OBniQZhjAAkjrfgv2A6D5ydKa4WzbFi3f0hqBrYgFByH09Tk6iPy0Dthoeb54wMkd9Sc95kO-ydhXXagd2scIL2a99-3A%20D0O0-IeCPt2KB5fTyI0EI72%20a1LmQhHsXsEL-mcIlwiTrOtALoYK6bt5MRsi1KA9V-HAqFoEj8EIHAgLIPemFYdgcCPg-T9IP9GBYNgiCP7HT%204IA)