# Constraining a generic parameter to be a union type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is there a way in Typescript to constrain a generic parameter to be a union type? To illustrate my intention, below I pretend `T extends UnionType` will achieve this:

```js
function doSomethingWithUnion<T extends UnionType>(val: T) {}

doSomethingWithUnion<number | string>(...) // good
doSomethingWithUnion<number>(...) // should result in an error
```

I've found in another SO question  ([53953814](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953814/typescript-check-if-a-type-is-a-union)) that we can check if a type is a union type:

```js
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true

type Foo = IsUnion<string | number> // true
type Bar = IsUnion<string> // false
```

Which allows to, for example, to assert than a function will never return if a generic parameter is *not* a union type:

```
declare function doSomethingWithUnion<T>(val: T): [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? never: boolean;

doSomethingWithUnion<number>(2) // never
doSomethingWithUnion<string|number>(2) // => boolean
```

([Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=53&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4AoKKAChiggA8c4ATfKAIZwQUAPwsA1gC5YASjo0AbkgQ8oMuBEV55nbnxbNpUBHABmeKBnm0lKnvPEZ1UTdtz16oSFfzwy5Kg0tFAA2qgAuuxcELz8of4o6Fg4BMSkKIFUUeJmAgA2hC7AuACuEJ5e4NAAYkhIdL6JFPglpgDmUAA+rqUAtgBGeDQA9CNQJeVVPgBCAriNGH6Ima24HaPjeYUVnjzE+fPQZqVwJGRQPEgAykh9EMAAFh0A6ghPzVnMigUyqLIyMKRaL6eLNZLYPCEc6ZII5VxaPAyAb1fIQIQAbj2NzuD2ecHabw+KwocH6Q1wVGYACZ5GMEe56Fdbvcnq93o9PmsOl0yYNhjS6eNbFAUUg0UJ6EA))

However, I have not found a way to constrain the type itself in a similar manner.

Comment: I'd love to know what use case would require a union type and forbid a non-union type.  Especially since what TypeScript considers a union is often different from what users of TypeScript expect (e.g., `boolean` is a union, and `"a" | "b" | "c" | string` is not a union).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typescript only allows you to specify an upper bound for a generic type parameter, not a lower bound or any other constraint. So it seems like it should be impossible, and at first I thought it must be. But it turns out this *is* possible, by making `T`'s upper bound depend on `T` itself.

```
function test<T extends (IsUnion<T> extends true ? any : never)>(arg: T): T {
  // ...
  return arg;
}

// OK
test<string | number>('foobar');

// Error: Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'never'.
test<string>('foobar');

// Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
test('foobar');
```

The one caveat I can think of is that `T` can always be `never`, even though that is not a union. That's unavoidable because `never` extends everything, so it extends any upper bound that the type variable could have. But if `T` is `never` then the function can only be called with an argument of type `never` (i.e. it can never be called), so this shouldn't be a problem in practice.

If you need another upper bound for `T`, you can write that instead of `any`.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgVQHYEsD2SA8AVANFBKCAD2AiQBM4psoBeGgPnoCgp2oAKWksy6gIZIQUAPxsOnQr3JUaYqADMBAGzjQAXFGAAnAK4QAlBI4ctSCADcIOw0VKzqytdFFLV6qFt0GWLRXpIAMbA6EjaEHDAOPZ8cpzwyGE4zDL82vquUEIi5lY2hoycAjoA5lrYhhVQAN4SAPT1UAB0rRI6EMB6OuElpQDcLAC+fo1QAPIA0ixkUZhROihIpVAAPlBIegC2AEY2RQDkimhoOyUHhoMsYwCiOjpoOhXg0AcLS6UHUBRokRtowCgcAEoTgihEwAAFtAghgFgIloCDhZrDoDs0ZpFou9lodjqdzpdRk07g8nlAAIJlbbkQFoRTaF5QN66D5fFDUJAA7JwOAoUpIAQ7FTQYBoKBgEoCLadGxQemMyDMlE2dGYqKcI4nM5oolAA)

Comment: I tried using the above approach to force the generic type to support a specific string. But TypeScript still doesn't allow the code to assign that string to the type. Any ideas? Here's a contrived example: `const defaultValue = <T extends ("Unavailable" extends T ? string : never)>(value?: T): T => value || "Unavailable";`

Comment: @MichaelBest You don't need fancy conditional types or lower bounds, just write `<T extends string>(value?: T | "Unavailable"): T | "Unavailable" => value || "Unavailable"`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, and seems to work. Not sure if I can simplify it by passing a union type instead of two types that get put into a union.

```
function onlyUnions<T, I>(result: T | I) {
    return result;
}

onlyUnions<string, number>("string");
```

Comment: This would still allow calling it like `onlyUnions<string, string>("foobar")` where the type is just `string`.