# How do I declare object value type without declaring key type?

Tags: typescript, types

## Problem statement

I'd like to declare `mapper1` so that it's values can only be `Type1`, and `mapper2` so that it's values can only be `Type2`. How do I do that without declaring the key type as well?

## Background

In TypeScript, I have:

```js
import Bar1 from './bar1'; // Type1
import Bar2 from './bar2'; // Type1
import Bar3 from './bar3'; // Type2
import Bar4 from './bar4'; // Type2

const mapper1 = {
  foo1: bar1,
  foo2: bar2,
} as const;
const mapper2 = {
  foo3: bar3,
  foo4: bar4,
} as const;
export type MapperKeys = keyof typeof mapper1 | keyof typeof mapper2;
```

`bar1` and `bar2` have the same type (`Type1`). `bar3` and `bar4` have the same type (`Type2`). `Type1` is different from `Type2`.

`MapperKeys` is the union of the keys of `mapper1` and `mapper2` (`'foo1' | 'foo2' | 'foo3' | 'foo4'`).

## What I tried

### Approach 1:

```js
const mapper1: Record<string, Type1> = {
  foo1: bar1,
  foo2: bar2,
} as const;
const mapper2: Record<string, Type2> = {
  foo3: bar3,
  foo4: bar4,
} as const;
```

but now `MapperKeys` is `'string'`. I want it to be the union of the keys of `mapper1` and `mapper2` (`'foo1' | 'foo2' | 'foo3' | 'foo4'`)

### Approach 2:

```js
const mapper1: Record<'foo1' | 'foo2', Type1> = {
  foo1: bar1,
  foo2: bar2,
} as const;
const mapper2: Record<'foo3' | 'foo4', Type2> = {
  foo3: bar3,
  foo4: bar4,
} as const;
```

This works but isn't [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WoDklw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w24p4m) meet your needs?  If you annotate a variable with an object type you are telling the compiler that it should not try to infer anything more specific (e.g., if you annotate as `Record<string, Type1>`, it means you can later write `mapper1.someOtherKey = bar1`, so the compiler cannot say that the type of `mapper1` has only keys `"foo1"` and `"foo2"`.)  If you want inference and constraint checking you can write a generic helper function to do that, as shown in my link above. If this makes sense I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz this approach looks good. Can you please post it as an answer so that it can be accepted? However, I don't understand your explanation, so can you please elaborate and perhaps provide links to relevant documentation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you use a [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) on a variable like `const x: T`, or a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) on an expression like `x as T`, then you're telling the compiler to treat the variable or value as that type.  This essentially throws away information about any more specific type that the compiler may have inferred*. The type of `x` will be *widened* to `T`:

```
const badMapper1: Record<string, Type1> = { foo1: bar1, foo2: bar2 };
const badMapper2 = { foo3: bar3, foo4: bar4 } as Record<string, Type2>;    

export type BadMapperKeys = keyof typeof badMapper1 | keyof typeof badMapper2;
// type BadMapperKeys = string
```

Instead, you're looking for something like "the `satisfies` operator" as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481) and which will be [introduced in TypeScript 4.9](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-rc/#satisfies).  The idea is that an expression like `x satisfies T` would *verify* that `x` is assignable to type `T` *without widening* it to `T`.  With that operator you could say something like

```
const mapper1 = { foo1: bar1, foo2: bar2 } satisfies { [key: string]: Type1 }
const mapper2 = { foo3: bar3, foo4: bar4 } satisfies { [key: string]: Type2 }

export type MapperKeys = keyof typeof mapper1 | keyof typeof mapper2;
// type MapperKeys = "foo1" | "foo2" | "foo3" | "foo4"
```

and be done.

---

For versions of TypeScript before 4.9 you can write helper functions to behave similarly.  The general form is something like this:

```
const satisfies = <T,>() => <U extends T>(u: U) => u;
```

And then instead of `x satisfies T` you write (the more cumbersome) `satisfies<T>()(x)`.  This works because `satisfies<T>()` produces an identity function of the form `<U extends T>(u: U)=>u` where the type of the input `U` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `T`, and the return type is the narrower type `U` and not the wider type `T`.

Let's try it:

```
const mapper1 = satisfies<Record<string, Type1>>()({ foo1: bar1, foo2: bar2 });
const mapper2 = satisfies<Record<string, Type2>>()({ foo3: bar3, foo4: bar4 });
export type MapperKeys = keyof typeof mapper1 | keyof typeof mapper2;
// type MapperKeys = "foo1" | "foo2" | "foo3" | "foo4"
```

Looks good!

---

In your case you specifically asked to specify the object value type but not the keys.  If you want you can adapt the `satisfies` function so that you specify the property value type `T` and let the compiler infer just the keys.  Something like this:

```
const satisfiesRecord = <T,>() => <K extends PropertyKey>(rec: Record<K, T>) => rec;
```

You can see that it behaves similarly:

```
const mapper1 = satisfiesRecord<Type1>()({ foo1: bar1, foo2: bar2, });
const mapper2 = satisfiesRecord<Type2>()({ foo3: bar3, foo4: bar4, });
export type MapperKeys = keyof typeof mapper1 | keyof typeof mapper2;
// type MapperKeys = "foo1" | "foo2" | "foo3" | "foo4"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECMyDeAUMsgB4BcyAzmFKAOYDchAvoaJLIihtgEwFiydJRABXALYAjaMzYATCAgA2cKCgQB7EDWRS1OSr1zNFKtRu279UPkawnCZ1euRadYPWoDM9-qaUXSw8vKAAWPwg+ZkJ3azh5AFk4TGwoQ2QAJSVNKHkAHho6EHoAGjQHHAA+ZABeAmQYTU0Mmxxyps07UIEWZjjPfSSUtIF6-Ebm31DvDuaI0LDkFmQ4KiycvMLaBnLjPirmCFJMXM8wB2QAIQTk1OgAaQh0dfqAa2fNGGQL7C+vYb3dLIAA+yA+6H+vwg-yGd1GzAA9IjkMdTlBzpcboC0k8XnVqDsSoQScjkKAAG5wZTAeTUdDgOCkcryTTIECac5QdCEMkDZASEbQPDjSYtShtOZdCVqXrUOBgYBUGDACDrbJaLZFXYVbDVXko-mCoFjBqdaY2WZihY2JYrKgKpUqtUbTUFbUlPYOA4k-kOxXK1WvZD5VClKoACgAlHUavkAKqo0iQEDydaoSNiSjxmO1GpiGL8zRvODoeHCgn+p1B-Ia3LuollXW4KqRqMRiadVoGKXdGy9KP9KyeYul8u2SuOwNq2ubBvFJv7VvRjtii0+KU2tR2wck2LD+UB51UOt5Amh8PR2Mhh5JlNp5AABSgmjSFzxkfUCEop4KDz2VS5jUX6FgexppCKh7Vmqv6hpUbarl2MrpL2yF8OULC7kaQoTvUVbTiec5wfwCGdlMyFWp0W7hBhu5omcPyXOOeLBhCUIOP84EVmCbHfNCnE4dEBqMdgyDMc8wYAERdpJoLINJzR8LJYIKZo3jKfJVGSUAA)

---

<sup>*This is not strictly true when you annotate a variable as a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types); in such cases the compiler will [narrow the type of the variable upon assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments).  But since `Record<string, Type1>` is not a union type, this is not applicable to the current situation.</sup>

Comment: Cleaner `satisfies` discussion moved to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920

Comment: `satisfies` does not declare value type as the question asked for, it only puts a lower bound on it.

Answer (score 0):

Using explicit type disables immutable assertion. Consider using either explicit type or `as const` assertion.

In order to achieve desired behavior you should use helper function and static validation:

```js
type Type1 = { type: 1 }
type Type2 = { type: 2 }

const bar1: Type1 = { type: 1 }
const bar2: Type1 = { type: 1 }

const bar3: Type2 = { type: 2 }
const bar4: Type2 = { type: 2 }

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type/50375286#50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953814/typescript-check-if-a-type-is-a-union
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true

type IsValueValid<Obj> = Obj extends Record<infer _, infer Value> ? IsUnion<Value> extends true ? never : Obj : never

const builder = <Key extends string, Value>(obj: IsValueValid<Record<Key, Value>>) => obj

const result1 = builder({
  foo1: bar1,
  foo2: bar2,
}) // ok, all values have same type

result1.foo1 // ok
result1.foo2 // ok

const result2 = builder({
  foo1: bar3,
  foo2: bar4,
}) // ok, all values have same type

const result3 = builder({
  foo1: bar1,
  foo2: bar4,
}) // expected error, values have different type
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w66v0w)

`IsUnion` - checks whether object values type is a union or not. If values have different type then we should consider this object as an invalid. This is exactly what we are doing in `IsValueValid`. This utility type return `never` if provided argument does not meet our requirements.

Comment: I think the OP wants `result1` to specifically have `Type1` values, not just "the same type" value.  But maybe I'm misreading it?

Comment: @jcalz to be honest I don't know.

Comment: What a very complicated solution... Looks like `keyof typeof result1 | keyof typeof result2` indeed resolves to `'foo1' | 'foo2' | 'foo3' | 'foo4'` as desired. I think that this does more than asked for, which may explain why it looks so complex.