# TypeScript get 'true' fields only able with new 'satisfied'?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a Type that only contains `true` fields.
I was able to achieve the wanted behavior with the new `satisfies` keyword but I am sure it has to be possible otherwise.

Example working with 'satisfies'

[image]

Without the 'satisfies' keyword it just gives me an empty type.

Example without 'satisfied'

[image]

Am I missing something here? In my brain it should just work.

```js
type Fields = {
  [FieldName: string]: boolean,
}

type GetTrues<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends true ? K : never]: T[K]
}

const fields: Fields = {
  trueField: true,
  falseField: false
};

type myTrueFields = GetTrues<typeof fields> // expected {trueField: true} got {}
```

Comment: The answer relies on this : `type BooleanExtendsTrue = boolean extends true ? true : false;`

Comment: Your `typeof fields` is not known-keyed, it's unreduced `Fields`

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70956050/how-do-i-declare-object-value-type-without-declaring-key-type) and its answers for more information.