# TS not complaining about function parameter which is generic array and has different type of elements

Tags: typescript

Why is TS not complaining here:

```
function print<G>(params: G[]): G {
 return params[0];
}

console.log(print(["1",false,"2",5]))
```

Array elements have different types no?

Comment: Why would it complain? You are passing in a generic, which means it infers `G` based on the array provided, which is in this case `string | boolean | number`. It then returns the inferred union type as expected. What kind of error do you expect?

Comment: If you want to make it complains - add `as const` like this `["1",false,"2",5] as const`

Comment: @Terry AAh so the type of G it inferred as that: `string | boolean | number`? interesting. post as answer if you like I will accept

Comment: @Drag13 Can you explain why would it complain in that case? I tried but I think it is mainly complaining about mutable vs readonly now

Comment: @Drag13 That only works because they used `G[]`, not `readonly G[]`. If they use `readonly G[]` then that won't error.

Comment: A workaround if you're interested: https://tsplay.dev/w610rW This will break if you use a type like `1 | 2 | 3` still of course, but it just makes sure that the inferred type is a single type.

Comment: @caTS I am TS beginner I think that is too much for me. But if you want you can add it as an answer too, but with explanations, because I couldn't follow it. Should be useful for someone else too. I will upvote at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript wouldn't complain because you're using generics correctly for its intended purpose, called [*type argument inference*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#hello-world-of-generics):

> Here we use type argument inference — that is, we want the compiler to set the value of Type for us automatically based on the type of the argument we pass in:
>
> `let output = identity("myString");`
>
> Notice that we didn’t have to explicitly pass the type in the angle brackets (`<>`); the compiler just looked at the value "myString" [...]. While type argument inference can be a helpful tool to keep code shorter and more readable [...]

In this case, the inferred type of `G` will be based on the type of the array you are passing to the function.

`["1", false, "2", 5]` will have an inferred type of `Array<string | boolean | number>`, so `G` will have the inferred union type of `string | boolean | number`. And that is exactly what `params[0]` is returning, which matches the explicit return type you've defined.

Comment: yeah I was mainly surprised why it accepted params of different type not about the return. But yeah this answers. I will accept soon.

Answer (score 1):

We'll be using `IsUnion` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953814/typescript-check-if-a-type-is-a-union) answer, along with `UnionToIntersection` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type). Those answers already have excellent explanations, so if you're interested, make sure to read them.

The only magic I do here is using `IsUnion` to check if `G` is a union:

```
function print<G>(params: readonly (IsUnion<G> extends true ? never : G)[]): G {
 return params[0];
}
```

I use `readonly` so you can pass readonly *and* regular arrays (since regular arrays are assignable to readonly arrays, but not the other way around). Then there is `IsUnion<G> extends true ? never : G`.

TypeScript is actually able to infer the type of `G` here, so it can pass it to `IsUnion`. If `G` was a union type, we disallow that and replace it with `never`.

[Here's](https://tsplay.dev/WP9Gew) a playground with some cases. Note that this will error for types like `1 | 2 | 3` since that's still a union.

Comment: Yeah I suppose I will first have to read at least those two links, and then try to come back here. Like I said I am TS beginner, and here are too many new concepts for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What @Terry noted is correct. TypeScript's Heuristics will infer `G` to be a union type of all the elements in the array. If you don't want this behaviour, this might be helpful:

```
function print2<G>(params: [G, ...(G & {})[]]): G {
 return params[0];
}

print2(["1","2"])         // Valid
print2(["1",false,"2",5]) // Error
```

Here, `G` will be inferred as the type of the first element in the tuple. The rest of the elements must comply to this type.

We give `params` a tuple type. The first element of this tuple is just `G` and TypeScript can use this element to infer `G`. The rest of the tuple... well it's an potentially unlimited amount `G`s too, but we intersect them with `{}`. This is a common way of telling TypeScript *"Hey, please just take the type of `G` here, but don't use this position to infer it"*. You can see a discussion about that [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320833603).

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE4zFAPAcQHwAUyAhqsQLYDOAXIjgNoC6AlLTogN4BQiqAplBCokJMlXoAGRgG4uAXy5c0GKAXoAiAIzqANMGIAbSnx3qATLoCsLRV1CRYCFOkxnchURRqJ6OHYgA6IIJ2ADJOOWYmFjZOHn5BYRRSL0kZeUVlVzUtXX0jE3MrGyyoMxztUwsWIA)

Comment: Wow, that's pretty neat! Unfortunately empty arrays don't work now.

Comment: Sorry I am TS beginner if you can also add some explanations would be better e.g. what is this: `[G, ...(G & {})[]]`?

Comment: @caTS - good pont :D although I am not sure passing an empty array would make sense here

Comment: I suppose, but in some other places it would make sense :p Fix is easy of course, just add `[] & any[]`: https://tsplay.dev/w8LZ0w

Comment: So what is this: `...(G & {})[]]`?

Comment: @john - I will write an explanation later.