# TypeScript object with exactly one property

Tags: typescript

I want to be able to specify a type that accepts an object with a single property with arbitrary key, but errors on 2+ properties (or zero). I.e. something like:

```
const A: SingleKeyObject = {name: "John"}
const B: SingleKeyObject = {department: "Sales", age: 30} // Err: Too many props
const C: SingleKeyObject = {department: "Sales"}
const D: SingleKeyObject = {} // Err: Too few props
```

Any idea how to do that?

The use case is I'm trying to implement something like the `.bind` method in `fp-ts`: https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/guides/do-notation.html but don't want to use a separate string argument for the key. I.e. something like this:

```
type Dict = Record<string, any>;
type SingleKeyObject<T extends Dict> = T; // For the sake of the example

class Store<T extends Dict> {
  constructor(public values: T) {}

  bind = <U extends Dict>(bindfn: (values: T) => SingleKeyObject<U>) => {
    const values = { ...this.values, ...bindfn(this.values) };
    return new Store(values);
  };
}

const store1 = new Store({a: 1, b: 2})
const store2 = store1.bind(({a, b}) => ({c: a + b})) // Should be allowed
const store3 = store1.bind(({a, b}) => ({d: a + b, e: a * b})) // Should error
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJ1K6m) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! That seems pretty close to what I'm after, I'm just not sure how to [wrangle the generic](https://tsplay.dev/weLYKW) for my use case, can you please have a look?

Comment: The way you use generics in bindsome doesn't make sense to me. You are using generics but you manually specify that the argument has `a` and `b` field. `U` will be the same as `T` if it has only one key. It's not a format in which you should use this type

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear what I was trying to do, I edited the original question so that it now shows my use case (my Store has `solid-js` signals instead of values, but other than that it's pretty much the same).

Comment: _"with arbitrary key"_ clashes with the idea of using types. The very basic idea of types is that the structure of the data is known (and can be validated) at compile time.

Comment: Wait I did manage to get it working, will update the question accordingly, thanks again @wonderflame & if you write up your answer I will accept it

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not accepting multiple return values in your do notation? I understand it is impossible with the original implementation or with generators, but because you return an object you don't have this limitation, which I think is kind of cool

Comment: @AdamB. will do in a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need generics to achieve the desired behavior, which is impossible in the format with the variables you are looking for.

It is possible to create a generic function that would validate the argument if it has only one property.

Logic:

- Using the `keyof` operator get a *union* of keys.
- If the object is empty the keys will be `never`. Raise an error.
- If the keys are union (more than one key). Raise an error.
- Otherwise everything is fine.

To determine whether a type is a union or not we will use the following utility type. More about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953814/typescript-check-if-a-type-is-a-union):

```
type IsUnion<T, U = T> = IsNever<T> extends true
  ? false
  : T extends U
  ? IsNever<Exclude<U, T>> extends true
    ? false
    : true
  : false;
```

To check whether a type is equal to never we will need the following:

```
// https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31751#issuecomment-498526919
type IsNever<T> = [T] extends [never] ? true : false;
```

We will turn `SingleKeyObject` into a generic type that will accept a generic parameter for the object and an optional parameter that is defaulted to its keys. Using the logic mentioned beforehand, we will return `never` if we should raise an error, otherwise the object itself:

```
type SingleKeyObject<T, K = keyof T> = IsNever<K> extends true
  ? never
  : IsUnion<K> extends true
  ? never
  : T;
```

Usage:

```
const singleKeyObject = <T>(obj: SingleKeyObject<T>) => obj;
```

Testing:

```
const A = singleKeyObject({ name: 'John' });
const B = singleKeyObject({ department: 'Sales', age: 30 }); // Err: Too many props
const C = singleKeyObject({ department: 'Sales' });
const D = singleKeyObject({}); // Err: Too few props
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=5.0.4#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)