# What is the type for a single key-value pair in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript I know how to declare a multiple key-value pairs object

```
{ [key: string]: any }
```

How can I declare a single key-value pair?

The specific use-case I want to support is a prop that can be an array of either `string` or a single key-pair object.

For example:

```
const searchArray = [
  'name', 
  {stats: 'resolution'},
  'uptime',
  {config: 'interface'},
];
```

At first I thought the solution was simply

`Record<string,string>`

So the final declaration for my `searchArray` would be

```
interface Props {
  (...)
  searchArray: (string | Record<string,string>)[],
}
```

But I expect it to reject this because I sent two key-pair in an object but it accepts it.

```
searchArray={[
 'name',
 'bitrate',
 {stats:'resolution', stats:'frameRate'}
]}
```

It should accept only one key-pair per object.
The following should be accepted

```
searchArray={[
 'name',
 'bitrate',
 {stats:'resolution'}, 
 {stats:'frameRate'}
]}
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Type for object that has one and only one property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56469951/12299000), or [typescript restrict count of object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39190154/12299000).

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there's no way to restrict a `string`-indexed type to having only one property entry, but here are two alternative suggestions:

1. Use a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsATiAPAaQiKEAewJwAmAzlAAqID2kioGIANFAGoCGANgK4QB8UAvFADa9Jmy4QAugG4AULIDGlOMWBRiEVogUALAIKJErLIKGyoUAORxWAWwiWm54ZdWtgxR1cQRilLsAAlsqWkgzOlpxgQfaOzkKWSnAAZoEA5l6WgQgQiMmsCg5hspLq7oHEqb5QABSqiNlpUAA+sAjIKPWNTF1waTwAlEIyskA)

```ts
type Entry<Key extends PropertyKey, Value> = [Key, Value];

const searchArray = [
  'name', 
  ['stats', 'resolution'],
  'uptime',
  ['config', 'interface'],
] satisfies (string | Entry<string, string>)[];
```

2. Or — slightly more verbose (but perhaps more clear, depending on your perspective) — use an object type with `key` and `value` properties:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsATiAPAaQiKEAewJwAmAzlAAqID2kioGIANFAGoCGANgK4QB8UAvFADeAKChQA1pgBcUegG4xUAG4dustlwiKAvopEBjSnGLAoxCK0QGAFgEFEiVlkEBtJQHI4rALYQPTEpCkjJQHqaswMQBKmoQsh6IEMSUXMAAlsYeUDoMnpxgGX4BQSEgCUZwAGbpAOYxqloJ6QgQiFWsBv45eQC65pHpxDXJUAAUpogttVAAPrAIyCiT00wrcLU8AJSuvYpAA)

```ts
type Entry<Key extends PropertyKey, Value> = {
  key: Key;
  value: Value;
};

const searchArray = [
  'name', 
  { key: 'stats', value: 'resolution' },
  'uptime',
  { key: 'config', value: 'interface' },
] satisfies (string | Entry<string, string>)[];
```

See also: [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#handbook-content) in the TS handbook

Comment: Thanks, you seem to know a lot! Are you one of the developers of Typescript? But the two solutions are different than my original writeup. In the first solution uses an array [] instead of object {}. In the second solution key and value properties were added. Are you saying it's impossible to represent with Typescript?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74707608/typescript-what-is-the-typing-for-a-single-key-pair-value/74707707?noredirect=1#comment131926046_74707707) @theconstantgardener Well... an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is an object! It's just an object with unique attributes (e.g. it uses number type keys (non-negative integers) to index its collection values instead of string type keys). The first example uses a tuple (an array with a fixed number of elements) to represent your constraint.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74707608/typescript-what-is-the-typing-for-a-single-key-pair-value/74707707?noredirect=1#comment131926046_74707707) @theconstantgardener "_Is it impossible?_" I don't think it's possible. When you use `string` as a property key index type, it necessarily means that "all values that can be assigned to `string` are allowed as property keys" (which means all strings — not just a specific one!), so the second suggestion addresses that by only allowing two types of keys: `key` and `value`, each holding its respective part of data from the entry pair.