# Define a type with only one property and the name of that property must be in a predefined set of names

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I want to create an error structure that indicates if the error is on the server side or the client side. Example:

```js
const serverErr = {
  server: "Error!"
};

const clientErr = {
  client: "Error!"
};
```

The error object must have only one property, and the name of that property must be `server` or `client`.

I tried the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469951/type-for-object-that-has-one-and-only-one-property) question but it's not working.

[image: Effort1]

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56469969/8884948), here is the definition of `IsSingleKey`:

```
export type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void)
    ? I
    : never;
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true;
type ISingleKey<K extends string, T> = IsUnion<K> extends true ? "Can only contain a single key" : Record<K, T>;
```

Comment: Try `ISingleKey<"server", string> | ISingleKey<"client", string>`

Comment: What if there are 20 names that could work? I don't want to join 20 "ISingleKey" together, and it's not good for maintaining.

Comment: You can’t really prohibit extra properties in TypeScript; all you can do is discourage them. Would you accept a solution that takes a union of key names and produces a type that requires exactly one of those keys to have a defined property?

Comment: I'm using that solution to get around this problem right now. When I work with the data, I have to do some extra work, though.

Comment: When you say you're using "that solution" do you mean [something like this](https://tsplay.dev/we68VN)?  Or do you mean something else?  I'm happy to write up this technique as an answer, but only if it meets your needs.

Comment: Oh, yes, that link has the answer I was looking for. I thought you said something about using `Record` with a union of names as keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to make an error type `AllowedErrors` which is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the allowable types, each member of which has exactly one of the acceptable keys as required, and prohibits defined values for the other keys.  It would look like this:

```
type AllowedErrors = 
  { server: string; client?: never; x?: never; y?: never; z?: never; } | 
  { client: string; server?: never; x?: never; y?: never; z?: never; } | 
  { x: string; server?: never; client?: never; y?: never; z?: never; } | 
  { y: string; server?: never; client?: never; x?: never; z?: never; } | 
  { z: string; server?: never; client?: never; x?: never; y?: never; };
```

Note that TypeScript doesn't explicitly support prohibiting a property key, but you can make it an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) whose value type is [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), then the only value you might find at that key would be `undefined`.

This should behave how you want:

```
const serverErr: AllowedErrors = {
    server: "Error!"
};

const clientErr: AllowedErrors = {
    client: "Error!"
};

const bothErr: AllowedErrors = {
    server: "Error",
    client: "Error"
} // error! Type '{ server: string; client: string; }' 
// is not assignable to type 'AllowedErrors'

const neitherErr: AllowedErrors = {
    oops: "Error"
} // Type '{ oops: string; }' is not assignable 
// to type 'AllowedErrors'.

const okayErr = Math.random() < 0.5 ? { x: "" } : { y: "" };
```

So, that's great.

---

But obviously you don't want to have to write or modify your `AllowedErrors` type manually.  You want to *generate* it from a union of the keys like

```
type AllowedErrorKeys = "server" | "client" | "x" | "y" | "z";
```

so that you just need to add/remove things there.  Well, here's one approach:

```
type SingleKeyValue<K extends PropertyKey, V, KK extends PropertyKey = K> =
    K extends PropertyKey ?
    Record<K, V> & { [P in Exclude<KK, K>]?: never } extends infer O ?
    { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never : never;
```

The type `SingleKeyValue<K, V>` produces the relevant union where each member has only one allowed key from `K` with value type `V` and the remainder of the keys from `K` are prohibited.

First, the type is wrapped with the seemingly no-op `K extends PropertyKey ? ... : never`, which actually a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) that splits `K` up into its individual union members, operates on each member, and then unites the results back into another union.

The inner type is essentially `Record<K, V> & { [P in Exclude<KK, K>]?: never }`; the first piece using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) to represent an object with the one key from `K` and the value type `V`, which is [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with a type prohibiting all keys from `Exclude<KK, K>` using [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion).  Wait, what's `KK`?  That's a "dummy" type parameter I declared in the outer scope which [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `K`.  This is really just a trick so that `K` is broken into its union pieces while `KK` is a copy of the original union `K`, so that we can express "all the members of the original union except htis one".

Anyway that's the type we need except it's pretty ugly (an intersection of utility types), so I use a technique described at [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218), `... extends infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never`, to copy the type to another type parameter and iterate its properties with a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to get a single object type.

---

And now we can just write

```
type AllowedErrors = SingleKeyValue<AllowedErrorKeys, string>;
```

and use IntelliSense to verify that it evaluates to

```
/* type AllowedErrors = 
  { server: string; client?: never; x?: never; y?: never; z?: never; } | 
  { client: string; server?: never; x?: never; y?: never; z?: never; } | 
  { x: string; server?: never; client?: never; y?: never; z?: never; } | 
  { y: string; server?: never; client?: never; x?: never; z?: never; } | 
  { z: string; server?: never; client?: never; x?: never; y?: never; }*/
```

as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=false&noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgOwOYBsIGkIgGoEMUCuEAPOlBAB7AQIAmAzlAAoBOA9pC6JiADRTZ+6MpWp1GrDhC4geUALxR0APgUAoKJqXkqNBs3aduWKAH4NWgEoQAxmxa1S-bKoBkUAN5QA2kyiIoAFEKG0JaEmEhZQBdUwAuKAQIADdpKABfHTF9RAAzNIB5MwtNL19-BCgAayw2XKgC6ISC32iMqASk1JYOxJTpAG41YdBIKABBFBQ2AHcIWkCWdhYeRkUAInppbvWoAB8oddC4GmBdg-WKc8OQa-WAL3Wh0ehJ6bmFpfs12ERUDCweEIJDes3mi2Wq349GALD+yiGagA9AAqKAvCZTMGfZY-CxeLYsboJGFw5ADKDHU7xPrdCkUGldQZQECM-osCn3Nl09oHfGUlAnBDAEmwv4UwndbnMhmddkU1lynlcpXMzJ80pQCiislICXbaTSjkCoXAI0K81QFW0tX7KD8kA68VQSWG1XGqnCy2ym3G61M43q+2a+5O8kug0sS2es3u+mWxW+inpFFI4ZqOwIGERonSCEJUEfCHfBSeEo54mHYssACE6zU6URmezMfzmPe4K+LB+HnLMYS62rdYbTbYWeAUAARmxgAALNuFzu40u9rQV6QD6vrXh9wWnTdd+uZJFI8hdmtQAAq4GgAHICZGw3qTfuXWLw+lb-5GAgZ1BcPQ9BwEgCC4JOaDomw6I3lAt6Lji3y3sMzYTkkcBznmSwFliRZdj25ZsBw9AHssR5QCeV4wfeUCEWAxFvrqyZfnAP5-gBQEgWBEHAFBGJwThS6IQAdMhY7ZmwVS4CAEKlgAsrgc5CSwuB0GwAC2AAUACUUDEFAAAMQkAKxmJ4WoDrsmQJF4jqHJZAxAA)

Comment: Oh these horrible tricks are why I hate TypeScript. +1 for explaining them!

Comment: Wow, thank you for your thorough response. The technique used to accomplish this is quite complicated. And now I see how the `never` type is used.