# TypeScript: type for an object with only one key (no union type allowed as a key)

Tags: typescript, union-types

I'm hoping to define a `type` of objects that can have exactly one key.

Here is an attempt:

```
type OneKey<K extends string> = Record<K, any>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't quite work because a variable can have a union type:

```
type OneKey<K extends string> = Record<K, any>

declare function create<
    K extends string,
    T extends OneKey<K>[K]
>(s: K): OneKey<K>

const a = "a";
const res = create(a);


// Good
const check: typeof res = { a: 1, b: 2 }
//                                ~~ Error, object may only specify known properties

declare const many: "a" | "b";
const res2 = create(many);


// **Bad**: I only want one key
const check2: typeof res2 = { a: 1, b: 2 }; // No error
declare const x: "k1" | "k2"
```

Comment: Why don't you create an interface to that? or like a factory method which will verify type and return "undefined" if its not a string (or throw an error, etc), or the desired object otherwise?

Comment: I'm interested in how to do the static check that an object has only one key.

Comment: `Object.keys(yourObj).length` should do the trick :)

Comment: @MaxHeiber Can you describe what is your use case for this? Seems quite counter intuitive to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typescript restrict number of object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190154/typescript-restrict-number-of-objects-properties) and there is also this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10667

Comment: @DaGardner thanks, I marked as a duplicate

Answer (score 23):

If I understand correctly, you want `OneKey<"a" | "b">` to be something like `{a: any, b?: never} | {a?: never, b: any}`.  Meaning that it *either* has an `a` key or a `b` key *but not both*.  So you want the type to be some sort of [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) to represent the *either-or* part of it.  Furthermore, the union type `{a: any} | {b: any}` isn't restrictive enough, since types in TypeScript are open/extendible and can always have unknown extra properties... meaning types are not [exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  So the value `{a: 1, b: 2}` does match the type `{a: any}`, and there's currently no support in TypeScript to represent concretely something like `Exact<{a: any}>` which allows `{a: 1}` but prohibits `{a: 1, b: 2}`.

That being said, TypeScript does have [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks), where *object literals* are treated as if they were of exact types.  This works for you in the `check` case (the error "Object literal may only specify known properties" is specifically a result of excess property checking).  But in the `check2` case, the relevant type will be a union like `{a: any} | {b: any}`... and since both `a` and `b` are both present in at least one member of the union, excess property checking won't kick in there, at least as of TS3.5.  That is [considered a bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20863); presumably `{a: 1, b: 2}` should fail the excess property check since it has excess properties for each member of the union.  But it's not clear when or even if that bug will be addressed.

In any case, it would be better to have `OneKey<"a" | "b">` evaluate to a type like `{a: any, b?: never} | {a?: never, b: any}`... the type `{a: any, b?: never}` will match `{a: 1}` because `b` is optional, but not `{a: 1, b: 2}`, because `2` is not assignable to [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never).  This will give you the *but-not-both* behavior you want.

One last thing before we get started with code: the type `{k?: never}` is equivalent to the type `{k?: undefined}`, since optional properties can always have an `undefined` value (and TypeScript doesn't do a great job of [distinguishing missing from `undefined`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195)).

Here's how I might do it:

```
type OneKey<K extends string, V = any> = {
  [P in K]: (Record<P, V> &
    Partial<Record<Exclude<K, P>, never>>) extends infer O
    ? { [Q in keyof O]: O[Q] }
    : never
}[K];
```

I've allowed `V` to be some value type other than `any` if you want to specifically use `number` or something, but it will default to `any`.  The way it works is to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to iterate over each value `P` in `K` and produce a property for each value.  This property is essentially `Record<P, V>` (so it *does* have a `P` key) intersected with `Partial<Record<Exclude<K, P>, never>>`... [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu) removes members from unions, so `Record<Exclude<K, P>, never>` is an object type with every key in `K` *except* `P`, and whose properties are `never`.  And the `Partial` makes the keys optional.

The type `Record<P, V> & Partial<Record<Exclude<K, P>, never>>` is ugly, so I use a [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) trick to make it pretty again... `T extends infer U ? {[K in keyof U]: U[K]} : never` will take a type `T`, "copy" it over to a type `U`, and then explicitly iterate through its properties.  It will take a type like `{x: string} & {y: number}` and collapse it to `{x: string; y: number}`.

Finally, the mapped type `{[P in K]: ...}` itself is not what we want; we need its value types as a union, so we [lookup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) these values via `{[P in K]: ...}[K]`.

Note that your `create()` function should be typed like this:

```
declare function create<K extends string>(s: K): OneKey<K>;
```

without that `T` in it. Let's test it:

```
const a = "a";
const res = create(a);
// const res: { a: any; }
```

So `res` is still the type `{a: any}` as you want, and behaves the same:

```
// Good
const check: typeof res = { a: 1, b: 2 };
//                                ~~ Error, object may only specify known properties
```

Now, though, we have this:

```
declare const many: "a" | "b";
const res2 = create(many);
// const res2: { a: any; b?: undefined; } | { b: any; a?: undefined; }
```

So that's the union we want.  Does it fix your `check2` problem?

```
const check2: typeof res2 = { a: 1, b: 2 }; // error, as desired
//    ~~~~~~ <-- Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

Yes!

---

One caveat to consider: if the argument to `create()` is just a `string` and not a union of string literals, the resulting type will have a string index signature and can take any number of keys:

```
declare const s: string
const beware = create(s) // {[k: string]: any}
const b: typeof beware = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}; // no error
```

There's no way to distribute across `string`, so there's no way to represent in TypeScript the type "an object type with a *single* key from the set of *all possible string literals*".  You could possibly change `create()` to disallow arguments of type `string`, but this answer is long enough as it is.  It's up to you if you care enough to try to deal with that.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think what I'm looking for is disallowing unions. I am apparently a capitalist pig.

Comment: But `declare const many: "a" | "b"; const res2 = create(many);` is specifically using a union type. You wanted *that* line to be an error?

Comment: maybe. Or maybe it would be OK if create(many) gave me a union of types of object with just one key each. What I am looking for in this case is the ability to restrict each object to have only one key each—whether `create(many)` distributes differently in this case or errors would be fine either way. Perhaps distributing differently would be nicer.

Comment: Okay well I guess this answer is the "distribute differently" answer, and I could also come up with a way to make `create(many)` give a compiler error if `many` is of a union type.  But at this point the question is marked as a duplicate and the question which it supposedly duplicates doesn't really touch on these points at all, so adding such an answer there would seem off-topic.  I'm not sure it makes any sense to proceed here, unless you'd like to reopen this question.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, is there really a way to make `create(many)` error if `many` is of a union type? If so, I'll gladly open a new question and link it here!

Comment: It's certainly [possible](https://repl.it/@jcalz/WhimsicalHappyCensorware) although maybe uglier than you'd want.  (I assume you want `K` to be a single string literal value, and a union or `string`)

Comment: A recent version of TypeScript now does distinguish between missing and undefined properties...