# Create an interface in typescript in which only one of two properties are allowed?

Tags: typescript

Let say I have an interface

```
interface ICart {
    property1?: string,
    propert2?: string,
    someOtherProperty: string
}
```

How can I enforce that only one of property1 and property2 are allowed but one of them needs to be there  ?

Comment: Make it a union of two types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types

Comment: `{property1: string, property2?: never, someOtherProperty: string} | {property1?: never, property2: string, someOtherProperty: string}` should work

Comment: @jcalz is there a concise way to do this in the case the interface is large

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57576688/2887218)?

Comment: @jcalz thanks, I think it may be something I can use but I am still a beginner at typescript so it may require some more reading to understand it.

Comment: Or [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdhA0hEAxATgewLYB4AqANFALJQC8UA3gL7GJQQAewEcAJgM5QDWKmAMyj4KvfkPwA+CgFgAUFEVQGzVh24BDOCCgB+KAAoyAMigAFAJYBjHrgBKEAI4BXC+gjsCk+tNNmN6MAWGgA29hBWmOieAKJMViHO7BC4fCCCwj7ECABuEOiSkgCUjCxsXFAWcAL5sHryStRQANpmlXBi6UIwALoAXLCtPVA0UAO5teMQeegA3PKgkFAAkgDCAcCi8EgoGDi4VFBgWJCBIACMA5zA6FUA5sTHmKegAExXN-cjxIecOBAwYAAC3yZhO+VAH1ucDuI0ksyAA) maybe

Comment: @jcalz wow thanks, will this snippet work if I just changed ```{ someOtherProperty: string }``` with ```{someOtherProperty1:string, someOtherProperty2: string //and so on}```

Comment: I don't know because I don't know what your use case is.  In the linked code, `OneKeyFrom<T, U>` will require all properties from `U` and exactly one property from `T`.  So if you have more properties to require, add them to `U`.  If you have more properties to switch between, add them to `T`.  I will write this up as an answer when I get the time (unless someone gets there first).  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow exactly one property from a list, you need a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of object types where each one allows a particular property and disallows all others.  TypeScript doesn't exactly allow you to disallow a particular property, but you can do something close: make it an optional property whose value type is `never`.  In practice this will allow a property of type `undefined`, but there's not a lot of difference between `undefined` properties and missing properties (and the difference isn't captured well in TypeScript with normal compiler options [see ms/TS#13195](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195)).

So, for your example above, the type you want looks like:

```
type ICartManual = {
    property1: string;
    property2?: undefined;
    someOtherProperty: string;
} | {
    property1?: undefined;
    property2: string;
    someOtherProperty: string;
}
```

And you can verify that it behaves as you desire:

```
const i1: ICartManual = {
    property1: "prop1",
    someOtherProperty: "other"
}

const i2: ICartManual = {
    property2: "prop2",
    someOtherProperty: "other"
}

const iBoth: ICartManual = { // error!
//    ~~~~~ <-- property1 is incompatible with undefined
    property1: "prop1",
    property2: "prop2",
    someOtherProperty: "other"
}

const iNeither: ICartManual = { // error!
//    ~~~~~~~~ <-- property2 is missing
    someOtherProperty: "other"
}
```

---

If you have a large interface and want to take two object types `T` and `U` and make a new one which requires exactly one property from `T` and all properties from `U`, you can define it like this:

```
type OneKeyFrom<T, M = {}, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = K extends any ?
    (M & Pick<Required<T>, K> & Partial<Record<Exclude<keyof T, K>, never>>) extends infer O ?
    { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never : never;
```

That uses a bunch of [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) types to build the union you want.  I could explain how it works but it would take a lot of words.  I've done similar before; look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57571664/typescript-type-for-an-object-with-only-one-key-no-union-type-allowed-as-a-key/57576688#57576688) for a more in-depth description of a similar type.

Anyway, we can define `ICart` like this now:

```
type ICart = OneKeyFrom<{ property1: string, property2: string }, { someOtherProperty: string }>;
```

and you can verify (via IntelliSense, for example) that it is the same as the manually-written type (except for the order the properties are written in, which doesn't change the type):

```
/* type ICart = {
    property1: string;
    property2?: undefined;
    someOtherProperty: string;
} | {
    property2: string;
    property1?: undefined;
    someOtherProperty: string;
} */
```

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=48&ssc=5&pln=40&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgwgQwE7ALIIHYFcEBsoC8UA3gLABQUVUYSA9pCiAIwBcUAzsEgJYYDmAbgrUa9RqABMAfnZYMAEwgAzPhAXDK1DnQC2EAPLAAFhCQAFcWdDsuvAZoC+UAD4kR1Wg2stZUeUqqGOqaol4SIJK23HxCHlQ6+kamFlZM0fZx5I4UFADGdBhcUDxssIgo6Nh4hO5aVOE+ZQBE4czNADTxnHqGJmaW3ulQzXT9SM0UOeT5hcU8UeXIaJg4+ERk9WJDUuyt4pKd3Yl9KYMRe2Mpk9m55AVFwCUAQlfs8MtVa7XEUAD0fygZnoSAAhBQAaIAH4wmFQAA8AFpEdsIswShwShgCrowAhgDwAEa4aAAdx4Jn8ihUagU3UaTBabSOWwZuxG4UOXS2J2SAzSNhGVzMN2ms0eJQAchAKSl3hUVtV1iR-oDgXQwRDAdRYbqoQjkaifJIMVBdDwOBxYsdenzUjsQJdxqK7hRQJAoAZggBpCAgABi9F08IAKh0oABVH6OcPeoEAD2AEEUmIA1n66MooCHaumQJnswA+WpxiCJ5MKTGYEBQaTdAAU5h4eVT8IAShAAI5YHhIdShwux4sAMig5mWPDw7YgBSQCnhAFF43lcFglPC8wWw1BvYOoMEAG5mQsjyMASgTSZTWOUZk9te6vwA2uYsVBN1mDABddgGF9fqBnHYQ872AiAjyQTQ7ndaAPhQWovQgX0AyDeFfjZFgMlicMMMWOxYkA8Nfl5cZzh8LCBEAwtND+AAqKAYKWeCNnpAVMM4GIHFYh0ZDkakghCG0klItiKKyZw3E2MI2Lwzismkh1mD8AIaWCDQhNOfkHTEpwoFov47iAA)

Answer (score 0):

```
// utility type which blocks two properties of the object coexisting 
type NeverTogether<A extends object, Key1 extends keyof A, Key2 extends keyof A extends Key1 ? never : keyof A> = 
  Omit<A, Key1 | Key2> & (({
    [k in Key1]: A[Key1]
  } & {[k in Key2]?: never}) | ({
    [k in Key1]?: never
  } & {[k in Key2]: A[Key2]}))

interface ICart {
    property1: string,
    property2: string,
    someOtherProperty: string
}

type IC = NeverTogether<ICart, 'property1', 'property2'>;

// error never together
const a: IC = {
  property1: '1',
  property2: '2',
  someOtherProperty: '2'
}

// error one needs to be there
const b: IC = {
  someOtherProperty: '2'
}

// correct
const c: IC = {
  property2: '2',
  someOtherProperty: '2'
}

// correct
const d: IC = {
  property1: '1',
  someOtherProperty: '2'
}
```

The issue which `NeverTogether` type has is composing it in order to have such rule for more keys. So works nice for two dependent fields, but cannot have it working for more. But maybe this will help you. For me it was nice puzzle to solve.