# Enforce Typescript object has exactly one key from a set

Tags: typescript

### Basic Question and Context

I'm trying to type an array of objects where each object has exactly one key from a set. For example:

```js
const foo = [
  { a: 'foo' },
  { b: 'bar' },
  { c: 'baz' },
]
```

My first attempt was `key in` a union:

```js
type Foo = { [key in 'a' | 'b' | 'c']: string }[]
const foo: Foo = [
  { a: 'foo' },
  { b: 'bar' },
  { c: 'baz' },
]
```

This doesn't work as Typescript wants *every* object to have *all* the keys in the union:

```js
type Foo = { [key in 'a' | 'b' | 'c']: string }[]
const foo: Foo = [
  { a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz' },
  { a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz' },
  { a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz' },
]
```

My second attempt was:

```js
type A = { a: string }
type B = { b: string }
type C = { c: string }
type Foo = (A | B | C)[]
const foo: Foo = [
  { a: 'foo' },
  { b: 'bar' },
  { c: 'baz' },
]
```

but, as [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872063/enforce-typescript-object-has-exactly-one-key-from-a-set#comment107698634_60872063), that still allows:

```js
const foo: Foo = [{ a: 'foo', b: 'bar' }]
```

Is there a way to enforce that each object has exactly one key and that key is either `a` *or* `b` *or* `c`?

#### Slightly more context

Our project is trying to read in [this JSON](https://github.com/tableau-mkt/addressfield.json) to handle dynamic forms for address fields in different countries in React. When Typescript reads that JSON blob in, it gets most things wrong. Most importantly, it believes that the `fields` key is not always an array and so doesn't let me `.map` over it. So I decided to copy the JSON blob into our project and type it by hand. I'm trying to capture the fact that the `fields` array is an array of objects that are either `thoroughfare`, `premise`, or `locality` and that `locality` is an array of objects that are either `localityname`, etc.

Comment: Your solution allows `const foo: Foo = [{a: "foo", b: "bar"}]` also.  When you say "exactly" one key, do you mean "at least"?  That is, your solution is equivalent to [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAgsAyECGBnYB5AdhA0hEAPDlBAB7ASYAmKUA1vgPYBmUSmIANFAGoB8UALxQA3lADaABSgBLTFBwBdAFyiJARVnzJK3lAC+B8UoDcAWABQoSFABijRkNgAnZ0kJxEqDNjyEAREj+UAA+UP4ARsFh-gDG-txoznIA5nx85haxjJhoUMwOqvaOwuKWUGpIqgDkBYzV3BGqgUhBBpzlak1Q1RFIztXtnWKxNX0AXoP6HRaKlpZAA), which may or may not be an answer to your question depending on your requirements.

Comment: Great catch and great question! My data is coming from a static JSON file in which there are no `{ a: '', b: '' }` items. That being said I'm not sure if my typing needs to exclude that case. Basically I'm using `if ('a' in obj) { ... }` so in the case of `{ a: '', b: '' }` my solution is order dependent but doesn't break because the source data doesn't have that case. That being said, let's assume I don't want to allow `{ a: '', b: '' }`. I'll update the question :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a type that expects *exactly* one key, you can (mostly) represent this as a union of object types where each member of the union has one key defined and all the rest of the keys as optional and of [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  (In practice this will also allow `undefined`, see [ms/TS#13195](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195), unless you use [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) which is not part of the `--strict` suite.

So your `Foo` should look something like:

```
type Foo = Array<
  { a: string; b?: never; c?: never; } | 
  { a?: never; b: string; c?: never; } |
  { a?: never; b?: never; c: string; }
>
```

How can we get that or something like it programmatically?  Well it's a bit tricky to explain, but my solution looks like this:

```
type ExactlyOneKey<K extends keyof any, V, KK extends keyof any = K> =
  { [P in K]: { [Q in P]: V } &
    { [Q in Exclude<KK, P>]?: never} extends infer O ?
    { [Q in keyof O]: O[Q] } : never
  }[K];

type Foo = Array<ExactlyOneKey<"a" | "b" | "c", string>>;
```

The type `ExactlyOneKey<K, V>` takes the key union `K` and iterates over it.  For each member `P` of the union, it makes an object type with that key present and the other keys absent/missing.  The type `{[Q in P]: V}` (aka `Record<P, V>`) has the present key and value, and the type `{[Q in Exclude<KK, P>]?: never}` has all the rest of the keys as optional-and-never.  We intersect those together with `&` to get a type with both features.  Then I do a little trick where `... extends infer O ? { [Q in keyof O]: O[Q] } : never` will take the type `...` and merge all intersections into a single object type.  This isn't strictly necessary, but it will change `{a: string} & {b?: never, c?: never}` to `{a: string; b?: never; c?: never;}` which is more palatable.

And let's make sure it works:

```
const foo: Foo = [
  { a: 'foo' },
  { b: 'bar' },
  { c: 'baz' },
]; // okay

const badFoo: Foo = [
  { d: "nope" }, // error
  { a: "okay", b: "oops" }  // error
];
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwMbADYgPIDsIGkIgA8uUEcwEWAJgM5QDWBA9gGZQJYgA0UAaj7hJkK1OoxCt2nKAF4ouAHyyAsACgoUAN5QA2gAUoASyzyAugC4tugIpGTei3ygBfKADI1Gjdp23jsOCRUAFcqCGJcHj0FUwB+SxwANwgAJxdSckpaOxZUqAwoWM8vHz8TcUkMRwxfU3SEiGSU4ucdXFMAbjU1UEgoABUIGmBZAOQ0TBx8IgAiBBmoAB8oGYAjBeWZpBmeYZTjAHMFLtUAegAqKF7oQeHZa4GhkblNYo0ESz3Dk68oVfioElUj8vEgAUCUidXMtXuovKtPsB9lgDiD3uDGsC3lAwQ0mlCllpsUhEcjUdiEBj8dj-nisapXOdTlBuqoHgAxJhMUYAQRSKQQRHg43Q2DwBEIcw2K3WhK2OygXxRCmOrKQTCwdxYXMsnO5ch0xW0HygAHJtUxTS4uEa-pZTasECkrc4bXDtCSzY6AF4ut2dKCnZlMeiCtUau6Oqh63Vc0aG91QKiWGZYJiQBauwPM1IpJjNRMmmYhwUKhErLlgGiZjRB0j8-NqTqsoA)

Answer (score 2):

Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57571664/typescript-type-for-an-object-with-only-one-key-no-union-type-allowed-as-a-key) work for you?

```
type OneKey<K extends string, V = any> = {
    [P in K]: (Record<P, V> &
        Partial<Record<Exclude<K, P>, never>>) extends infer O
        ? { [Q in keyof O]: O[Q] }
        : never
}[K]; //CREDITS TO JCALZ

type Foo = Array<OneKey<'a' | 'b' | 'c', string>>;

const foo: Foo = [
    { a: 'foo' },
    { b: 'bar' },
    { c: 'baz' },
]; //OK

const foo2: Foo = [
    { a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz' },
    { a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz' },
    { a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz' },
]; //NOPE

const foo3: Foo = [{ a: 'foo', b: 'bar' }]; //NOPE
```

Comment: Great! I believe this is also correct and I think also makes my question a duplicate! But you've made things difficult for me :-) As you've linked to an answer from jcalz who has _also_ posted an answer directly to this question I'm not sure which one to mark as an answer nor if/how to mark this question as a duplicate. I wonder if @jcalz could help me out in determining if their answer and yours are equivalent and if this question should be marked as duplicate?

Comment: @MarkLodato My bad, my answer is silly in that case. Accept his of course :)