# How to type an object key in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a simple function that takes an object in parameter. In order to receive only valid data, I need to type the key of the object as such:

```js
type DataType = "about" | "favorites" | "username";
type UpdatedData = { [key in DataType]: any };

function onSave (updatedData: UpdatedData){
//do stuff
}

// in a component
const onClickSave = () => onSave({ "about": text });
```

Typescript throws the following error:

> Argument of type '{ about: text; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UpdatedData'.
> Type '{ about: text; }' is missing the following properties from type 'UpdatedData': favorites, username

How to fix this? Of course, I could write `[key: string]` instead of `[key in DataType]` but the typing would be useless then.

Comment: Are all the properties of UpdatedData optional?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to pass one of the DataType option as the key of the object in onSave().

Comment: one and only one ?

Comment: Basically, onSave({hello: text}) should be false because the key "hello" is not allowed, and onSave({about: text}) should be true because the key "about" is allowed.

Comment: and onSave({}) or onSave({about:'', username:''})

Comment: I only need one object for the moment. So onSave({}) will do the trick. However, the second solution could be handy in the future. So if you have both solutions, feel free to write them down :)!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the properties of `UpdatedData` can be optional just add in a `?` to make them optional.

**Edit:**
As @Jérémie B mentioned an empty `{}` is still permitted with this.

```
type DataType = "about" | "favorites" | "username";
type UpdatedData = { [key in DataType]?: any };
function onSave (updatedData: UpdatedData){
}
const text = "hello"

const onClickSave = () => onSave({ "about": text });
```

Comment: but `onSave({})` is valid here. with ths function name, I don't know if it's really allowed.

Comment: @JérémieB that is true, I will ask the OP whether this is sufficient or whether `{}` should not be allowed.

Comment: {} should not be allowed, it wouldn't make sense to send an empty object to the server.

Comment: I will accept @yudhiesh's answer, I only have to make a check before the call, this will do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```js
type DataType = "about" | "favorites" | "username";
type Expand<U> = U extends string ? { [key in U]: any } : never

type UpdatedData = Expand<DataType>
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIgQxAgKpWBeGAiBAjAewFcRsYAfHAMwQDcCAnASxCgGczLsi2oGA7BAFso2ANzBQ6GAFEAHhAT8AJgB4AqgD4YWdTChzWKtjDYhm-AOYwA-DADeMANoBrKGBhN%20MdQF0AXDBKHgC%20MIH8ULR8UtA%20EMpIUMqIyDqyCkpqqajompJURPwAxiBMBN4VAMp0sAAURAlJKUgIgepNrC3IAJT2wAD0A8oEpiBEVFTAIZJDnt4IMMUEQhAVUPwgwMv8ZjAVAMIANkzFLjXR6XU9OtrVtXWOuIQk2IHYYARkIT0SQA)

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the same thing that @JérémieB provided can be accomplished with the following [const assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993264/what-does-the-as-const-mean-in-typescript-and-what-is-its-use-case):

```js
const DataType = ["about", "favorites", "username"] as const;
type UpdatedData = { [key in typeof DataType]?: any };
```

But as @yudhiesh mentioned, making each field optional allows more than one field to be present (as well as no fields at all). If you're in a scenario where *only* one key should be allowed from a list of expected key values, then I'd recommend taking a look at this post instead: [Enforce Typescript object has exactly one key from a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872063/enforce-typescript-object-has-exactly-one-key-from-a-set)