# Can you create a Typescript type that has exactly one of a set of properties AND is indexable by that set

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have the following types:

```
type OrBranch = {
   or: Branch[]
}

type AndBranch = {
   and: Branch[]
}
```

I'd like a type `Branch` that can be either an `OrBranch` or an `AndBranch`.  So I first tried:

```
type Branch = AndBrand | OrBranch
```

Work great, unless I want to do something like:

```
let branch: Branch = ...
let andOr = 'and';   // or 'or'

let nodes = branch[andOr]
```

Then I get that `branch` isn't indexable.  OK, so I try an indexable type:

```
type AndOr = 'and' | 'or';
type Branch = Record<AndOr, Branch[]>;
```

But that requires that BOTH `and` and `or` exist, so I can't cast and AndBranch to Branch in this case.

Similarly

```
type Branch = Record<AndOr, Branch[]> | AndBranch | OrBranch
```

doesn't work, for the same reason.

While I could use type guards to determine the type, I have long functions that operate on these objects, in which they can be treated the same other than the property.  I was hoping to eliminate a bunch of duplicate code by using the `andOr` variable, which type guards don't really prevent.  For example:

```
let retval = {} as Branch;
if (isAnd(branch)) {  // branch is a Branch parameter passed in
   (retval as AndBranch).and = [] as Branch[];
   set = (retval as AndBranch).and;
} else {
   (retval as OrBranch).or = [] as Branch[];
   set = (retval as OrBranch).or;
}

set = _.reduce(set, (all, item: Branch)=> {
   if (isAnd(branch) && isAnd(item)) 
      return _.union(all, item.and);
   else if (isOr(branch) && isOr(item)) 
      return _.union(all, item.or);
   else 
      return all;
}, [] as Branch[]);
```

vs.

```
andOr = isAnd(branch) ? 'and' : 'or';
let retval = {} as Branch;
retval[andOr] = _.reduce(set, (all, item: Branch) => {
   if (item[andOr]) 
      return _.union(all, item[andOr]);
   else
      return all;
}, [] as Branch[]);
```

I know there's a way to require exactly one of `and` and `or` (like the answer to [Enforce Typescript object has exactly one key from a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872063/enforce-typescript-object-has-exactly-one-key-from-a-set)).  But that type is not indexable.

Is it possible to get both effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the type indexable won't solve the basic problem, which is that you're trying to use the property `and` on something that may be an `and` branch (and thus have the property) or may be an `or` branch (and thus not). Instead, ask the branch what it has and use that, because that allows TypeScript to narrow the type:

```typescript
if ("and" in branch) {
    // ...use `branch.and`...
} else {
    // ...use `branch.or`...
}
```

You could combine that with your `andOr` if you have code that thinks it knows what the branch is, perhaps by using a type assertion function:

```typescript
function assertIsAndBranch(branch: Branch): asserts branch is AndBranch {
    if (!("and" in branch)) {
        throw new Error(`branch is not an AndBranch`);
    }
}
// (And `assertIsOrBranch`)
```

Then:

```
if (andOr === "and") {
    assertIsAndBranch(branch);
    // ...here, TypeScript knows `branch` is an `AndBranch`...
}
```

---

Re your edit: If you have significant code that needs to deal with the items contained by `AndBranch`'s `and` or `OrBranch`'s `or` without knowing or caring whether they're `AndBranch` or `OrBranch` instances, I'd redesign them as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) where all members of the union have the same `items` (or whatever) property:

```typescript
type OrBranch = {
    type: "or";
    items: Branch[];
};

type AndBranch = {
    type: "and";
    items: Branch[];
};
```

That way, the code that doesn't care what type of branch it is can work with `items`. The code you showed would be:

```typescript
const items = _.reduce(branch.items, (all, item) => {
    return _.union(all, item.items);
}, [] as Branch[]);
const retval = {type: branch.type, items};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAfTgMyhEcBEAbCATAQwGcALTAbgChKYBPMAUzgHkoAhKAgOwGMS4AvHADelOOLh1GALizQKYicBgMQRWR258A2gF0qAXyo16TAIJc8m3vyGiJk07Mzc8Ch8tXq41nfspG1FJMvrZwFlacNnAAPizsUXzGyACuvDDAEFxweBAAyugMMCTAXADmABQARokkGrUAlCKK4jxZRPCeaoKIAHRQDHgpPAzVtb1dRAA0cBUE2NgzXU0CAHzNDg4DMClQ2Qi9aZlccwtLKiATF0QNVA4GM3pwxD61erctcG1cHXDbAG7zHrCYKyGpaEi9YLnLyBBwAenh8Wkn0RX3a8ABQLsvVx4JsMLUcIk2122Sx2EMlCAA)

Having properties do double-duty (both indicating the type of branch and the items within it) as they do in your current types makes writing typesafe code to handle the items without knowing/caring what type of branch it is really hard.

Comment: Thanks.  My challenge is I have functions that operate on both branch types the same way and I was hoping to prevent duplicating all this code.  Type guards can sort of do that, but they cause a code mess of their own.  I've edited the question with an example.

Comment: @DovRosenberg - I've added to the answer to address the edit. :-)

Comment: Ah... good call.  Thanks.