Using generics to match a single string literal in Typescript
The class MyClass interfaces with an indexing sub-system that requires each record (Record<string, any>) to contain a specific primary key field. I'm trying to use Typescript's type system to ensure that every record given to MyClass contains this primary key field, by giving it a string literal as a generic parameter. I do not need to use the field's value; only to ensure it exists in each record. Is it possible to craft a class MyClass<T...> such that T... matches a string literal only?
Example usage of MyClass<T>:
class MyClass<T ...> { // Can T match a single string literal?
  add(arg: Record<T, any> & Record<string, any>): void {}
  get(arg: T): Record<T, any> & Record<string, any> {}
};

const myClass = new MyClass<"requiredKey">();
myClass.add({
    requiredKey: "someValue";
    //...
}); // Ok
myClass.add({
    someOtherKey: "someValue";
}); // Rejected by the compiler

I started to define a type which I thought was constrained to being a string literal and not a union, based on a previous answer
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never;
type StringLiteral<T extends string> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>]
  ? string extends T ? never : string : never;

My test cases:
class MyClass<K extends StringLiteral<K>> {
  constructor() {}
  add(arg: Record<K, any> & Record<string, any>) {}
  get(arg: Record<K, any>): Record<K, any> & Record<string, any> { return null!; }
};

let t = new MyClass<"a">();        // Ok: Valid
let u = new MyClass<"a" | "b">();  // Ok: Invalid `"a" | "b"` does not satisfy `never`
let v = new MyClass<string>();     // Ok: Invalid `string` does not satisfy `never`
let w = new MyClass<1>();          // Ok: Invalid `1` does not extend `string`
let x = new MyClass<`${"a"}`>();   // Ok: String template literals are fine
let z = new MyClass<never>();      // Not ok, but I can live with that...

I am satisfied with this approach; but since I am new to Typescript, and I am wondering if there was a simpler solution.
Currently using typescript 5.5.
LONG EDIT
Following the discussion in the comments, I reworded the question to better illustrate the problem. Leave a comment if still unclear.

What is the underlying use case? What bad thing happens if arg has more than one key? Because no matter what you do in TS, that can still happen. Trying to force TS not to allow extra properties is, to a large extent, wasted effort.  Please [edit] to clarify the use case; it's quite possible there's an approach that works better for this.

(see prev comment).  Also note that TS allows template string pattern index signatures so you might want to guard against K being something like \abc${number}def`` as shown in this playground link. Do you care about this? Either way, please [edit] to clarify.

@jcalz I've updated the first paragraph and some of the code example to - hopefully - give a good sense of my use-case. Template string patterns still fit my use case, if a user were to define them as shown in your example. I had not considered Symbols, and I need to read more about it.

I've realised that I could simplify the template expression in MyClass to the same effect. So I changed class MyClass<K extends [K] extends [StringLiteral<K>] ? string : never> to class MyClass<K extends StringLiteral<K>> which has the same meaning if I also change StringLiteral<K> to return string instead of any.

• Why doesn't the constructor accept the field name as a key? I don't see how requiring K to be anything in particular matters with the code here. I'd love to see how something bad happens if you allow K to be, say, "a" | "b". • No, \${"a"}`isn't what I'm talking about (that's just"a"). I'm talking about template string *patterns* like `abc${number}def`. You see that numberin there? That matches *multiple strings* like"abc1def"and"abc5632def". So it's not a single key anymore and your StringLiteral` utility improperly classifies it. Do you understand?

• Since I placed checks in the member functions to verify that records would contain the key, I decided to explore if it was possible to use the type system to avoid the need for the checks. • Thanks for the additional precision, I understand what you mean now and definitely learned something new about Typescript here. StringLiteral<K> will not constrain K to a single string literal, as you said initially, it was wasted effort. The simpler MyClass<K extends string> would have achieved a similar outcome.

I think you will need runtime checks no matter what, but I don't see those checks in your code so I'm not sure how you even determine what key you're looking for (the code here just has the key as a type, so there's no way runtime knows about it.) You can try to constrain to a single string literal but it's complicated and probably fragile. ... So what do you want to see here? An answer saying "don't try to do this"? An answer showing the closest we can get to ensuring a single string literal?

To expand on the use case: MyClass hands over the record to an external sub-system that does the indexing; I initially wrote MyClass's methods with checks such as Object.keys(arg).includes(this.primaryKey); before exploring using types instead. I'm interested to understand how your playground works, with the caveat that it may only be useful to ensure the presence of said key.

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872063/enforce-typescript-object-has-exactly-one-key-from-a-set

I'm afraid I still don't see the use case that requires the type to be a single string literal type, but in what follows I'll see how close we can get.

First, we can write a utility type IsUnion<T, Y, N> to detect if an input type T is a union and return Y if yes and N if no:
type IsUnion<T, Y = unknown, N = never, U = T> =
    T extends unknown ? [U] extends [T] ? N : Y : never

This is a distributive conditional type in T. It splits T into its union members, and checks each member against the whole union U (which uses a default type argument to be a non-distributed copy of T). If the whole union is assignable to each member, that means there is only one member and we return N. Otherwise we return Y.

Then we can write a StrLit<T, Y, N> utility type to detect if the (presumed non-union) input string type T is a string literal type, or if it's something wider like string or a template literal pattern type (as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#40498) like `foo${string}`:
type StrLit<T extends string, Y = unknown, N = never> =
    T extends `${infer F}${infer R}` ? (
        ["0", "1"] extends [F, F] ? N : StrLit<R, Y, N>
    ) : T extends "" ? Y : N

There's not really a clean way to do this. The only way I've found is to use template literal types to parse T one "character" at a time. If any character is something wide then it's not a string literal. By "something wide" I mean either string or one of the other possible pattern template literal types like `${number}` or `${bigint}`.  My test here is: if both "0" and "1" are assignable to it, then it's wide.  (Note that "0" and "1" are both valid strings and valid serialized numbers and valid serialized bigints).  When we're finished parsing we should end up with "", which means we've found a string literal. If not (because the last "character" of the string type is wide) then we haven't.

And now we can write the utility checking type SingleKey<T> that evaluates to unknown if T (presumed to be an object type) has a single string literal key, and never otherwise:
type SingleKey<T> = IsUnion<keyof T, never,
    keyof T extends string ? StrLit<keyof T> : never>

class MyClass<T extends object & SingleKey<T>> {
  constructor() { }
  functionThatMeetsMyGoal(arg: T) { return arg }
}

Let's test it:
new MyClass<{key: any}>(); // okay   
new MyClass<{key1: any; key2: any}>(); // error
new MyClass<{ [k: `abc${number}def`]: string }>() // error
new MyClass<{ [k: number]: string }>() // error

Looks good.

There you go. I wouldn't recommend trying to really use this to guarantee single keys in a type.
First of all, nothing would prevent a value of such a type from having more than one key, because TypeScript does not have "exact types" as described in microsoft/TypeScript#. You can always widen types with extra properties to ones without them:
let x = { key: "abc", oopsie: 123 };
let y: { key: any } = x; // this is allowed

So such types aren't really helpful in preventing runtime values from having more properties than you expect.
And more importantly, the above utility types are complex and probably fragile. TypeScript does not really intend to allow you to query "is this a single string literal", and the implementation above depends on knowing exactly what subtypes of string TypeScript supports and uses tricks to distinguish them.  Future versions of TypeScript might add or change string types in such a way as to break this. So I'd stay away from anything like this in any sort of production system that depends on it.  It's fun to explore, but not something you should rely on.
Playground link to code

Thanks @jcalz, this was very instructive!
