# When defining an index type, can I limit the number of properties that exist?

Tags: typescript

Typescript lets me set an index type on a method signature like so:

```
function myFunc(dict: { [x: string]: string }) {
  ...
}
```

so this function will only accept objects that have `string` indicies and `string` values - akin to `Dictionary<string, string>` in C#. Can I restrict this further so that only objects that have a **single** string key with a string value are accepted?

i.e. so that

```
const a = {
  x: 'val'
};
```

is valid, but

```
const b = {
  x: 'val1',
  y: 'val2'
};
```

is not?

Obviously I can check the length of `Object.keys()` but it would be nice if the compiler could enforce it.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a dictionary? Dictionaries are used when there's any number of properties in which names are not known in advance. Perhaps `function myFunc(key: string, value: string)` would do the trick just as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typescript restrict number of object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190154/typescript-restrict-number-of-objects-properties)

Answer (score 1):

I never like to say TypeScript can't do something, because...it's extremely powerful and there are a *lot* of obscure corners. :-) But I've never seen anything to suggest it can limit an indexed type to a single property.

Even if it can, though, I think in that situation I would use a `[string, string]`, not an indexed type:

```
function example(tuple: [string, string]) {
    console.log(tuple[0], tuple[1]);
}

example(['x', 'val']); // works

example(['x', 'val', 'y', 'val']); // fails
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=11&ssc=52&pln=8&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCihD2QC5EBtAZygCcYwBzAGkVoeYF0BKRAbwCwAKERjEEBNTj4AdLjhMiJfJQAMXNsVKUAjLwDcIgL4iRaLKQKUA5KhtsbAN3S4bhxAHpPiAO5w6AGtqM2ELHHxrOwdEZ1cYmwBPBJc3D29EYHQYXBDhIA)