# Allow object to have only one key from the type

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

There is a type:

```
type AllKeys = {
  prop1: string
  prop2: string
  prop3: string
}
```

What I want to achieve is to create another type `OneOfKeys` that will allow objects to be created with only one of the keys:

```
const obj: OneOfKeys = { // <-- should work
  prop1: 1
}
```

```
const obj: OneOfKeys = { // <-- should work
  prop2: 2
}
```

```
const obj: OneOfKeys = { // <-- should not be allowed
  prop1: 1
  prop2: 2
}
```

```
const obj: OneOfKeys = { // <-- should not be allowed
  randomProp: 1
}
```

I tried to create it this way but with this implementation we need to provide all 3 props. I know that we can add `?` before `:` to make them optional, but we won't get an error if more than 1 property is declared on the object. Is there a way to achieve the behavior described?

```
type OneOfKeys = {
  [Property in keyof AllKeys]: number
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190154/typescript-restrict-count-of-objects-properties?noredirect=1&lq=1) should answer your question, you can upvote him ;)

Comment: [This approach](https://tsplay.dev/mArB8W) is how one might do this programmatically; see the linked questions/answers for details.